# How to iterate over arguments in a Bash script

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a complex command that I'd like to make a shell/bash script of.  I can write it in terms of `$1` easily:

```
foo $1 args -o $1.ext
```

I want to be able to pass multiple input names to the script. What's the right way to do it?

And, of course, I want to handle filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: FYI, it's a good idea to always put parameters within quotes. You never know when a parm might contain an embedded space.

Answer (score 1943, accepted):

Use `"$@"` to represent all the arguments:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

This will iterate over each argument and print it out on a separate line.  $@ behaves like $* except that, when quoted, the arguments are broken up properly if there are spaces in them:

```
sh test.sh 1 2 '3 4'
1
2
3 4
```

Comment: Incidentally, one of the other merits of `"$@"` is that it expands to nothing when there are no positional parameters whereas `"$*"` expands to the empty string -- and yes, there is a difference between no arguments and one empty argument.  See [`${1:+"$@"} in `/bin/sh`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154625/).

Comment: Note that this notation should also be used in shell functions to access all the arguments to the function.

Comment: how do I start from the second argument? I mean, I need this but always start from the second argument, this is, skip $1.

Comment: @m4l490n: `shift` throws away `$1`, and shifts down all subsequent elements.

Comment: It should be noted that (as per bash man page) the first positional parameter ($0) is not included inside $@ or "$@". This is in general what you want when executing a script **file** but this may surprise you when executing `bash -c 'echo "$@"' a b` only shows `b`.

Comment: Even simpler, change the first line to `for var`. As per the bash man page, if the `in X` part is left off, it is assumed to be `in "$@"`,

Answer (score 275):

<sup>*Rewrite of a now-deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255939/) by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc).*</sup>

[Robert Gamble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255913/417685)'s succinct answer deals directly with the question.
This one amplifies on some issues with filenames containing spaces.

See also: [${1:+"$@"} in /bin/sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154625/1-in-binsh)

**Basic thesis:** `"$@"` is correct, and `$*` (unquoted) is almost always wrong.
This is because `"$@"` works fine when arguments contain spaces, and
works the same as `$*` when they don't.
In some circumstances, `"$*"` is OK too, but `"$@"` usually (but not
always) works in the same places.
Unquoted, `$@` and `$*` are equivalent (and almost always wrong).

So, what is the difference between `$*`, `$@`, `"$*"`, and `"$@"`?  They are all related to 'all the arguments to the shell', but they do different things. When unquoted, `$*` and `$@` do the same thing.  They treat each 'word' (sequence of non-whitespace) as a separate argument.  The quoted forms are quite different, though: `"$*"` treats the argument list as a single space-separated string, whereas `"$@"` treats the arguments almost exactly as they were when specified on the command line.
`"$@"` expands to nothing at all when there are no positional arguments; `"$*"` expands to an empty string — and yes, there's a difference, though it can be hard to perceive it.
See more information below, after the introduction of the (non-standard) command `al`.

**Secondary thesis:** if you need to process arguments with spaces and then
pass them on to other commands, then you sometimes need non-standard
tools to assist. (Or you should use arrays, carefully: `"${array[@]}"` behaves analogously to `"$@"`.)

*Example:*

```
    $ mkdir "my dir" anotherdir
    $ ls
    anotherdir      my dir
    $ cp /dev/null "my dir/my file"
    $ cp /dev/null "anotherdir/myfile"
    $ ls -Fltr
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Nov  1 14:55 my dir/
    drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Nov  1 14:55 anotherdir/
    $ ls -Fltr *
    my dir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 my file

    anotherdir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 myfile
    $ ls -Fltr "./my dir" "./anotherdir"
    ./my dir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 my file

    ./anotherdir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 myfile
    $ var='"./my dir" "./anotherdir"' && echo $var
    "./my dir" "./anotherdir"
    $ ls -Fltr $var
    ls: "./anotherdir": No such file or directory
    ls: "./my: No such file or directory
    ls: dir": No such file or directory
    $
```

Why doesn't that work?
It doesn't work because the shell processes quotes before it expands
variables.
So, to get the shell to pay attention to the quotes embedded in `$var`,
you have to use `eval`:

```
    $ eval ls -Fltr $var
    ./my dir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 my file

    ./anotherdir:
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  0 Nov  1 14:55 myfile
    $
```

This gets really tricky when you have file names such as "`He said,
"Don't do this!"`" (with quotes and double quotes and spaces).

```
    $ cp /dev/null "He said, \"Don't do this!\""
    $ ls
    He said, "Don't do this!"       anotherdir                      my dir
    $ ls -l
    total 0
    -rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    0 Nov  1 15:54 He said, "Don't do this!"
    drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Nov  1 14:55 anotherdir
    drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff  102 Nov  1 14:55 my dir
    $
```

The shells (all of them) do not make it particularly easy to handle such
stuff, so (funnily enough) many Unix programs do not do a good job of
handling them.
On Unix, a filename (single component) can contain any characters except
slash and NUL `'\0'`.
However, the shells strongly encourage no spaces or newlines or tabs
anywhere in a path names.
It is also why standard Unix file names do not contain spaces, etc.

When dealing with file names that may contain spaces and other
troublesome characters, you have to be extremely careful, and I found
long ago that I needed a program that is not standard on Unix.
I call it `escape` (version 1.1 was dated 1989-08-23T16:01:45Z).

Here is an example of `escape` in use - with the SCCS control system.
It is a cover script that does both a `delta` (think *check-in*) and a
`get` (think *check-out*).
Various arguments, especially `-y` (the reason why you made the change)
would contain blanks and newlines.
Note that the script dates from 1992, so it uses back-ticks instead of
`$(cmd ...)` notation and does not use `#!/bin/sh` on the first line.

```
:   "@(#)$Id: delget.sh,v 1.8 1992/12/29 10:46:21 jl Exp $"
#
#   Delta and get files
#   Uses escape to allow for all weird combinations of quotes in arguments

case `basename $0 .sh` in
deledit)    eflag="-e";;
esac

sflag="-s"
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in
    -r*)    gargs="$gargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            dargs="$dargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            ;;
    -e)     gargs="$gargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            sflag=""
            eflag=""
            ;;
    -*)     dargs="$dargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            ;;
    *)      gargs="$gargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            dargs="$dargs `escape \"$arg\"`"
            ;;
    esac
done

eval delta "$dargs" && eval get $eflag $sflag "$gargs"
```

(I would probably not use escape quite so thoroughly these days - it is
not needed with the `-e` argument, for example - but overall, this is
one of my simpler scripts using `escape`.)

The `escape` program simply outputs its arguments, rather like `echo`
does, but it ensures that the arguments are protected for use with
`eval` (one level of `eval`; I do have a program which did remote shell
execution, and that needed to escape the output of `escape`).

```
    $ escape $var
    '"./my' 'dir"' '"./anotherdir"'
    $ escape "$var"
    '"./my dir" "./anotherdir"'
    $ escape x y z
    x y z
    $
```

I have another program called `al` that lists its arguments one per line
(and it is even more ancient: version 1.1 dated 1987-01-27T14:35:49).
It is most useful when debugging scripts, as it can be plugged into a
command line to see what arguments are actually passed to the command.

```
    $ echo "$var"
    "./my dir" "./anotherdir"
    $ al $var
    "./my
    dir"
    "./anotherdir"
    $ al "$var"
    "./my dir" "./anotherdir"
    $
```

[*Added:*
And now to show the difference between the various `"$@"` notations, here is one more example:

```
$ cat xx.sh
set -x
al $@
al $*
al "$*"
al "$@"
$ sh xx.sh     *      */*
+ al He said, '"Don'\''t' do 'this!"' anotherdir my dir xx.sh anotherdir/myfile my dir/my file
He
said,
"Don't
do
this!"
anotherdir
my
dir
xx.sh
anotherdir/myfile
my
dir/my
file
+ al He said, '"Don'\''t' do 'this!"' anotherdir my dir xx.sh anotherdir/myfile my dir/my file
He
said,
"Don't
do
this!"
anotherdir
my
dir
xx.sh
anotherdir/myfile
my
dir/my
file
+ al 'He said, "Don'\''t do this!" anotherdir my dir xx.sh anotherdir/myfile my dir/my file'
He said, "Don't do this!" anotherdir my dir xx.sh anotherdir/myfile my dir/my file
+ al 'He said, "Don'\''t do this!"' anotherdir 'my dir' xx.sh anotherdir/myfile 'my dir/my file'
He said, "Don't do this!"
anotherdir
my dir
xx.sh
anotherdir/myfile
my dir/my file
$
```

Notice that nothing preserves the original blanks between the `*` and `*/*` on the command line.  Also, note that you can change the 'command line arguments' in the shell by using:

```
set -- -new -opt and "arg with space"
```

This sets 4 options, '`-new`', '`-opt`', '`and`', and '`arg with space`'.

]

Hmm, that's quite a long *answer* - perhaps *exegesis* is the better term.
Source code for `escape` available on request (email to firstname dot
lastname at gmail dot com).
The source code for `al` is incredibly simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv != 0)
        puts(*argv);
    return(0);
}
```

That's all.  It is equivalent to the `test.sh` script that Robert Gamble showed, and could be written as a shell function (but shell functions didn't exist in the local version of Bourne shell when I first wrote `al`).

Also note that you can write `al` as a simple shell script:

```
[ $# != 0 ] && printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

The conditional is needed so that it produces no output when passed no arguments.  The `printf` command will produce a blank line with only the format string argument, but the C program produces nothing.

Comment: Is `escape` available for macOS anywhere?

Comment: You can find the code for `escape` in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `escape.c` and `escape.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  It's packaged as a library function (by default); you can create an executable by adding `-DTEST` to the command line options.  I also have a separate but roughly equivalent executable (not library function) that isn't in my SOQ repository, and which doesn't use the code from the library — contact me if you want that (see my profile).

Answer (score 157):

Note that Robert's answer is correct, and it works in `sh` as well.  You can (portably) simplify it even further:

```
for i in "$@"
```

is equivalent to:

```
for i
```

I.e., you don't need anything!

Testing (`$` is command prompt):

```
$ set a b "spaces here" d
$ for i; do echo "$i"; done
a
b
spaces here
d
$ for i in "$@"; do echo "$i"; done
a
b
spaces here
d
```

I first read about this in *Unix Programming Environment* by Kernighan and Pike.

In `bash`, `help for` documents this:

> `for NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done`
>
> If `'in WORDS ...;'` is not present, then `'in "$@"'` is assumed.

Comment: I disagree.  One has to know what the cryptic `"$@"` means, and once you know what `for i` means, it's no less readable than `for i in "$@"`.

Comment: I did not assert that `for i` is better because it saves keystrokes.  I compared the readability of `for i` and `for i in "$@"`.

Comment: this is what I was looking for -- what do they call this assumption of $@ in loops where you don't have to explicitly reference it? Is there a downside to not using $@ reference?

Answer (score 91):

For simple cases you can also use `shift`.
It treats the argument list like a queue. Each `shift` throws the first argument out and the
index of each of the remaining arguments is decremented.

```bash
#this prints all arguments
while test $# -gt 0
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: I think this answer is better because if you do `shift` in a for loop, that element is still part of the array, whereas with this `shift` works as expected.

Comment: Note that you should use `echo "$1"` to preserve the spacing in the value of the argument string.  Also, (a minor issue) this is destructive: you can't reuse the arguments if you've shifted them all away.  Often, that isn't a problem — you only process the argument list once anyway.

Comment: Agree that shift is better, because then you have an easy way to grab two arguments in a switch case to process flag arguments like "-o outputfile".

Comment: On the other hand, if you are starting to parse flag arguments, you might want to consider a more powerful script language than bash :)

Comment: I don't see how this is better in any way.  If you just quote the argument inside the loop, a `for` loop is more succinct and idiomatic.  If you don't, both `while` and `for` are broken.

Comment: This solution is better if you need some couple parameter-value, for example `--file myfile.txt` 
So, $1 is the parameter, $2 is the value and you call shift twice when you need to skip another argument

Comment: `shift` will empty out your arguments list. I would discourage its use for the same reason why you avoid mutation where possible. The `for` loop in the top-voted answer is straight forward and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 30):

You can also access them as an array elements, for example if you don't want to iterate through all of them

```
argc=$#
argv=("$@")

for (( j=0; j<argc; j++ )); do
    echo "${argv[j]}"
done
```

Comment: I believe the line argv=($@) should be argv=("$@") other wise args with spaces are not handled correctly

Comment: I confirm the correct syntax is argv=("$@"). unless you will not get last values if you have a quoted parameters. For example if you use something like `./my-script.sh param1 "param2 is a quoted param"` : 
 - using argv=($@) you will get [param1, param2],
 - using argv=("$@"), you will get [param1, param2 is a quoted param]

Answer (score 27):

Loop against $#, the number of arguments variable, works too.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
  printf "${!i}\n"
done
```

```
./test.sh 1 2 '3 4'
```

Ouput:

```
1
2
3 4
```

Comment: what does the ! mean? I see it makes it call what is stored in the ith argument as opposed to printing a number... is it an indirect reference?

Comment: @SkyScraper it's called [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and means the parameter is expanded twice, eg. from `${!i}` to `${3}` to `'3 4'`.

Comment: `!` expansion seems to be not working in ZSH (was testing in MacOS).

Answer (score 9):

Amplifying on baz's answer, if you need to enumerate the argument list with an index (such as to search for a specific word), you can do this without copying the list or mutating it.

Say you want to split an argument list at a double-dash ("--") and pass the arguments before the dashes to one command, and the arguments after the dashes to another:

```
 toolwrapper() {
   for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
     [[ "${!i}" == "--" ]] && break
   done || return $? # returns error status if we don't "break"

   echo "dashes at $i"
   echo "Before dashes: ${@:1:i-1}"
   echo "After dashes: ${@:i+1:$#}"
 }
```

Results should look like this:

```
 $ toolwrapper args for first tool -- and these are for the second
 dashes at 5
 Before dashes: args for first tool
 After dashes: and these are for the second
```

Answer (score 5):

```
aparse() {
while [[ $# > 0 ]] ; do
  case "$1" in
    --arg1)
      varg1=${2}
      shift
      ;;
    --arg2)
      varg2=true
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
}

aparse "$@"
```

Comment: As stated below the `[ $# != 0 ]` is better.

In the above, `#$` should be `$#` as in `while [[ $# > 0 ]] ...`

Answer (score 1):

**getopt** Use command in your scripts to format any command line options or
parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extract command line options & values with getopt
#
set -- $(getopt -q ab:cd "$@")
#
echo
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
case "$1" in
-a) echo "Found the -a option" ;;
-b) param="$2"
echo "Found the -b option, with parameter value $param"
shift ;;
-c) echo "Found the -c option" ;;
--) shift
break ;;
*) echo "$1 is not an option";;
esac
shift
```