# pass arguments between shell scripts but retain quotes

Tags: shell, argument-passing

How do I pass all the arguments of one shell script into another? I have tried $*, but as I expected, that does not work if you have quoted arguments.

Example:

```
$ cat script1.sh

#! /bin/sh
./script2.sh $*

$ cat script2.sh

#! /bin/sh
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

$ script1.sh apple "pear orange" banana
apple
pear
orange
```

I want it to print out:

```
apple
pear orange
banana
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/ (slightly different question - but the answer is "$@" just the same as here).

Comment: I learnt a lot from that, thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `"$@"` instead of `$*` to preserve the quotes:

```
./script2.sh "$@"
```

More info:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

> $*
>   All of the positional parameters, seen as a single word
>
> Note: "$*" must be quoted.
>
> $@
>   Same as $*, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the
>   parameters are passed on  intact, without interpretation or expansion.
>   This means, among other things, that each parameter in the argument
>   list is seen as a separate word.
>
> Note: Of course, "$@" should be quoted.

Comment: I that has issues with parenthesis - I ran into it and was unable to solve it myself.