# Parsing/passing command line arguments to a bash script - what is the difference between "$@" and "$*"?

Tags: bash, arguments, argument-passing, command-line-arguments

I am using a bash script to call and execute a `.jar` file from any location without having to constantly enter its explicit path.

The `.jar` requires additional variable parameters to be specified at execution, and as these can be anything, they cannot be hard coded into the script.

There are 3 variables in total, the first specifies 1 of 2 actions that the `.jar` is to make, the second specifies a target file to enact this action on and the third specifies the name of a file that the action is to create.

The script I am currently using is:

```
#!/bin/bash  
java -jar "C:\path\to\file.jar" "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

I know very little about bash scripting, but while searching for another answer to my woes (now fixed) I came across `"$@"` and `"$*"` when referencing command line arguments.  Doing more searching brought me to this site: [How To Wiki: How to read command line arguments in a bash script](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script), but I can't find any solid information about those arguments without having to wade through tons of advanced bash programming that is way above my head.

So now that I have rambled on forever, my question is relatively simple:

Can I replace `"$1" "$2" "$3"` with `"$@"` or `"$*"`, and if so which is the better one to use?

Also what, if any, is the difference between those commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What the difference between "$@" and "$\*" in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

Comment: My apologies - I had been google searching the difference and that didn't throw up any StackOverflow pages - I forgot to actually search StackOverflow. - sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $@ and $\* in shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`"$@"` corresponds to `"$1" "$2" "$3"` etc. `"$*"` corresponds to `"$1 $2 $3"` which you do not seem to need.

Without quotes, there is no difference, they both correspond to `$1 $2 $3` etc.

Comment: Thank you.  Between your answer and @mogul I think I now understand.  I will use `"$@"` as I feel this is the best suited option.

Answer (score 4):

`$*` is all parameters as a single word, `$@` is all parameters as individual quoted string.

I usually ends up using `"$@"`, seems to work the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

`$*` contains a single string composed of all of the arguments separated by the first character of `$IFS`.  Thus, if you set `IFS` to contain a character that cannot usefully be present in your arguments (e.g. a newline if you're passing filenames), then you can consider `$*` and `"$@"` to be functionally equivalent, though they work differently under the hood.

`$@` is essentially an array of all of the arguments.  When passed in double quotation marks (`"$@"`), the shell **individually** wraps each value in the array with double quotes (making it an odd exception to the normal rule of double quotes wrapping the entire expansion of a variable).

IIRC, the behavior of a bare `$@` without double quotes is not fully specified in the POSIX spec, so it should be considered undefined behavior.  Thus, you should never use a bare `$@` without double quotes.

BTW, if you care about System V prior to version 3, there were some [ancient quirks](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/) in how they handled `$@.`  These are largely of historical interest at this point, but they'll give you some appreciation of how the standard evolved as people ran into problems.  :-)