# what did I do wrong in initializing my array with 0 ?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

when I check the length of the array is always 1 even I give more parameters in the command line

```
for i in $*
do 
echo $i
conect[$i]=0
done

echo ${#conect}
```

Comment: `for i in "$@"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A conect
for i in "$@"
do
    echo $i
    conect[$i]=0
done
echo ${#conect[@]}
```

Explanation:

- An *associative* array (i.e. indexes can be non-numeric) must be declared with `declare -A`. You do not need this if indexes are guaranteed to be numeric.
- `${#foo}` is the length (number of characters) of a string-valued variable; `${#conect[@]}` is the length (number of elements) of an array.
- As pointed out by others, `"$@"` is better than `$*`, especially when (quoted) parameters may contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

$* create one single argument separated with IFS. that's why. Use $@

[What is the difference between "$@" and "$*" in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

**Edit**
Actually, as pointed out by @that_other_guy  and @Ruud_Helderman (thanks to you both), what I said isn't quite right.

First thing is the Mea Culpa, as this matters isn't the full solution.

But it made me wonders so here is the correct way.
The IFS difference is a fact. But this solely matters if you quote "$*" or "$@"

```
for i in "$*"
do
     echo $i
done
```

Will output every arguments on the same line whereas

```
for i in "$@"
do
     echo $i
done
```

Will do it one at a time.

Comment: `f() { for i in $*; do echo "Looping"; done; }; f 1 2 3` shows this to be false

Comment: @KuuAku Excellent advice but not the reason for OP's problem; notice there were no quotes around `$*`. See the examples in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts#2761739

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array:

```
for i in "$@"
```

Comment: Excellent advice but not the reason for OP's problem; notice there were no quotes around `$*`. See the examples in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts#2761739