# How to output every argument of a Bash function?

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I want to output all arguments of a function one by one.
The function can receive many arguments, $# is the length of arguments.

```
showArg(){
    num=$#
    for order in `seq 1 ${num}`
    do
        echo $order
    done
}
```

To execute it.

```
showArg  x1 x2 x3 
1
2
3
```

How to fix the echo statement `echo $order` to get such the following output?

```
x1
x2
x3
```

I have tried `echo $$order`.

To call every argument with "$@" in for loop can list it, but it is not the way I expected.

```
showArg(){
    for var in "$@"
    do
        echo "$var"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indirection:

```
showArg() {
  num=$#
  for order in $(seq 1 ${num}); do # `$(...)` is better than backticks
    echo "${!order}"               # indirection
  done
}
```

Using a C-style loop (as suggested by @chepner & @CharlesDuffy), the above code can be rewritten as:

```
showArg() {
  for ((argnum = 1; argnum <= $#; argnum++)); do
    echo "${!argnum}"
  done
}
```

But Bash provides a much more convenient way to do it - use `"$@"`:

```
showArgs() {
  for arg in "$@"; do  # can also be written as: for arg; do
    echo "$arg"        # or, better: printf '%s\n' "$arg"
  done
}
```

---

See also:

- [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)
- [What is the difference between $@ and $* in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts)
- [What is the difference between $(command) and `command` in shell programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming)
- On Unix & Linux StackExchange - [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Don't use `seq` at all; use a C-style `for` loop.

Comment: The first loop was just a correction to OP's original code.  I kept the loop format because OP might have had an intention to put more logic inside, not just print.

Comment: @codeforester, sure, but you don't need `seq` for that. `for ((order=1; order<=num; order++)); do ...`

Comment: Hmm. Might actually want to showcase `printf 'argument %d is %q\n' "$argnum" "${!argnum}"` or such -- that way you're printing the text in an `eval`-safe way that makes hidden characters (trailing DOS newlines or the like) visible.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an explicit loop:

```
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

Answer (score -4):

Normally, it's easier to use "$*" to represent all arguments, so :

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in $*
do
    echo $arg
done
```

In fact, this is the default behaviour for the 'for' loop, so the `in` can be left off :

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg
do
    echo $arg
done
```

If you really do want use sequence numbers, though, you can use the exclamation point syntax, which uses the value of the supplied variable as the name, so :

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$#
for order in $(seq 1 ${num})
do
    echo ${!order}
done
```

Comment: Using `$*` is *not* the default for `for`.

Comment: Try running any of your test scripts with the following argument list to observe some of the issues pointed out by prior commenters firsthand: `./yourscript "*" "hello world" $'goodbye\t\tworld'`