# convert inputs arguments to string with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How can I merge the input arguments to be as single element in array?
for example, the name of the `script` is `"run_it"` so, if I will run the script in the next way:
`run_it a b c d`

I want to create array with just only cell: `arr[0]="a b c d"`.

I thought to do it like that:
`arr=("$@")`

But I get that : `arr[0]=a  arr[1]=b arr[2]=c arr[3]=d`.
Can someone explain why it's the result and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think you want `"$*"`   -  as: `$*` is all input args

Comment: can you explain the difference between `"$*"` to `"$@"` please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts