# A confusion about ${array[*]} versus ${array[@]} in the context of a bash completion

Tags: arrays, bash, bash-completion

I'm taking a stab at writing a bash completion for the first time, and I'm a bit confused about about the two ways of dereferencing bash arrays (`${array[@]}` and `${array[*]}`).

Here's the relevant chunk of code (it works, but I would like to understand it better):

```
_switch()
{
    local cur perls
    local ROOT=${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    perls=($ROOT/perls/perl-*)
    # remove all but the final part of the name
    perls=(${perls[*]##*/})

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${perls[*]} /usr/bin/perl" -- ${cur} ) )
}
```

bash's [documentation says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell's filename expansion operators. If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word.

Now I think I understand that `compgen -W` expects a string containing a wordlist of possible alternatives, but in this context I don't understand what "${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word" means.

Long story short: `${array[*]}` works; `${array[@]}` doesn't. I would like to know why, and I would like to understand better what exactly `${array[@]}` expands into.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

(This is an expansion of my comment on Kaleb Pederson's answer -- see that answer for a more general treatment of `[@]` vs `[*]`.)

When bash (or any similar shell) parses a command line, it splits it into a series of "words" (which I will call "shell-words" to avoid confusion later).  Generally, shell-words are separated by spaces (or other whitespace), but spaces can be included in a shell-word by escaping or quoting them.  The difference between `[@]` and `[*]`-expanded arrays in double-quotes is that `"${myarray[@]}"` leads to each element of the array being treated as a separate shell-word, while `"${myarray[*]}"` results in a single shell-word with all of the elements of the array separated by spaces (or whatever the first character of `IFS` is).

Usually, the `[@]` behavior is what you want.  Suppose we have `perls=(perl-one perl-two)` and use `ls "${perls[*]}"` -- that's equivalent to `ls "perl-one perl-two"`, which will look for single file named `perl-one perl-two`, which is probably not what you wanted.  `ls "${perls[@]}"` is equivalent to `ls "perl-one" "perl-two"`, which is much more likely to do something useful.

Providing a list of completion words (which I will call comp-words to avoid confusion with shell-words) to `compgen` is different; the `-W` option takes a list of comp-words, but it must be in the form of a single shell-word with the comp-words separated by spaces.  Note that command options that take arguments always (at least as far as I know) take a single shell-word -- otherwise there'd be no way to tell when the arguments to the option end, and the regular command arguments (/other option flags) begin.

In more detail:

```
perls=(perl-one perl-two)
compgen -W "${perls[*]} /usr/bin/perl" -- ${cur}
```

is equivalent to:

```
compgen -W "perl-one perl-two /usr/bin/perl" -- ${cur}
```

...which does what you want.  On the other hand,

```
perls=(perl-one perl-two)
compgen -W "${perls[@]} /usr/bin/perl" -- ${cur}
```

is equivalent to:

```
compgen -W "perl-one" "perl-two /usr/bin/perl" -- ${cur}
```

...which is complete nonsense: "perl-one" is the only comp-word attached to the -W flag, and the first real argument -- which compgen will take as the string to be completed -- is "perl-two /usr/bin/perl".  I'd expect compgen to complain that it's been given extra arguments ("--" and whatever's in $cur), but apparently it just ignores them.

Comment: This is excellent; thanks. I really wish it blew up more loudly, but this at least clarifies why it didn't work.

Answer (score 89):

Your title asks about `${array[@]}` versus `${array[*]}` (both within `{}`) but then you ask about `$array[*]` versus `$array[@]` (both without `{}`) which is a bit confusing. I'll answer both (within `{}`):

When you quote an array variable and use `@` as a subscript, each element of the array is expanded to its full content regardless of whitespace (actually, one of `$IFS`) that may be present within that content. When you use the asterisk (`*`) as the subscript (regardless of whether it's quoted or not) it may expand to new content created by breaking up each array element's content at `$IFS`.

Here's the example script:

```
#!/bin/sh

myarray[0]="one"
myarray[1]="two"
myarray[3]="three four"

echo "with quotes around myarray[*]"
for x in "${myarray[*]}"; do
        echo "ARG[*]: '$x'"
done

echo "with quotes around myarray[@]"
for x in "${myarray[@]}"; do
        echo "ARG[@]: '$x'"
done

echo "without quotes around myarray[*]"
for x in ${myarray[*]}; do
        echo "ARG[*]: '$x'"
done

echo "without quotes around myarray[@]"
for x in ${myarray[@]}; do
        echo "ARG[@]: '$x'"
done
```

And here's it's output:

```
with quotes around myarray[*]
ARG[*]: 'one two three four'
with quotes around myarray[@]
ARG[@]: 'one'
ARG[@]: 'two'
ARG[@]: 'three four'
without quotes around myarray[*]
ARG[*]: 'one'
ARG[*]: 'two'
ARG[*]: 'three'
ARG[*]: 'four'
without quotes around myarray[@]
ARG[@]: 'one'
ARG[@]: 'two'
ARG[@]: 'three'
ARG[@]: 'four'
```

I personally usually want `"${myarray[@]}"`. Now, to answer the second part of your question, `${array[@]}` versus `$array[@]`.

Quoting the bash docs, which you quoted:

> The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell's filename expansion operators.

```
$ myarray=
$ myarray[0]="one"
$ myarray[1]="two"
$ echo ${myarray[@]}
one two
```

But, when you do `$myarray[@]`, the dollar sign is tightly bound to `myarray` so it is evaluated before the `[@]`. For example:

```
$ ls $myarray[@]
ls: cannot access one[@]: No such file or directory
```

But, as noted in the documentation, the brackets are for filename expansion, so let's try this:

```
$ touch one@
$ ls $myarray[@]
one@
```

Now we can see that the filename expansion happened after the `$myarray` exapansion.

And one more note, `$myarray` without a subscript expands to the first value of the array:

```
$ myarray[0]="one four"
$ echo $myarray[5]
one four[5]
```

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307672/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-unix/3308046#3308046) regarding how `IFS` affects the output differently depending on `@` vs. `*` and quoted vs. unquoted.

Comment: I apologize, since it's pretty important in this context, but I always meant `${array[*]}` or `${array[@]}`. The lack of braces was simply carelessness. Beyond that, can you explain what `${array[*]}` would expand into in the `compgen` command? That is, in that context what does it mean to expand the array into each of its elements separately?

Comment: To put this another way, you (like almost every source) say that `${array[@]}` is usually the way to go. What I'm trying to understand is why in this case *only* `${array[*]}` works.

Comment: It's because the wordlist supplied with the -W option must be given as a single word (which compgen then splits based on IFS).  If it's split into separate words before being handed to compgen (which is what [@] does), compgen will think that only the first one goes with -W, and the rest are regular arguments (and I think it only expects one argument, and will therefore barf).

Comment: @Gordon: Move that to an answer, and I'll accept it. That's what I really wanted to know. Thanks. (Btw, it doesn't barf in an obvious way. It silently barfs - which makes it hard to know what went wrong.)

Comment: @Telemachus - Looks like you have your answer. I'll give @Gordon a chance to add an answer or will otherwise edit my post giving him credit.

Comment: Just curious, where is the `myarray[2]`? - was not declared by some explicit reason?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753925/527038