# linux reading file line by line and passing to another program

Tags: linux, bash

I have an input file of this form:

```
Some text here
Another text here
Something else here
```

Now I want to write a linux script picks one line at a time from input file and creates a separate file which stores just the line received. After this I want to pass this file to a program (for which I have just binary file). Is it possible to write such a linux script. I am used to programming in C++ I know it is possible there. But I want to know if something like this is possible using linux script. Basically I intend to do the following:

```
   read inputfile.txt line by line
       store line read in inputFileInside.txt
       ./myprogram paramater1 inputFileInside.txt //run my C++ binary file which I usually run as (root$./myprogram parameter1 inputFileInside.txt)
      sudo sh -c \"sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\"
 exit when the input file has been read
```

Comment: You can break up "reading a file line by line and store the line in a text file" into 1. [reading a file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line), and 2. [writing text to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-on-text-file-by-bash-shell-scripting). These are easy to find existing solutions for individually, and can be combined to do what you want.

Comment: It seems like you have an answer, I was wondering though if what you are trying to do it not execute a program based on the input of a line in a file. Is the textfile being created not just a side effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read line by line like this using for loop

```
while read x
   do
     echo $x > inputFileInside.txt;
     # do whatever you want
   done < inputfile.txt
```

this may hep you to loop, $x is line read one by one till it reach end of file

```
while read x
   do
     echo $x > $2;
     ./myprogram paramater1 
      #your other command
   done < $1;
```

save the above file as any name like prog.sh, then give execute permission and run ur program with argument

```
chmod u+x prog.sh
./prog.sh inputfile.txt inputFileInside.txt
```

here $1 is inputfile.txt and $2 is inputFileInside.txt

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I dont know how to run the program like root$./myprogram parameter1 inputFileInside.txt and root$sudo sh -c \"sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\". Can you help me a little with this too

Comment: Also I want my program ./myprogram to terminate its run during each loop

Comment: inputFileInside.txt you want to overwrite

Comment: -1. Don't use this (`for x in \`cat\``)approach. This will pick one word per iteration, not one line. Check yourself on the terminal.  Use `while read x; do ... done < file`. I will undo downvote after you fix this.. Thanks.

Comment: There should not be any space between variable, = & the value. `IFS = '\n'` -> `IFS='\n'` & no, it will not fix the split by word problem here.

Comment: I am sorry I am getting "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'" error. Please correct me as to where am I going wrong

Comment: It was easy to add a trivial answer to a trivial question. But it sounded more worth to help a new coder. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do 

    echo "$line" > inputFileInside.txt

    ./myprogram paramater1 inputFileInside.txt \
    && sudo sh -c \"sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\"

done < <(cat inputfile.txt)
```

This will:

- input the file "inputfile.txt" line-by-line
- each line will be assigned to $line as it is read
- echo the line into "inputFileInside.txt" overwriting any previous information in it
- run "./myprogram ..."
- then only run "sudo ..." if "./myprogram ..." was successful
- go to next line.

Make sure there is no white space (spaces) behind the end-of-line backslash (\).