# Writing output into a file via linux script?

Tags: linux, input, scripting

I have to write a script in linux that saves one line of text to a file and then appends a new line.  What I currently have is something like:

```
read "This line will be saved to text." Text1
$Text1 > $Script.txt
read "This line will be appended to text." Text2
$Text2 >> $Script.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open and write data on text file by bash/shell scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-on-text-file-by-bash-shell-scripting)

Comment: In your output file, did you want to append content which is already on the second line, or overwrite whatever is already on the second line?

Comment: The output file is completely blank.  The output simply needs to be Text1, with Text2 underneath it.

Comment: Matt, your script is fine: you just forgot to insert the command `echo` at the start of lines 2 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main benefits of scripting is that you can automate processes. Using
`read` like you have destroys that. You can accept input from the user without
losing automation:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" != 3 ]
then
  echo 'script.sh [Text1] [Text2] [Script]'
  exit
fi
printf '%s\n' "$1" "$2" > "$3"
```

Comment: All that does is output script.sh [Text1] [Text2] [Script] for me.  I'm looking to save user input into a variable and then put that into a .dat file.   Not really looking to automate much, just looking to complete this assignment as needed.

Comment: @MattSmith this is perhaps not the right community for you. You clearly do not have even the most basic understanding of shell scripting

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a class with a very subpar teacher, which leaves me to teach myself via what i can through assignments and books.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind if the second line of your output file is overwritten (not appended) every time the script is run; this might do.

```
#!/bin/sh
output_file=output.dat
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then echo Need at least two arguments.; fi
line1=$1; line2=$2
echo $line1 > $output_file
echo $line2 >> $output_file
```

Executing the script:

```
# chmod +x foo.sh 
# ./foo.sh 
Need at least two arguments.
# ./foo.sh hello world
# cat output.dat 
hello
world
```