# ADB shell command to execute repeatedly every x interval

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Wish to ask if there is any ADB command feature  to execute same command  repeatedly after a mentioned interval. like watch command for linux

eg

```
  ls -l to execute repeatedly after every 20 second.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an unconditional loop:

```
while true; do ls -l; sleep 20; done
```

You can also look into tools like [inotifywait](https://github.com/jrummyapps/inotify-android-tools) or [fsmon](https://github.com/nowsecure/fsmon) depending on what you are trying to accomplish. You can also install busybox for Android which contains the watch command.

Comment: Thank you very much . it  works is there any way i can store generated data in text file. sorry i am new to ADB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-on-text-file-by-bash-shell-scripting

If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.