# create html file in shell script

Tags: html, shell, unix

How do we create html file in shell script?

I tried the below code

```
    echo "<html>"
    echo "<head>"
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\">"
    echo "table{background-color:#DCDCDC}"
    echo "thead {color:#708090}"
    echo "tbody {color:#191970}"
    echo "</style>"
    echo "</head>"
    echo "<body>"
    echo "<table border=\"1\">"
    echo "<thead>"
    echo "<tr width="100" bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><center><td colspan="3"><font color="#000000"><b>CONSOLIDATED RUNBOOK</b></font></center></td>"
    echo "</h4>"
    echo "</tr>"
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">APP NAME</font></th>"
    echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS</font></th>"
    echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS AS ON</font></th>"
    echo "</tr>"
 >> text.html
```

I am trying to create html file with the help of shell script. Can you please help>

Comment: If you're using `"` for your echo statements you can't use `"` *within* the string unless you escape each instance with backslash \ Why not use some kind of template system instead of this dizzying pile of `echo` statements? Using something primitive like `sed` would be better than this.

Comment: Or a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open and write data on text file by bash/shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-on-text-file-by-bash-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<style type=\"text/css\">"
echo "table{background-color:#DCDCDC}"
echo "thead {color:#708090}"
echo "tbody {color:#191970}"
echo "</style>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table border=\"1\">"
echo "<thead>"
echo "<tr width="100" bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><center><td colspan="3"><font color="#000000"><b>CONSOLIDATED RUNBOOK</b></font></center></td>"
echo "</h4>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">APP NAME</font></th>"
echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS</font></th>"
echo "<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS AS ON</font></th>"
echo "</tr>"
}>> text.html
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the quoting issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) instead:

```
cat > text.html <<EOF
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
table{background-color:#DCDCDC}
thead {color:#708090}
tbody {color:#191970}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border=\"1\">
<thead>
<tr width="100" bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><center><td colspan="3"><font color="#000000"><b>CONSOLIDATED RUNBOOK</b></font></center></td>
</h4>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">APP NAME</font></th>
<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS</font></th>
<th><col width="100"><font color="000000">STATUS AS ON</font></th>
</tr>
EOF
```