# Capture Tensorflow output in bash script

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow

The training session of a Tensorflow estimator with train and evaluate trainspec  gets occasionally killed.

I would like to resume the training session upon reading the output "Killed" (generated by tf.logging.INFO). Ideally by executing the python script again and again. Is there a short way to accomplish this?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-to-text-file-using-bash-shell-scripting

`python script.py > output.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open and write data to text file using bash/shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-to-text-file-using-bash-shell-scripting)

Comment: I don't see any duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while [ 1 ]; do

    if grep -Fxq "killed" logFile; then
       # code if found (Run your script again from here)
    fi

    #check every 5 minutes
    sleep 300

done
```

(Code adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749368/10008499 )

Comment: The `[ 1 ]` happens to work but doesn't do what you think.  You are probably looking for `while true; do`

Comment: @tripleee yeah,  true, but 1 is faster to type than true :)

Comment: On my keyboard, `[ 1 ]` is significantly more cumbersome to type than `true` and one character longer.

Answer (score 0):

Not too much experience about it, but according to my limited knowledge, you can turn to the use of **pipe** in Linux. Like this,

```
tail -f xxx.log | grep --line-buffered killed_information | while read msg ; do python train.py ; done
```

Note: killed_information should be replaced by actual error outputs of the train.py