# batch file to read a variable value from another file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Need help in creating a batch file which reads a variable value from *.txt file.

Eg.,

```
MyTxtFile.txt
VAR_A=5
VAR_B=10
```

MyBatFile.bat
**Needs to read MyTxtFile.txt and echo the value of VAR_A and VAR_B**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open and write data to text file using bash/shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-to-text-file-using-bash-shell-scripting)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I dont want to write anything to the .txt file. I need to print the value of .txt -> VAR_A using a batch file.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] of your code!

Comment: I have not tried anything as I am not so used to the batch file scripting. I dont know if this can be achieved through the batch file.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in (MyTextFile.txt) do set "%%a"`

Comment: Well I don't know of too many programming languages these days that cannot read a file. So maybe you could have started by researching that topic and attempting to code it. Ignorance or lack of experience is not an excuse for not putting in some effort.

Comment: @Aacini, you might as well post that as an answer. It is better then the two below IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how these values have been written. If you can add small "tags" before the values then it makes this job easy and done.

For example, here is a text file I made:

```
random random
VAR-A 2853
VAR-B 1039410
our code wont notice this text
```

And the batch file ran on it and outputted this:

```
2853
1039410
```

Which in the code is written as:

```
echo %varA%
echo %varB%
```

Full code is here:

```
@echo off
cls
cd %~dp0

rem Extracting lines with the tag "VAR-A/B"...

findstr "VAR-A" myfile.txt > Vara.txt
findstr "VAR-B" myfile.txt > Varb.txt

rem Setting the lines to variables...

set /P varA=<Vara.txt
set /P varB=<Varb.txt

rem Deleting temp files...

del Vara.txt
del Varb.txt

rem Now the 2 variables have tags before them, time to remove them...

set varA=%varA:~6%
set varB=%varB:~6%

rem Output:

echo %varA%
echo %varB%

pause>nul
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. This works. Is there a way to extract without the tags as the length of the variable name is not fixed.

Comment: [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/8458095) showed an easy way to measure string length. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (see the explanatory `rem` comments to learn how it works):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=MyTxtFile.txt"
rem // Determine number of lines in text file:
for /F %%C in ('^< "%_FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
rem // Read from text file:
< "%_FILE%" (
    rem // Loop over number of lines:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        rem // Clear line variable:
        set "LINE="
        rem // Read current line into variable:
        set /P LINE=""
        rem // Check whether current line is not empty:
        if defined LINE (
            rem // Apply current line as variable assignment (avoid messages for invalid ones):
            > nul 2>&1 call set "%%LINE%%"
        )
    )
)
```

Run the batch file (let us call it `assign.bat`) from a command prompt window. To show the assigned variables, type `set VAR_` into the prompt:

> ```cmd
> >>> assign.bat
>
> >>> set VAR_
> VAR_A=5
> VAR_B=10
> ```