# How to write list of executing program in a text file by bash

Tags: bash

I trying write a program with **bash** file that create a text file then write the List of running programs file in the text file. I created a text file with bash that name is test.txt, how can I write List of running programs in the text file?
I put my code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat test.txt
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to write into the file? The name of the script? The contents of the script? Something else?

Comment: I want write List of running programs in the text file

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-to-text-file-using-bash) and the man page for the command `ps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of running programs, use `ps`. Run `man ps` for details.

To redirect the output of a command to a file, use `>`.

```
ps > test.txt
```

See REDIRECTION in `man bash` for details.