# How to split a bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following command

```
mkdir -p /tmp/{A,B,C,D}
```

The above command working fine, but not the below as bash considering B,C and D as different commands:

I want something like below:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/{A,
B,
C,
D}
```

Comment: Search for *bash line continuation*.

Comment: Add \ after each line.

Comment: Why replace something beautiful with something ugly?

Comment: It looks as if this answer solve your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7316194/1606556

Comment: It is not working in a shell script. (On Redhat)

Comment: If your script is run by `sh`,  you cannot use `bash` constructs.  In a script run by `bash`, the linked answer should work. This is unrelated to the linked answer, but probably relevant for this question.

Comment: I am running using sh and ./script-name. Ut is  creating {A, folder under /tmp and B, and C} under PWD.

Comment: So, again, slowly: Don't use `sh` if you want to use `bash` constructs.  Use `bash` if you want to use `bash` constructs.

Comment: Even with bash, it is creating {A, folder under /tmp and B, and C} under PWD.

Comment: That's because whitespace is not ignored.  Remove all whitespace and you should get what you expect.

Comment: That worked! Awesome!

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, you can do this with backslashes before the newlines, but any whitespace will be regarded as significant, and the whole thing will end up rather ugly.  As an aesthetically more pleasurable workaround, you can put the directory names in an array.

```
dirs=(
    a
    b
    c
    d
  )
mkdir -p "${dirs[@]/#//tmp/}"
```

The construct `"${array[@]/#/prefix)"` reproduces the values in `array` with the prefix `prefix` added before each.

This is relatively obscure, though; unless the real directory names you are creating are very long and cumbersome, simply writing them out in longhand would be my recommendation.

As noted in comments, both arrays and `{A,B,C,D}` are Bash constructs, so will not be available if you invoke `sh` instead of `bash` (even when `sh` is a symlink to `bash`; Bash will notice, and enable POSIX mode).

Comment: Thanks tripleee. You saved my day. In fact the of the directories are very  cumbersome. Using array will make it easy.

Comment: Accept and/or upvote are the recommended ways to say thanks here.  Nudge & wink.