# git config --global user.email Wont let me change email after reinstalling

Tags: github

Hey I reinstalled Github completely with all files removed.

Now I have installed it again but when I try to set it up i face some problems.

git config --global user.email 'my@mail.com'

When I write this the terminal changes the first sign from a "$" to a ">". And no further commands work, how can I set up my email again? I did manage to link it to my account before but now when I need to do it again it does not work, Github will however let me link other emails but not this one.

Sincerely me, any help is appreciated. My class just started and I dont wanna get behind and I cant get an answer from my professors yet

Comment: Sounds like you left off the last `'`, or there's some sort of special character in the email address.

Comment: Thank's I am so stupid, we had another class in programming where we got told to not use " and instead use '. and I mixed them up! How the hell did i manage to confuse these 2 different things

Comment: `'` and `"`, to my knowledge, are both valid in a shell, as is leaving them off entirely in some cases. I suspect a simple typo in that you had only one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct command:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

Note that in your example you are using `'` instead of `"`.

Moreover you should learn that when in a shell the first character changes from  **$** to **>** it means that the command that you where entering in the previous line is still waiting for more inputs/parameters. Take a look here to more information about [line-continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316107/bash-continuation-lines)

**-- UPDATE --** 
I checked on [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) and it seems that the sugested form for this command is supposed to be:

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

However for my experience also my first solution works on UNIX at least

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the answer after checking the official documentation

Comment: And now when I spectate the manual we got it atually says to type with ' signs between the mail.

What the hell