# Process all arguments except the first one (in a bash script)

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple script where the first argument is reserved for the filename, and all other optional arguments should be passed to other parts of the script.

Using Google I found [this wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage), but it provided a literal example:

```
echo "${@: -1}"
```

I can't get anything else to work, like:

```
echo "${@:2,1}"
```

I get "Bad substitution" from the terminal.

What is the problem, and how can I process all but the first argument passed to a bash script?

Comment: To call out for anyone else confused, the wrong shebang was provided causing `"{@:2}"` to not work, which is why the correct answer matches above.

Comment: You just used default shell, which is dash on Ubuntu and many other Linuxes. In dash "${@: -1}" is interpreted as:
{parameter:-word}  - Use Default Values, and use word if the parameter is not defined or null.

So in dash "${@: -1}" results exactly the same as "$@".
To use bash just use the following first line in the script file:
#!/bin/bash

Answer (score 953, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo "${@:2}"
```

---

The following syntax:

```
echo "${*:2}"
```

would work as well, but is not recommended, because as [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one#comment11369452_9057392) already explained, that using `*`, it runs all of the arguments together as a single argument with spaces, while `@` preserves the breaks between them (even if some of the arguments themselves contain spaces). It doesn't make the difference with `echo`, but it matters for many other commands.

Comment: I just realised my shebang was bad: `#!/usr/bin/env sh` That's why I had problems. You example works fine, same as above provided, after I removed that shebang

Comment: Use `"${@:2}"` instead -- using `*` runs all of the arguments together as a single argument with spaces, while `@` preserves the breaks between them (even if some of the arguments themselves contain spaces).  The difference isn't noticeable with `echo`, but it matters for many other things.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The whole point here is to run the arguments together.  Were we passing filenames, you would be correct.  `echo` is forgiving enough to concatenate them for you; other commands might not be so nice.  Don't just use one or the other: learn the difference between `*` and `@`, and when to use each.  You should be using them about equally.  A good example of when this will be a problem: if `$3` contains a line break (`\n`), it will be replaced with a space, provided you have a default `$IFS` variable.

Comment: @Zenexer: As I understand it, the question was how to pass all but the first argument to "to other part of script", with `echo` just used as an example -- in which case they should *not* be run together. In my experience, situations where you want them run together are rare (see [this question for one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348443/a-confusion-about-array-versus-array-in-the-context-of-a-bash-comple/)), and `"$@"` is almost always what you want. Also, the problem you mention with a line break only occurs if `$@` (or `$*`) isn't in double-quotes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hmm... you're right, now that I think about it; the line break shouldn't be an issue.  I must have been thinking of something else.  However, I still have to disagree about running them together; I need to use `$*` quite often in my scripts.

Comment: FWIW, the [Google Shell Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml?showone=Quoting#Quoting) says that `"$@"` is right almost everytime, and `$*` is wrong almost everytime. There is more information why in the style guide.

Comment: What's the name for this syntax?

Comment: @Addison: It's the "parameter:offset" syntax described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: @theta that is to say, this is Bash syntax not Sh syntax !

Comment: @theta take a look: `$ sh -c 'echo 1 $1; echo 2 "$@";  echo 3 "${@:2}"; shift ; echo 4 1 $1 ; echo 5 2 "$@" ; echo 6 3 "${@:2}"' -- Мама мыла раму`

Comment: What's the point of the double quotes? `"${@:2}"` vs `${@:2}` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This was used in my x265 transpiler over at https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/e3d432edc29d8c5494bd4f5f034d25c8238fa56a/x265.sh#L23

Comment: To forward the arguments to another script, should you use `ARGS="${@:2}"; grep $ARGS` or `ARGS="${@:2}"; grep "$ARGS"` ?

Answer (score 243):

If you want a solution that also works in `/bin/sh` try

```sh
first_arg="$1"
shift
echo First argument: "$first_arg"
echo Remaining arguments: "$@"
```

`shift [n]` shifts the positional parameters *n* times. A `shift` sets the value of `$1` to the value of `$2`, the value of `$2` to the value of `$3`, and so on, decreasing the value of `$#` by one.

Comment: +1: You should probably save $1 into a variable before shifting it away.

Comment: Surprisingly `foo=shift` doesn't do what I'd expect.

Comment: I know this is old, but try `foo=$(shift)`

Comment: @raumaankidwai That doesn't work for 2 reasons:  1) `shift` (in shell) does not have any output.  It just discards `$1` and shifts everything down.  2) `$(...)` starts a subshell, which has its own local arguments.  It shifts the arguments in the subshell, which does not affect the parent

Comment: Thanks :) Is there any way to do what `somecommand "$1" "${@:2}"` does with this method (i.e. shift "inline") though?

Comment: @Anonymous not that I know that works in sh. The normal way is to save the prior arguments and then shift. The good part is that is works in every terminal I've ever checked. bash has something like what you ask, though

Comment: This answer is compatible with shellchecker

Comment: Very nice. I am looking for this POSIX compliant approach too. Together with @Anonymous, I wish we can find an one-liner which does the job like `"$1" "${@:2}"`. I try using subshells `$1 (shift; echo "$@";)`, command substitution `$1 $(shift; echo "$@";)` or compand commands `$1 { shift; echo "$@"; }`. But none of them work.

Answer (score 67):

Working in bash 4 or higher version:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0";         #"bash"
bash --version;    #"GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
```

In function:

```
echo $@;              #"p1" "p2" "p3" "p4" "p5"
echo ${@: 0};  #"bash" "p1" "p2" "p3" "p4" "p5"
echo ${@: 1};         #"p1" "p2" "p3" "p4" "p5"
echo ${@: 2};              #"p2" "p3" "p4" "p5"
echo ${@: 2:1};            #"p2"
echo ${@: 2:2};            #"p2" "p3"
echo ${@: -2};                       #"p4" "p5"
echo ${@: -2:1};                     #"p4"
```

Notice the space between ':' and '-', otherwise it means different:

> **${var:-word}** If var is null or unset, 
> word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change.
>
> **${var:+word}** If var is set, 
> word is substituted for var. The value of var does not change.

Which is described in:[Unix / Linux - Shell Substitution](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-substitutions.htm)

Comment: Your explanation helped a lot and the examples worked pretty fine when using `bash`. Nevertheless I couldn't use the "minus" elements. It didn't the work for me. Not as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams

It explains the use of `shift` (if you want to discard the first N parameters) and then [implementing Mass Usage](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage)

Answer (score 3):

Came across this looking for something else.
While the post looks fairly old, the easiest solution in bash is illustrated below (at least bash 4) using `set -- "${@:#}"` where # is the starting number of the array element we want to preserve forward:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    someVar="${1}"
    someOtherVar="${2}"
    set -- "${@:3}"
    input=${@}

    [[ "${input[*],,}" == *"someword"* ]] && someNewVar="trigger"

    echo -e "${someVar}\n${someOtherVar}\n${someNewVar}\n\n${@}"
```

Basically, the `set -- "${@:3}"` just pops off the first two elements in the array like perl's *shift* and preserves all remaining elements including the third.  I suspect there's a way to pop off the last elements as well.