# Stop Python from generating pyc files in shebang

Tags: python, shell, scripting, pyc

Is there a way to stop python from creating .pyc files, already in the shebang (or magic number if you will) of the Python script?

Not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -B
```

Comment: @VajkHermecz, no my question is much more specific.

Comment: Yeah, sorry related would have been a better term... srry

Comment: Voting to reopen because it has different implications than the duplicate.

Comment: The so called "duplicate" is a quite completely different question which does not have any answer related to shebang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if and only if, we assume the Python program runs in a somewhat POSIX compatible system (for /bin/sh), this will work:

<sub>(**IMPROVED** based on input from glglgl)</sub>

```
#!/bin/sh
"exec" "python" "-B" "$0" "$@"

# The rest of the Python program follows below:
```

Comment: Note to self: later improve with http://stackoverflow.com/a/9057699/193892

Comment: Looks great! The `"`s are for the shell and ignored by python...

Comment: But it breaks syntax highlighting...

Comment: @glglgl, haha, I though it might.  Will it appear again if the script is called something.py ? :)

Comment: What about `"exec" "python" "-B" "$0" "$@"`?

Comment: @glglgl, that might be it. Also thought about shift from the other answer. Will try later.

Comment: Yes, that would do it. But then the script has a .py extension... not nice either, but probably you'll have to die one death...

Comment: @glglgl, there, fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 7):

it is possible by putting your python interperter path directly in the she bang instead of using env.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -B
```

of course this means you lose out on some of the portability benefits of using env. There is a discussion of this issue with env on the [wikipedia Shebang page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). They use python as one of their env examples.

Answer (score 4):

According to the man page for env, you can pass `name=value` to set environment variables.  The [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE) environment variable causes Python to not write .py[co] files (the same as the `-B` flag to `python`).  So using

```
#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 python
```

should do the trick.

EDIT:

I tested this with a simple Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 python
print 1
```

then

```
$chmod +x test.py
$./test.py
1
$ls
test.py
```

(but not `test.pyc`)

Comment: For me the script just hangs...

Comment: Does it work with just `python -B script.py`?  I just tested a simple script, and it seemed to work OK to me.

Comment: me too. this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, it works with `python -B script.py `

Answer (score 3):

Alas, no. The shebang stuff is limited to giving an executable and one parameter.

So `env` tries to execute `python -B` with the given file as one argument instead of `python` with `-B` and the current file as two arguments.

I don't see a way to achieve the wanted goal.

Comment: The funny part is that Python Windows Launcher doesn't know about this limitation and passes the options (un)correctly. So for once Python on Window works better ;)