# Linux shell script for calling Java program with arguments

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I have a java program that runs as a service in linux box. I have shell script file that has the following line to start the program.

```
$EXEC -home "$JAVA_HOME" -cp "$CLASS_PATH" -outfile "$LOG_OUT" -errfile "$LOG_ERR" -pidfile "$PID" $1 $CLASS 

$CLASS_PATH has class path
$CLASS has the name of main class
EXEC="/usr/bin/jsvc"
```

I can start and stop the service using following commands

- > service myscriptfilename start
- > service myscriptfilename stop

Now I added a new argument to my program called "myflag" . It works fine on windows box . Now I am having difficulty passing the new argument to my program on my linux box using the shell script.

Now I am starting my service as

- > service myscriptfilename start myflag

I can get the value of myflag using $2 in shell script. I am trying to figure out how do I pass that to my program

How can i pass my "myflag" to my program from shell script in the following line?

```
$EXEC -home "$JAVA_HOME" -cp "$CLASS_PATH" -outfile "$LOG_OUT" -errfile "$LOG_ERR" -pidfile "$PID" $1 $CLASS
```

Comment: Are you asking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one)?

Comment: I can get the value of myflag using $2 in shell scriipt . I am trying to figure out how do I pass that to my program?

Comment: Who knows how your program parses command line arguments. There's no agreed standard, so there could be a million ways. It's *your* program after all, and you should know better than us... (You didn't even say what's `$EXEC`, for that matter; maybe it's known to all Java programmers? I'm not sure.)

Comment: I am looking for args[0].It is working fine in windows box . I am not sure where to pass that argument in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering that `$EXEC` is java executable, `$1` is your JAR, `$CLASS` is your main class. In this case just append `${@:2}` to the end of the line:

```
$EXEC -home "$JAVA_HOME" -cp "$CLASS_PATH" -outfile "$LOG_OUT" -errfile "$LOG_ERR" -pidfile "$PID" $1 $CLASS ${@:2}
```

Comment: EXEC="/usr/bin/jsvc"  and $1=start from the command  service myscriptfilename start myflag

Comment: Should work nevertheless - it has similar [execution options](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html).

Comment: @KennerDev, can you investigate which part doesn't work? Have you tried replacing `${@:2}` with `myflag`? There are two places where your parameter may not be passed: `service start` and `jsvc ...`. Try to determine which of these doesn't work.

Comment: It is at jsvc level .It is passing at service start.

Comment: @KennerDev, are you retrieving them through [DaemonContext](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/apidocs/org/apache/commons/daemon/DaemonContext.html#getArguments%28%29) ?

Comment: I am using args[0].toString().trim(); I tried hard coding the value of myflag but it is still not getting passed.