# cut command in Mac terminal lacks complement option

Tags: macos, unix, sh, text-processing, cut

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cut.1.html) cut command lacks --complement option. Any suggestions as how to get this?

I needed this as it is supported on Linux sh

My problem is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script) so I tried following to make it work

```
#!/bin/sh
EXTRA=$@
REST=`echo $EXTRA | cut -d ' ' --complement -s -f1`
echo $REST
```

Any suggestions are welcome

PS: I cannot use bash instead of sh

Comment: Since you know `cut` on OSX doesn't support `--complement`, why would you think this would work?  Can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish, as there may be a way to do it that doesn't involve using this feature of `cut` (in fact, may not use `cut` at all).

Comment: to amplify on ScottHunter 's comment, your Q needs small sample set of input, and required output from that input, your current output and exact text of any error messages. Good luck.

Comment: `EXTRA=$@` is not a useful thing to do, which makes me doubt that `cut` is the solution to what you want in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to solve this for generic use-cases with `--complement`, would be:

`brew install coreutils`

as gnu-cut is part of the pkg.

Comment: And use gcut for cut in terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can install `gcut`, the GNU version of cut using `homebrew`.

```
brew install coreutils
```

That one supports `--complement` (as well as `--output-delimiter`).

Comment: Did not work on my Mac. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191667/to-install-gnu-cut-in-osx solved it

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want all but the first argument, use `shift`.

```
#!/bin/sh
first_arg=$1
shift
printf '%s\n' "$@"  # Prints all but the first argument, one per line
```

Answer (score -1):

Using minus at the end without anything else is equivalent to --complement

```
#!/bin/sh
echo test asdf test | cut -d ' ' -s -f2-
```

For example the above example is equivalent to

```
#!/bin/sh
echo test asdf test | cut -d ' ' -s -f1 --complement
```

Comment: Adding the minus means that you are cutting the range from 2 until the end, so this just happens to work if you are dropping all columns to the left of an index but not if you are dropping one specific column in the middle.