# ash: Remove last param

Tags: shell, sh, busybox, ash

I'm in a busybox environment which only has sh and ash available.

Now I'm doing a script in which I need to pass all but the last param to ln.

So far it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/ash
TARGET="/some/path/"

for last; do true; done

ln $@ $TARGET$last
```

Obviously now I pass the last param twice, first unmodified then modified with $TARGET in front of it.

How can I get rid of the last param in $@?

Comment: Try modifying the solution in this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script.

Comment: @namokarm echo "${@:2}" just cuts off the first characters of the first param, how would I modify it to remove the last param?

Comment: I can't try it atm, but could you try this 
echo "${@:1:$#-1}"

Comment: @namokarm That gives me "Illegal number: 17�-1"

Comment: Did you try running this  echo "${@:1:$#-1}" or as a part of your script?

Comment: @namokarm As part of my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
last_arg () {
shift $(($#-1))
echo "$@"
}
last=$(last_arg "$@")
echo "all but last = ${@%$last}"
```

Comment: this had weird effects, with some param lists it would cut of the last 2 plus the last character of the param before that, and with others it did nothing. But it made me think of a working solution.

Comment: @Diskutant give sample of param lists where it cut the last char and another where it do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Got a working solution now, it's not that nice, and it shifts the params, but until a better solution comes up this will do it.

```
for last; do true; done
while [[ "$1" != "$last" ]] ; do
    args="$args $1"
    shift
done

echo $args
```