# How to pass arguments from command line after case matched

Tags: linux, bash

Currently trying to write a looping case script that matches different cases to execute scripts. However, I am unsure as off how to pass arguments into the cases after the cases have been matched! This is what I have but does not work. I am new to bash so thanks for any help in advance!

Edit:
I have changed to `${@:2}` but when I enter `delete text.txt` or `open x`, I get `Error` returned. I think the program is unable to read the rest of the input.

I run the looping script in the command line -

```
./loop.sh
```

I then type

```
open John
```

The script `open.sh` runs to make a new directory with the name of the following argument. It works manually - I type `./open.sh John` and a directory named `John` is created. Here I wish to type `open John` which enters the loop, matches the `open` case and then puts `John` after the command to run the script and make the directory.

If I type `./loop.sh`

Then `open` it does match it. But cannot run the script because the script requires an argument

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        read request
        case $request in
         open)
                 ./open.sh "${@:2}"
                ;;
        delete)
                 ./delete.sh "${@:2}"
                ;;
        *)
           echo "Error"
                exit 1
       esac
done
```

Comment: It looks like this is what you're looking for: [process all arguments except the first one in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: I would suggest not to load fine into loop , rather do some other logic.

Comment: @j4ckofalltrades does not appear to work but thank you for the suggestion. Appreciated!

Comment: The problem description "does not work" is not sufficient. What exactly does not work? Please [edit] your question and show the command line you use to run your script, the input you enter and the actual and expected output or result. If necessary, explain what exactly is wrong. If you get any error message, copy&paste the error message to the question. If a suggested solution does not work, add to your question how exactly you used the suggestion (what exactly you did/changed) and the corresponding result/output/error.

Comment: Instead of `while true; do read request...`, just do `while read request; do ...`

Comment: `echo "Error" >&2`.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Comment: @Bodo I hope the edit is clearer!

Comment: @WilliamPursell unfortunately this did not make a difference - It still returns 'error'. (I have added in the stderr - thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the command line entered as `request` into separate arguments. One way to do this is the `set` shell builtin, see e.g. the end of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
        read request
        # split into positional parameters $1, $1, ...
        set -- $request
        # the first word is now $1
        case "$1" in
        open)
                ./open.sh "${@:2}"
                ;;
        delete)
                ./delete.sh "${@:2}"
                ;;
        *)
           echo "Error" >&2
                exit 1
       esac
done
```

Comment: Oh I understand! I'll have a read up about it. Thank you so much, you've been very helpful

Comment: @Michelle If this answer fixes your problem you can accept it.