# what does ${@:3} means in bash?

Tags: bash

In the `dist_train.sh` from [mmdetection3d](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection3d/blob/master/tools/dist_train.sh), what does `${@:3}` do at the last line ?

I can't understand its bash grammar.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONFIG=$1
GPUS=$2
NNODES=${NNODES:-1}
NODE_RANK=${NODE_RANK:-0}
PORT=${PORT:-29500}
MASTER_ADDR=${MASTER_ADDR:-"127.0.0.1"}

PYTHONPATH="$(dirname $0)/..":$PYTHONPATH \
python -m torch.distributed.launch \
    --nnodes=$NNODES \
    --node_rank=$NODE_RANK \
    --master_addr=$MASTER_ADDR \
    --nproc_per_node=$GPUS \
    --master_port=$PORT \
    $(dirname "$0")/train.py \
    $CONFIG \
    --seed 0 \
    --launcher pytorch ${@:3}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is standard [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:offset}`
> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to
> length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character
> specified by offset. If parameter is `@`, an indexed array
> subscripted by `@` or `*`, or an associative array name, the
> results differ as described below. If length is omitted, it expands
> to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character
> specified by offset and extending to the end of the value. length
> and offset are arithmetic expressions (see Shell Arithmetic).

[...]

> If parameter is `@`, the result is length positional parameters
> beginning at offset. A negative offset is taken relative to one
> greater than the greatest positional parameter, so an offset of -1
> evaluates to the last positional parameter. It is an expansion error
> if length evaluates to a number less than zero.
>
> The following examples illustrate substring expansion using positional parameters:
>
> ```
> $ set -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h
> $ echo ${@:7}
> 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h
> $ echo ${@:7:0}
>
> $ echo ${@:7:2}
> 7 8
> $ echo ${@:7:-2}
> bash: -2: substring expression < 0
> $ echo ${@: -7:2}
> b c
> $ echo ${@:0}
> ./bash 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h
> $ echo ${@:0:2}
> ./bash 1
> $ echo ${@: -7:0}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Bash Hackers wiki on the Positional Parameters syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#range_of_positional_parameters), the `${@:3}` means any script argument starting at the third argument.

In other words, the `${@:3}` syntax means "all arguments EXCEPT the first and second". A [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script) exists from which you can infer the same conclusion.

A contrived example:

```
foo() {
    echo "${@:3}"
}
foo a b c d e f g h i
# prints c d e f g h i
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
In bash this is one kind of something called variable expansion. In this case the variable is `$@` representing all the parameters received by the program (or function), as a string.

Using the colon `:` means that you want to 'expand' `$@` to a subset of it's original string (ie. a substring).
So in this instance you're saying give me the string representing all the incoming parameters, but start from the 3rd one.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer *per se* but in case you're looking for a POSIX-compatible equivalent for BASH's `${@:3}` here you are:

```bash
$(printf '%s' "$*" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)"
```

Here's how it works:

`printf '%s' "$*"` take all passed parameters as string

`tr -s ' '` replace multiple whitespace with single ones

`cut -d ' ' -f 3-` split into "fields" by space and take all starting from 3 (included)

If it could be shorter/better - please share ;)

Comment: Probably safer to avoid reparsing: `e1=$1; e2=$2; shift; shift` now `"$@"` gives the same as bash's `"${@:3}"` and the first two values are still available if needed. Consider applying your code after: `set -- 'v1' ' v 2 ' '  v  3  ' '    v    4    '`