# How to run python script with a specific working directory?

Tags: python, bash

**tl;dr**: What I am looking for:

```
python3.5 --working-dir=~/company_repo/ ~/company_repo/something.py
```

---

In the codebase I am working on, there are some scripts that help with various tasks - let's call them company scripts. These are owned by the teams responsible for those features.

Next to the codebase, I have my own repo with my own helper scripts - let's call them my scripts. Now my scripts are just bash scripts, and call a sequence of the python company scripts:

###### `myscript.sh`

```bash
python3.5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper1.py someargument
python3.5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper2.py
```

Problem is, some of the company scripts rely on being run within the company repo, because they call git commands, or load other files by relative path. I cannot change the company scripts right now.

Is there a way to tell the python runtime to use different working directory? I do not want to do `cd ~/company_repo` in my bash scripts.

Comment: Note that I did a lot of googling, but all results were showing how to set working dir from WITHIN a python script, whereas I want to set it from outside, without changing the script.

Comment: Not the best thing we can do but I do something like `cd ~/company_repo/ && python3.5 executable.py`

Comment: @PranjalDoshi I disagree, that is a perfect suggestion. You should post it as an answer. Maybe make it to `(cd...  &  python... ) ` using the parantheses will not alter the current working dir of the bash script

Comment: You can wrap `cd...  &  python...` in a bash file and push it in one of folder in PATH, something like: `cd $1 && python3 $2`. If additional arguments for python is desired, maybe this can help: [Process all arguments except the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057387/process-all-arguments-except-the-first-one-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a pythonic way but we can use the bash to mimic the same behavior.

you can try as suggested by @FlyingTeller

```
(cd company_repo && python3 helper.py)
```

or you can also use `pushd` & `popd`

```
pushd company_repo && python3 helper.py && popd
```

Comment: Yeah, the second is what I am using after I failed to find a command line argument/env variable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `env --chdir`:

```
env --chdir=$dir python3.5 $dir/scripts/helper1.py someargument
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a script like this one

```
#! /bin/bash
if cd company_repo
then
    exec /usr/local/bin/python3.5 "$@"
fi
```

name it `~/bin/python3.5`, make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/bin/python3.5
```

be sure `~/bin` is before the directory containing the real `pythno3.5` in your `PATH`:

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

then when you run (*that would remain unchanged*):

```
python3.5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper1.py someargument
python3.5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper2.py
```

it will change the directory and then use the real `python3.5` to execute it.

Comment: Upvote for the out of the box approach, but I used the pushd solution in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function (called `python3-5`)：

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
python3-5()(
    cd "$(dirname "$1")"
    python3.5 "$@"
)

python3-5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper1.py someargument
python3-5 ~/company_repo/scripts/helper2.py
```