# Cannot tar array of files with spaces inside filename inside bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, tar, quoting

I have bash script `my_tar.sh` which calls `tar czf output.tgz` on 3 files with filename spaces passed from array: `file`, `file 2` and `file 3`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a files_to_zip

files_to_zip+=(\'file\')
files_to_zip+=(\'file 2\')
files_to_zip+=(\'file 3\')

echo "tar czf output.tgz "${files_to_zip[*]}""
tar czf output.tgz "${files_to_zip[*]}" || echo "ERROR"
```

Though three files exist, when `tar` is ran inside the script, it ends with error. However when I literally run `echo` output (which is the same as next command of `my_tar.sh`) inside bash console, `tar` runs ok:

```
$ ls
file  file 2  file 3  my_tar.sh
$ ./my_tar.sh
tar czf output.tgz 'file' 'file 2' 'file 3'
tar: 'file' 'file 2' 'file 3': Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
ERROR
$ tar czf output.tgz 'file' 'file 2' 'file 3'
$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `declare -p files_to_zip`

Comment: @Cyrus Oh, I see. This: [@ and *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348443/a-confusion-about-array-versus-array-in-the-context-of-a-bash-comple) explained my confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you escape the `'` and thereby add it to the file name instead of using it to quote the string:

```
files_to_zip+=(\'file 2\')
```

vs

```
files_to_zip+=( 'file 2' )
```

Also, it generally is advisable to use `@` instead of the asterisk (`*`) to reference all array elements, since the asterisk will not be interpreted when quoted (-> http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html, Example 27-7) .

Also also I assume your intention was to put quotes in the string when printing out the array elements. To do so, you need to escape the quotes.

```
echo "tar czf output.tgz \"${files_to_zip[@]}\""
```

Your fixed script would look like

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a files_to_zip

files_to_zip+=( 'file' )
files_to_zip+=( 'file 2' )
files_to_zip+=( 'file 3' )

echo "tar czf output.tgz \"${files_to_zip[@]}\""
tar czf output.tgz "${files_to_zip[@]}" || echo "ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem to tar and compress many directories, files and programs on a MacOS system and make it work by decompressing all of those files on another computer. I don't know if it will help, but, after many tests I did it.
Here is the script that I used, and it worked fine to deal with spaces on folders, .app  and every thing.
I had to add doble doble quotes and also quotes to the vars:
This compress and bzip2 it all.
Maybe can help some one.

```html
#!/bin/bash

## Routes
epic=""/Applications/Epic\ Games\ Launcher.app""
urshared=""/Users/Shared/Epic\ Games""
wwise=""/Applications/Wwise\ Launcher.app""
ww1170=""/Applications/Audiokinetic/Wwise\ 2022.1.7.8290""
ww1171=""/Library/Application\ Support/Audiokinetic/Wwise\ 2022.1.7.8290""
ww202=""/Applications/Audiokinetic/Wwise\ 2022.1.4.8202""
ww202b=""/Library/Application\ Support/Audiokinetic/Wwise\ 2022.1.4.8202""
libframe=""/Library/Frameworks""
advgame=""/Applications/Audiokinetic/Wwise\ Adventure\ Game\ 2022.1.0.230""
unityhub=""/Applications/Unity\ Hub.app""
uniyed2018=""/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.4.17f1""
unityed2020=""/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.40f1""
fmod=""/Applications/FMOD\ Studio.app""

tar -cjf franza.tgz "$epic" "$urshared" "$wwise" "$ww1170" "$ww1171" "$ww202" "$ww202b" "$libframe" "$advgame" "$unityhub" "$uniyed2018" "$unityed2020" "$fmod"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Besides your "double double quotes" are just void. You could remove them. And all that remains are escaped spaces, but for static, hard coded, files. Correct answer was already given. Please, be sure when answering old questions to bring something new that wasn't already been said years ago.