# How do you add spaces for aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides and/or --tags?

Tags: bash, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am trying to get spaces into the tags parameter for the aws cli and it works if I hardcode it but not if I use bash variables. What is going on and how do I fix it?

**This works with out spaces:**

```
aws cloudformation deploy  \
      --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
      --stack-name my-new-stack \
      --tags Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2
```

**This works with out spaces but with variables:**

```
tags="Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2" 
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags $tags
```

**This works with spaces:**

```
aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags 'Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2'
```

**This does not work, spaces and variables:**

```
tags="'Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2'"

aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags $tags
```

**Attempting to fix bash expansion, also does not work, spaces and variables:**

```
tags="'Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2'"

aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags "$tags"
```

**Attempting to fix bash expansion, also does not work, spaces and variables:**

```
tags="'Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2'"

aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags "$(printf '%q' $tags)"
```

Error:

> Invalid parameter: Tags Reason: The given tag(s) contain invalid
>   characters (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameter; Request ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing some ideas from https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3274 I was able to get this working by doing the following

```
    deploy=(aws cloudformation deploy 
            ...
            --tags $(cat tags.json | jq '.[] | (.Key + "=" + .Value)'))

    eval $(echo ${deploy[@]})
```

With a tags.json file structure of

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Name With Spaces",
        "Value": "Value With Spaces"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Foo",
        "Value": "Bar"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
tags=('Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2')

aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags "${tags[@]}"
```

Comment: Does not work for `create-stack` (instead of `deploy`), returns error: 
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in Tags[0]: "Key"
Missing required parameter in Tags[0]: "Value"
Unknown parameter in Tags[0]: "Key1", must be one of: Key, Value

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
tags="'Key1=Value1' 'Key Two=Value2'"

aws cloudformation deploy  \
  --template-file /path_to_template/template.json \ 
  --stack-name my-new-stack \
  --tags "$tags"
#        ^     ^
#     double quotes
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022-02 this was still an issue described

[here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3274)

[here also](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4055)

[and a little here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3445)

@esolomon is correct you have to array expansion. His answer which works just fine:

```sh
deploy=(aws cloudformation deploy 
            ...
            --tags $(cat tags.json | jq '.[] | (.Key + "=" + .Value)'))

eval $(echo ${deploy[@]})
```

The actual problem is a result of the shell environment (`bin/bash` here) that is used in combination with how python cli executable's handling of values. Since the `aws cloudformation deploy` does not standardize the input but expects the shell program to standardize array input this was causing my problem.

So my errors with the `--debug` flag turned on produced the first response which is the error and the second response is the expected input into `aws cloudformation deploy`

Error input:

> 2022-02-10 17:32:28,137 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['cloudformation', 'deploy', '--region', 'us-east-1', ..., '--parameter-overrides', **'PARAM1=dev PARAM2=blah', '--tags', "TAG1='Test Project' TAG2='blah'...",** '--debug']

Expected input:

> 2022-02-10 17:39:40,390 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['cloudformation', 'deploy', '--region', 'us-east-1', ..., '--parameter-overrides', **'PARAM1=dev', 'PARAM2=blah', '--tags', "TAG2='Test Project'", 'TAG2=blah',**..., '--debug']

I was unexpectedly sending in a string instead of array of strings this error resulted in several errors depending on how I sent it:
example TAG: `TAG1=Test Project`

> ['Project'] value passed to --tags must be of format Key=Value

- the means [IFS needs to be set to something other than the default `' \t\n'`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS#:%7E:text=The%20IFS%20variable%20is%20used,is%20space%2C%20tab%2C%20newline), solution below

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'Test Project Tag2=Value2 ...' at 'tags.1.member.value' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 256

- **the error starts after the first `=`** this error means that I am sending in one long string instead of array items, as seen here when doing `[*]` instead of `[@]` `aws cloudformation deploy ... --tags "${TAGS[*]}"` [diff between `[*]` and `[@]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348659/3870664)

To fix this the most important thing was that IFS needed to be set to anything other than `' \t\n'` and secondly I still need to do array expansion with `[@]` and could not input a string. The `--parameter-overrides` for me did not have this problem even though similar variable loading BECAUSE it did not have a string.

This was my solution, my params and tags input is all over the place, spaces + sometimes arrays + bad indenting thus the `sed`:

```sh
export IFS=$'\n'
# Build up the parameters and Tags
PARAMS=($(jq '.[] | .ParameterKey + "=" + if .ParameterValue|type=="array" then .ParameterValue | join(",") else .ParameterValue end ' parameters-${environment}.json \
    | sed -e 's/"//g' \
    | sed -e $'s/\r//g' | tr '\n' ' '))
TAGS=("$(jq -r '.[] | [.Key, .Value] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"'  tags-common.json)")
TAGS=($TAGS "$(jq -r '.[] | [.Key, .Value] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' tags-${environment}.json)")

aws cloudformation deploy \
    --region "${REGION}" \
    --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
    --template-file "stack-name-cfn-transform.yaml" \
    --stack-name "stack-name-${environment}" \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
    --parameter-overrides "${params[@]}" \
    --tags "${TAGS[@]}" \
    --profile "${PROFILE}"
```

parameters file

```json
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "Environment",
        "ParameterValue": "dev"
    }
]
```

tags file - both common and environment specific tag files have same format

```json
[
    {
        "Key": "TAG1",
        "Value": "Test Project"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Name With Spaces",
        "Value": "Value With Spaces"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Foo",
        "Value": "Bar"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this scenario using options below:

`"scripts": { "invoke": "sam ... --parameter-overrides \"$(jq -j 'to_entries[] | \"\\(.key)='\\\\\\\"'\\(.value)'\\\\\\\"''\\ '\"' params.json)\"" }`

Or

`sam ... --parameter-overrides "$(jq -j 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)='\\\"'\(.value)'\\\"''\ '"' params.json)"`