# Preserving Spaces in Array Elements with Mixed Strings and Command-Line Flags

Tags: arrays, string, bash, expansion

I dislike bash, I dislike it a lot,

because I'm fighting with array expansion, believe it or not.

I'm using an array to pass arguments to hyperfine, which expects commands as strings,

```bash
commands+=("$top_dir/bin/whisper --model medium.en --language en --input {input_file}")
hyperfine --warmup 3 --runs 10 --show-output \
        --parameter-list input_file $ihm_files \
        --export-json $results_path/bench/json/$device/group.json --export-markdown $results_path/bench/md/$device/group.md \
        "${commands[@]}"
```

but no matter how I unpack it, spaces separate the things:

```
`error: unexpected argument --model...
```

the array contains both flags for the bench and the commands being run:

```bash
echo_python() {
...
    command="$command {input_file} --device $device --model $model_name --model_dir $model_directory --output_dir $results_path/output/$device/$contender --output_format json"
    echo -e "${command}"
}
...
commands=()
commands+=(--prepare "use_venv ${top_dir}/original")
commands+=("'$(echo_python ${top_dir}/original whisper ${model_path} medium.en $device)'")
```

but anyway I expand it, the commands come undone!

Let me list what I've tried and failed, although it does sting:

1. I've obviously tried to pass it as a string

```bash
commands+=("$top_dir/bin/whisper --model medium.en --language en --input {input_file}")
```

2. I've tried unpacking with a [wildcarded array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348443/a-confusion-about-array-versus-array-in-the-context-of-a-bash-comple), but then its contents became one string as the error will display:

```bash
hyperfine --warmup 3 --runs 10 --show-output \
        --parameter-list input_file $ihm_files \
        --export-json $results_path/bench/json/$device/group.json --export-markdown $results_path/bench/md/$device/group.md \
        "${commands[*]}"
```

```bash
`error: unexpected argument '--prepare use_venv ... --cpu'' found`
```

3. I've even tried escaping quotes in this stupid way, but it was same expansion as before, to my growing dismay.

```bash
commands+=(--prepare "\'use_venv ${top_dir}/original\'")
```

4. I tried escaping the spaces but nothing changed. I thought that would solve it? expansion is strange

I want to use an array, so I can arbitrarily add more commands,

but no matter how it's unpacked, I cannot meet this demand.

I got a little closer once I unquoted the substitution:

```
$results_path/bench/md/$device/group.md \
        ${commands[@]}
```

now the `--prepare` flag is recognized, though that's not quite the solution...

so is there anyway to preserve spaces in [this array of strings and params](https://github.com/skewballfox/Whisper-bench/blob/26807f7c7413619f4b893942e14a6d2fa6f48286/bench.sh#L228),

so that I might put this to bed and finish this program?

### EDIT

5. I tried [changing IFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781051/11019565) and testing the entries with this:

```bash
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$""
    commands+=(--prepare "use_venv $top_dir/original")
    commands+=("$(echo_python ${top_dir}/original whisper ${model_path} medium.en $device)")

    ...
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"
    for command in "${commands[@]}"; do
        echo $command '|'
    done
```

the spacing seems correct but hyperfine complains that the number of `--prepare`s mismatches commands what gives?

```
--prepare |
use_venv /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/original |
whisper {input_file} --device cpu --model medium.en --model_dir /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/models --output_dir /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/results/output/cpu/original --output_format json |
--prepare |
use_venv /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/ctranslate2 |
whisper-ctranslate2 {input_file} --device cpu --model medium.en --model_dir /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/models --output_dir /home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/results/output/cpu/ctranslate2 --output_format json |
--prepare |
true |
/home/Daedalus/Workspace/whisper-bench/bin/whisper --model medium.en --language en --input {input_file} --cpu |
Error: The '--prepare' option has to be provided just once or N times, where N is the number of benchmark commands.
```

Comment: The hyperfine's README shows `hyperfine 'hexdump file' 'xxd file'`, so each command should be a single parameter. `commands+=(--prepare "use_venv ${top_dir}/original")` (no final vertical bar!) and `commands+=("$top_dir/bin/whisper --model medium.en --language en --input {input_file}")` should work with `"${commands[@]}"`. I'm not sure what you mean by `{input_file}`, though.

Comment: {input_file} is for hyperfine's `--parameter-list`, which in this case is comma separated wav files for testing the transcriptionists

Comment: How exactly would you run the command directly, i.e. without first storing parts of it in an array? If you can show that, it should be easy to translate it into a version that uses an array. Also, do *not* use `echo somecommand` to see what a command looks like; `echo` shows what it looks like *after* quotes and escapes have been parsed and removed, which can be very misleading.

Comment: The [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is just overcomplicating things. Use an array _with correct quoting_ around each array member and you will be fine.