# How can I know if a string contains only one or several words in Bash?

Tags: string, bash

When I get the content of an array in a string, I have the 2 solutions bellow :

```
$ a=('one' 'two')
$ str1="${a[*]}" && str2="${a[@]}"
```

After, of course, I can reuse my string on the code
but how can I know if my variable has only one or several words?

Comment: Minimal research would have found numerous [detailed explanations](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

Comment: When I wrote this post, the title isn't the actual title: "The difference between ${array[*]} and ${array[@]} in Bash ?". And for me, there is no confusion between ${array[*]} and ${array[@]}. A person has changed my title and **she hasn't read** my question, that is "How can I know if my variable has only one or several words?"

Comment: Your question was posed as a question about array expansion using `[*]` and `[@]`. The linked question explains the difference -- and if you want to know the number of array elements, use `${#a[@]}`. If you want to count words in the expanded array after expansion, I guess the easiest way would be to turn it back into an array and count elements. `s="${a[@]}"; b=($s); echo "${#b[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the contents of the array are concatenated to a single string and assigned to the variable. The only difference is what is used to join the elements. With `${a[*]}`, the first character of `IFS` is used. With `${a[@]}`, a single space is always used.

```
$ a=(one two)
$ IFS="-"
$ str1="${a[*]}"
$ str2="${a[@]}"
$ echo "$str1"
one-two
$ echo "$str2"
one two
```

When expanding `$str1` or `$str2` without quoting, the number of resulting words is entirely dependent on the current value of `IFS`, regardless of how the variables were originally defined. `"$str1"` and `"$str2"` each expand, of course, to a single word.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @chepner's great answer: the difference between `${arr[*]}` and `${arr[@]}` is very similar to the difference between `$*` and `$@`.  You may want to refer to this post which talks about `$*` and `$@`:

[What's the difference between $@ and $* in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307672/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-unix)

As a rule of thumb, it is always better to use `"$@"` and `"${arr[@]}"` than their unquoted or `*` counterparts.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is *better* to use `@`, rather it is more likely that `@` does what you want.

Comment: One important difference (although I think it is fixed in a recent Bash version) : `"$@"` expands to nothing if there are no arguments, and `"${arr[@]}"` causes an error if the array is empty.  This is so annoying...  You have to use `${arr[@]+"${arr[@]}"}` instead to get the same result (often useful in `for` loops, for instance).

Comment: @Fred I can't seem to reproduce any error with `"${foo[@]}"` for `foo` either unset or empty, at least not in `bash` 3.2 or 4.4. Was it a regression in an earlier 4.x release?

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I forgot to mention that this was with `set -u`.  I use that systematically in all my scripts, so for me what `set -u` does is my "mental default".  `"$@"` expands without errors even when there are no positional parameters under `set -u`.

Answer (score 0):

`"${a[*]}"` expands to one string for all entries together and `"${a[@]}"` expands to one string per entry.

Assume we had a program `printParameters`, which prints for each parameter (`$1`, `$2`, and so on) the string `my ... parameter is ...`.

```
>_ a=('one' 'two')

>_ printParameters "${a[*]}"
my 1. parameter is one two

>_ printParameters "${a[@]}"
my 1. parameter is one
my 2. parameter is two
```

If you would expand the array manually, you would write
`${a[*]}` as `"one two"` and
`${a[@]}` as `"one" "two"`.

There also differences regarding `IFS` and so on (see other answers). Usually `@` is the better option, but `*` is *way* faster – use the latter one in cases where you have to deal with large arrays and don't need separate arguments.

**By the way:** The script `printParameters` can be written as

```
#! /bin/bash
argIndex=0
for argValue in "$@"; do
    echo "my $((++i)). argument is $argValue"
done
```

It's very useful for learning more about expansion by try and error.