# How to use the S-output-modifier with Unix/Linux command ps?

Tags: unix, ps

The command

```
ps -o time -p 21361
```

works; however what I need is the running time of the process including **all
the children**. For example, if 21361 is a bash script, which calls other scripts,
then I want the total running time, including the running time of all children.

Now the ps documentation lists the "OUTPUT MODIFIER":

```
S

Sum up some information, such as CPU usage, from dead child processes into their parent. This is useful for examining a system where a parent process repeatedly forks off short-lived children to do work.
```

Sounds just right. Unfortunately, there is no specification of the ps-syntax, so
I have no clue where to place the "S"! For hours now I tried many combinations, but
either I get syntax errors, or "S" makes nothing. And on the Internet you find only
very basic information about ps (and always the same), specifically the "S" modifier
I couldn't find mentioned anywhere, and also nobody ever explains the syntax of ps.

Comment: but won't the parent process be the longest running process of them all? Are you deliberately trying 'double-count' the childern process time? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but it might be that ps is somewhat buggy in this respect. Try this here:

```
$ ps p 12104 k time
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
12104 ?        Ss    16:17 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

$ ps p 12104 k time S
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
12104 ?        Ss   143:16 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

This is using the BSD options for ps. It works on my machine, however you get an extra header row and extra columns. I would cut them away using tr and cut:

```
$ ps p 12104 k time S | tail -n 1 | tr -s '[:space:]' | cut -d ' ' -f 4
143:39
$ ps p 12104 k time | tail -n 1 | tr -s '[:space:]' | cut -d ' ' -f 4
16:17
```

Comment: Thanks!! I would say, ps is definitely buggy: your combination seems **the only one** to achieve the result --- everything else, which should be equivalent or more powerful (cutting away for example the superfluous output) doesn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. If my or Jonathan's answer fulfills your question, don't forget to mark them as answers.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS X (10.7, Lion) the manual page says:

> `-S`      Change the way the process time is calculated by summing all exited children to their parent process.

So, I was able to get output using:

```
$ ps -S -o time,etime,pid -p 305
     TIME     ELAPSED   PID
  0:00.12 01-18:31:07   305
$
```

However, that output was not really any different from when the '`-S`' option was omitted.

I tried:

```
$ ps -S -o time,etime,pid -p 305
     TIME     ELAPSED   PID
  0:00.14 01-18:43:59   305
$ time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1m count=100k
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
107374182400 bytes transferred in 15.374440 secs (6983941055 bytes/sec)

real    0m15.379s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m15.034s
$ ps -S -o time,etime,pid -p 305
     TIME     ELAPSED   PID
  0:00.14 01-18:44:15   305
$
```

As you can see, the 15 seconds of system time spent copying `/dev/zero` to `/dev/null` did not get included in the summary.

At this stage, the only way of working out what the '`-S`' option does, if anything, is to look at the source.  You could look for `sumrusage` in the FreeBSD version, for example, at [FreeBSD](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/8/bin/ps/print.c?revision=219943&view=markup).