# How do I pass $@ as a single argument to another command in a bash function?

Tags: bash

I have this as a bash function:

```
function gits() {
  git grep -i -n --color $@ -- $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel);
}
```

If I run this:

```
gits def add_crumb
```

I want:

```
git grep -i -n --color "def add_crumb" -- $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

Comment: See [How to iterate over arguments in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225) for an extensive discussion of `$@` vs `$*` vs `"$@"` vs `"$*"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of `$@` is specifically to split it into individual arguments.  Use `"$*"` if you don't want that.  (Yes, with the double quotes; you should have them in `"$@"` as well, actually.)