# How to write a bash script to execute a different command with additional arguments?

Tags: linux, bash

When called as `my_cmd -a -b ... c`,

the script will finally call program `a` with addition parameters:

```
a -additional -a -b ... c
```

How can I write such a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a -additional "$@"` [pad to 30 characters]

Comment: Always use `"$@"` to relay arguments.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler ,why is `""` necessary?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: thanks, forgot the doublequotes, edited the answer. Explanation [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage)

Comment: Because you get different results with `$@` and `"$@"` when there are spaces inside the arguments.  See [How to iterate over arguments in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/).

Answer (score 1):

Given that the additional arguments come immediately after the command, it is trivial:

```
exec a -additional "$@"
```

The `exec` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If the command's name "a" has to be also taken from the my_cmd's parameters:

```
"${1:1}" -additional "$@"
```