# Passing variables in arguments

Tags: bash, find, filenames, arguments

Im looking how to pass an argument in a find file function
this should give all the sh files in my computer first the basename  a tab with then all
the directories
For example `myBashfile.sh *sh`
at the moment i have this:
while getopts b opt
 do
      case $opt in
          b) find / -name  $OPTARG -printf "%f\n"-print 2>/dev/null    ;;
          esac
done
wich gives only the output of 
test1.sh
test60.sh
anothertest.sh

but i need as output: (with a tab)
    test1.sh          /home/directory5/directory6
    test60.sh         /home/directory50/directory6
    anothertest.sh    /home/directory5/directory6

can anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried? You should read this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Comment: Tangentially, the shell is going to try to expand `*sh` by looking in your current directory before it is passed to your script. Start with `myBashfile.sh "*sh"` so that your script actually sees the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/256225/1367611) and the [manuals](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST). In brief:

```
$1 # means the 1st argument
$2 # means the 2nd argument
$@ # means all arguments
```