# Accepting multiple arguments through sh script [UNIX]

Tags: bash, unix, arguments, sh

What I'm trying to do here is allow users to enter multiple arguments (filenames) and send them to a recycle bin I have created
the sh script is called "sh safe_rm"

so I would do this:

$] sh safe_rm testFile2 testFile 3

I need both files able to be passed, any ideas?

```
file=$1

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "You have not entered a file"
   exit
elif [ -d $file ]
then
   echo "Your file is a directory"
   exit
elif [ -e $file ]
then
   sendToBin
else
   echo "Your file $file does not exist"
   exit


  fi
```

Comment: You'll want to look into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
sh safe_rm testFile2 testFile 3

for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

This will print:

```
testFile2
testFile
3
```

[See this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script)

Comment: +1. @claybanks, note the necessary use of double quotes everywhere.