# Shell script array syntax

Tags: arrays, shell

I give an array as a parameter to a function like this:

```
 declare -a my_array=(1 2 3 4)  
 my_function  (????my_array)
```

I want the array to be passed to the function just as one array, not as 4 separate argument. Then in the function, I want to iterate through the array like:

(in my_function)

```
for item in (???) 
do 
.... 
done
```

What should be the correct syntax for (???).

Comment: You want "$@" if this is bash. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script).

Comment: @Troy My argument is an array(single argument). Looks like it's different from combination of several arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash does not have a syntax for array literals. What you show (`my_function (1 2 3 4)`) is a syntax error. You must use one of

- `my_function "(1 2 3 4)"`
- `my_function 1 2 3 4`

For the first:

```
my_function() {
    local -a ary=$1
    # do something with the array
    for idx in "${!ary[@]}"; do echo "ary[$idx]=${ary[$idx]}"; done
}
```

For the second, simply use `"$@"` or:

```
my_function() {
    local -a ary=("$@")
    # do something with the array
    for idx in "${!ary[@]}"; do echo "ary[$idx]=${ary[$idx]}"; done
}
```

---

A reluctant edit...

```
my_function() {
    local -a ary=($1)   # $1 must not be quoted
    # ...
}

declare -a my_array=(1 2 3 4)  
my_function "${my_array[#]}"       # this *must* be quoted
```

This relies on your data NOT containing whitespace. For example this won't work

```
my_array=("first arg" "second arg")
```

You want to pass 2 elements but you will receive 4. Coercing an array into a string and then re-expanding it is fraught with peril.

You can do this with indirect variables, but they are ugly with arrays

```
my_function() {
    local tmp="${1}[@]"       # just a string here
    local -a ary=("${!tmp}")  # indirectly expanded into a variable
    # ...
}

my_function my_array          # pass the array *name*
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. It's working very well. However, I met another problem. I have updated my original post.Could you take a look:> Bash is very new to me and sometimes I just got stuck on some simple problem:>

Comment: That seems an arbitrary requirement. Why restrict yourself that way when it just makes your life harder?

Comment: Yes.You are right. Anyway thanks a lot for your reply.Looks very good.