# How to remove some arguments from the arguments list in bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

Suppose I need a script, which removes a few specific arguments from the argument list and echo the rest. For instance:

The script is `myscript.bash` and the arguments to remove are `b` and `e`.

```
> myscript.bash a b c d e f
a c d f
> myscript.bash a b c
a c
> myscript.bash b e
```

How would you write such a script ?

Comment: It sounds nice. Please show what you tried so we can suggest or help wherever you found some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [case](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) to accomplish this and then `echo -n` to put the parameters on the same line. You can get all the arguments with **$@**. Borrowing the example from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script).

```
for var in "$@"
do
  case $var in
   "a") echo -n $var ;;
   "b") ;;
   [...]
  esac
done
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work if there are spaces in the parameters.