# How do I pass a wildcard parameter to a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, wildcard

I'm trying to write a bash script that allows the user to pass a directory path using wildcards.

For example,

```
bash show_files.sh *
```

when executed within this directory

```
drw-r--r--  2 root root  4.0K Sep 18 11:33 dir_a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   223 Sep 18 11:33 file_b.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   106 Oct 18 15:48 file_c.sql
```

would output:

```
dir_a
file_b.txt
file_c.sql
```

The way it is right now, it outputs:

```
dir_a
```

contents of `show_files.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs="$1"

for dir in $dirs
do
    echo $dir
done
```

Comment: Quoting the wildcard is fine, but the main difference in your script and those below is $@ instead of $1

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The parent shell, the one invoking `bash show_files.sh *`, expands the `*` for you.

In your script, you need to use:

```
for dir in "$@"
do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

The double quotes ensure that multiple spaces etc in file names are handled correctly.

See also [How to iterate over arguments in a <s>`bash`</s> shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script).

---

#### *Potentially confusing addendum*

If you're truly sure you want to get the script to expand the `*`, you have to make sure that `*` is passed to the script (enclosed in quotes, as in the other answers), and then make sure it is expanded at the right point in the processing (which is not trivial).  At that point, I'd use an array.

```
names=( $@ )
for file in "${names[@]}"
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

I don't often use `$@` without the double quotes, but this is one time when it is more or less the correct thing to do.  The tricky part is that it won't handle wild cards with spaces in very well.

Consider:

```
$ > "double  space.c"
$ > "double  space.h"
$ echo double\ \ space.?
double  space.c double  space.h
$
```

That works fine.  But try passing that as a wild-card to the script and ... well, let's just say it gets to be tricky at that point.

If you want to extract `$2` separately, then you can use:

```
names=( $1 )
for file in "${names[@]}"
do
    echo "$file"
done
# ... use $2 ...
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do that which would allow for multiple parameters. For instance, `bash show_files.sh * second_param`. This application doesn't really need that. Just curious.

Comment: @eisaacson if second_param comes first you can do `sparam=$1; shift;` then use `$@`.

Comment: @jordanm Your comment here is a great solution. Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What you added to your answer makes it all very confusing.

Comment: Sorry; that wasn't the intention.  Passing wild-cards around is not a good idea, in part because it makes everything very confusing.  Let the shell deal with it naturally.  In your design, pass the 'second' parameter first, and leave the 'list of files/directories' as the remainder of the arguments.  This is the natural Unix design.  I would recommend using it if at all possible.

Comment: `names=( $@ )` should be `names=( "$@" )`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: wouldn't encoding it in quotes prevent meta characters being expanded, which is the object of the exercise?

Comment: Ahh. If the only intent is for globs to be expanded, you might want to clear IFS first, so we don't also get string-splitting, but `names=( $@ )` does make sense in that case.

Answer (score 12):

Quote the wild-card:

```
bash show_files.sh '*'
```

or make your script accept a list of arguments, not just one:

```
for dir in "$@"
do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

It's better to iterate directly over `"$@'` rather than assigning it to another variable, in order to preserve its special ability to hold elements that themselves contain whitespace.

Comment: Great! The second option is perfect. Is there a way to do that which would allow for multiple parameters. For instance, `bash show_files.sh * second_param`. This application doesn't really need that. Just curious.

Comment: Kind of. Your script would receive a variable number of parameters, with what you call "second_param" really being the *last* parameter. `show_files.sh` never sees the `*`, only the list of files that the shell expands it to. It's a little tricky to get the last argument, although `bash` has some extensions to make it easier. `${@: -1}` (space required) would give you the last argument. `${@:0:$#}` seems to give you all *but* the last, but using an offset of 0 with `$@` (which is otherwise a 1-based array) seems a little fishy and that expression may be buggy.

Comment: For me, the first option is perfect. I needed to pass a parameter to another script that handles wildcards on its own.