# Linux bash script: Recurisely delete files if empty based on file format from user input

Tags: linux, bash

So as the title describes, I want to recursively delete all files which match a naming pattern given by the user, but only if the file is empty. Here is my attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

_files="$1"
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 filename"; exit 1; }
[ ! -f "$_files" ] && { echo "Error: $0 no files were found which match given naming structure."; exit 2; }
for f in $(find -name $_files)
do

    if [ -s "$f" ] 
    then
        echo "$f has some data."
            # do something as file has data
    else
        echo "$f is empty. Deleting file."
        rm $f
    fi
done
```

Example output:

```
./remove_blank.sh *.o*
./Disp_variations_higher_0.o1906168 has some data.
./remove_blank.sh *.e*
./Disp_variations_higher_15.e1906183 is empty. Deleting file.
```

As you can see, the code works, but only for one file at a time. Should be a relatively simple fix to get it to work, but I extremely new to bash scripting and can't seem to figure it out. Sorry for the noobish question. I did some research to find an answer but didn't find exactly what I needed. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit**
I have found two different solutions to the problem. As @David Z's suggestion, one can fix this by 1st deleting the Error checking part of the script as well as putting quotes around the $_files variable in the find function. Then the code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
_files=$1
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 filename"; exit 1; }
for f in $(find -name "$_files")
```

do

```
    if [ -s $f ] 
    then
        echo "$f  has some data."
        # do something as file has data
    else
        echo "$f is empty. Deleting file."
        rm $f
    fi
```

done

Or, one can also simply change the for loop to for f in "$@", which allows the error check to be kept in the script. I am not sure which method is better but will update again if I find out.

Comment: You need to quote the command line argument and `$_files` everywhere to prevent expansion.

Comment: Couldn't you do this in a single `find` command?

Comment: Whenever _files_ and _recursive_ are associated in a bash question, the obvious answer should be [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)).

Comment: It is a bit hidden, but I am using the find module in the 4th line of the body:
for f in $(find -name $_files)

Comment: I would have expected something like `find -name $_files -empty -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way you're invoking the script, the shell expands the pattern before running your script. For example, in

```
./remove_blank.sh *.o*
```

the shell converts `*.o*` to the list of filenames that match that pattern, and then what it actually runs is something like

```
./remove_blank.sh Disp_variations_higher_0.o1906168 other_file.o12345 ...
```

But you only check the first argument in your script, so that's the one that winds up getting deleted.

Solution: quote the pattern when you run the script.

```
./remove_blank.sh '*.o*'
```

You will also need to remove the test `[ ! -f "$_files" ] ...` because `$_files` is being set to the *pattern* (such as `*.o*`), not a filename. In fact, you might want to rename the variable to make that clear. And finally, you need to quote the variable in your `find` command,

```
... $(find -name "$_files") ...
```

so that the pattern makes it all the way through to `find` without being converted into filenames by the shell.

There are some other issues with the script but you might want to ask about those on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). What I've identified here is just the minimum needed to get it working.

---

Incidentally, you can accomplish this whole task using `find` itself, which will at least give cleaner code:

```
find -name "$_files" -type f -empty -delete
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it throws the error message: Error: ./remove_blank.sh no files were found which match given naming structure. 
From input: ./remove_blank.sh '*.o*' 
And yes, I made sure that there are *.o* files in the directory I am running the script.

Comment: Ah, right, I'll update to clarify about that.

Comment: That did the trick David, thanks for that. However I did find a substitute  which allows me to keep the error check. I simply replace the `for f in $(find -name "$_files")` line with `for f in "$@"` as per the suggestion of this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458104/how-do-i-pass-a-wildcard-parameter-to-a-bash-file

Are there any pro/con trade-offs for the two methods?