# Protecting arguments containing spaces from eval

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, eval

In order to get eval to work on commands that contain spaces inside one of the parameters, I have only found this to work so far:

```
eval 'sed 's/foo/foo'" "'bar/g' filename'
```

In a hypothetical program where users would enter a command and then the command and arguments to be fed to eval, this isn't a very elegant or robust solution. Are there any other ways to run the eval command so that the interface for my_command can be a little more user friendly? The following is an example of how the program accepts arguments now.

```
my_command 'sed 's/foo/foo'" "'bar/g' filename'
```

I would like the interface to work something like this:

```
my_command sed 's/foo/foo bar/g' filename
```

---

edit:

I'll try asking a different question:

How do I get bash to read input from the command line literally? I want the exact input to be preserved, so if there are quotes I want to keep them. I can accomplish what I want to do by using egrep to read from file and then sanitizing the input, like so:

```
egrep '/.*/' filename |
sed 's/\(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\) \(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\)/\1'"\'"'\2" "\3'"\'"'\4/g'
```

with "filename" containing this line

```
sed 's/foo/foo bar/g' file
```

this gives me the desired output of:

```
sed 's/foo/foo" "bar/g' file
```

Problem here is that I can't `echo "$@"` because bash interprets the quotes. I want the literal input without having to read from file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Original question

For your preferred use-case, you'd simply write (inside `my_command`):

```
"$@"
```

to execute the command as given.

Your `eval` line is odd:

```
eval 'sed 's/foo/foo'" "'bar/g' filename'
```

Because of the way single quotes don't nest, it is equivalent to:

```
 eval 'sed s/foo/foo" "bar/g filename'
```

#### Revised question

Possible solution:

```
egrep '/.*/' filename | sh
```

This feeds what is in `filename` directly to the shell for interpretation.  Given `file` containing:

```
Some text containing foo; and bar.
More foo bar?
More text; more foo and bar; more foo bar beyond the possibility of unfooing.
```

The output is:

```
Some text containing foo bar; and bar.
More foo bar bar?
More text; more foo bar and bar; more foo bar bar beyond the possibility of unfoo baring.
```

#### Fixing quotes is hard!

Note that your complex `sed` script is not complex enough.  Given `filename` containing:

```
sed 's/foo/foo bar/g' file
sed 's/foo bar/foo bar baz/g' file
```

the output from:

```
egrep '/.*/' filename |
sed 's/\(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\) \(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\)/\1'"\'"'\2" "\3'"\'"'\4/g'
```

is:

```
sed 's/foo/foo" "bar/g' file
sed 's/foo bar/foo bar" "baz/g' file
```

which has not solved all the problems for the `eval`.

I've spent a lot of time, on and off, working on such issues over quite a long period of time (a quarter century is no exaggeration), and it isn't trivial.  You can find one discussion in extenso in [How to iterate over arguments in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225).  Somewhere, I have another answer which goes through gyrations about this stuff, but I can't immediately find it (where 'immediately' means an hour or so of distracted searching, where the distractions were sets of duplicate questions, etc).  It may have been deleted, or I may have looked in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the nested quotes problem, and also asked the question in more specific way.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put in to this response! I'm ready to take your word for it re the complexity of this issue and just explore alternatives, e.g. command options, or as someone suggested elsewhere, ANSI C quoting and just typing the desired text directly in the command parameters.

Answer (score 1):

your design is flawed. Create a user interface that doesn't let them input commands directly. give options, or let them enter the parameters only.
At the back end, you do your sanitization check on the parameters before calling `sed` or other tools desired. You don't have to use `eval`

Answer (score 1):

#### Array quoting

The following keeps spaces in arguments by quoting each element of array:

```
function token_quote {
  local quoted=()
  for token; do
    quoted+=( "$(printf '%q' "$token")" )
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${quoted[*]}"
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$ token_quote token 'single token' token
token single\ token token
```

Above, note the `single token`'s space is quoted as `\`.

```
$ set $(token_quote token 'single token' token)
$ eval printf '%s\\n' "$@"
token
single token
token
$
```

This shows that the tokens are indeed kept separate.

---

Given some untrusted user input:

```
% input="Trying to hack you; date"
```

Construct a command to eval:

```
% cmd=(echo "User gave:" "$input")
```

Eval it, with **seemingly** correct quoting:

```
% eval "$(echo "${cmd[@]}")"
User gave: Trying to hack you
Thu Sep 27 20:41:31 +07 2018
```

Note you were hacked. `date` was executed rather than being printed literally.

Instead with `token_quote()`:

```
% eval "$(token_quote "${cmd[@]}")"
User gave: Trying to hack you; date
%
```

`eval` isn't evil - it's just misunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

It can actually work as you desire. Use `"$@"` - this will pass all the arguments exactly as they were given on the command line.

If my_command.sh contains:

```
sed "$@"
```

Then `my_command.sh 's/foo/foo bar/g' filename` will do exactly what you expect.