# How do I use a filter, that is a taken input from standard input, instead of from the default log file /var/log/messages

Tags: unix

How would I start off using get-opts?
The output should be similar to this, but I need the filter that is a taken input from standard input

```
  awk < /var/log/messages '{ print $2, $1, $5}' | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $3, $1, $4 }' | cut -d':' -f1
```

Comment: If you need good answers I would recommend posting some sample input data and your desired output. `awk` is very powerful and can easily remove the need of extra pipes, but you need to show what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a shell script, then the normal answer is to use `"$@"`, which is somewhat magical:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ print $2, $1, $5}' "$@" |
uniq -c |
awk '{ print $2, $3, $1, $4 }' |
cut -d':' -f1
```

The `"$@"` represents 'all the command line arguments', or nothing if there are no command line arguments.  Given that `awk` is a command that reads the files named on its command line, or standard input if no files are specified, this will work correctly — it is an important part of the design of good, general purpose, Unix tools.  If you want to process `/var/log/messages` in the absence of a command line argument, then you need to use the [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) notation:

```
"${@:-/var/log/messages}"
```

If there are no arguments in the argument list, then it substitutes `/var/log/messages` as the file name.

You can find out more about `"$@"` in the Bash manual under [Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters).  See also [How to iterate over the arguments in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/256225#256225).

Note that `uniq` does not sort the data; it looks for lines that are adjacent and the same.  You would usually insert a `sort` before `uniq -c`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ print $2, $1, $5}' "$@" |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '{ print $2, $3, $1, $4 }' |
cut -d':' -f1
```