# If xargs is map, what is filter?

Tags: shell, dictionary, filter, xargs

I think of `xargs` as the map function of the UNIX shell. What is the `filter` function?

EDIT: it looks like I'll have to be a bit more explicit.

Let's say I have to hand a program which accepts a single string as a parameter and returns with an exit code of 0 or 1. This program will act as a predicate over the strings that it accepts.

For example, I might decide to interpret the string parameter as a filepath, and define the predicate to be "does this file exist". In this case, the program could be `test -f`, which, given a string, exits with 0 if the file exists, and 1 otherwise.

I also have to hand a stream of strings. For example, I might have a file `~/paths` containing

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/foo/bar/baz
/etc/hosts
```

Now, I want to create a new file, `~/existing_paths`, containing only those paths that exist on my filesystem. In my case, that would be

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/hosts
```

I want to do this by reading in the `~/paths` file, filtering those lines by the predicate `test -f`, and writing the output to `~/existing_paths`. By analogy with `xargs`, this would look like:

```
cat ~/paths | xfilter test -f > ~/existing_paths
```

It is the hypothesized program `xfilter` that I am looking for:

```
xfilter COMMAND [ARG]...
```

Which, for each line `L` of its standard input, will call `COMMAND [ARG]... L`, and if the exit code is 0, it prints `L`, else it prints nothing.

To be clear, I am not looking for:

- a way to filter a list of filepaths by existence. That was a specific example.
- how to write such a program. I can do that.

I *am* looking for either:

- a pre-existing implementation, like `xargs`, or
- a clear explanation of why this doesn't exist

Comment: Because isn't effective **fork** N-times a command what only will filer based on exit-status. As you stated, it is simple to write in any language (bash, perl, C) - but isn't effective. Much more effective is using directly some command (the right tool - based on situation) what could read _STDIN_ and _filter the input_ as zilion times **fork/exec** a command for exit-status. Many times the `xargs` isn't the most effective way too. (Imagine a file-list long 1_000_000 lines. Milion forks isn't the best thing what you can do...) And if need such thing (as you known) it is an 3 line bash function

Comment: @jm666 sounds like by "effective" you mean "performant". I don't care about performance, I care about expressiveness.

Answer (score 15):

If map is `xargs`, filter is... still `xargs`.

Example: list files in the current directory and filter out non-executable files:

```
ls | xargs -I{} sh -c "test -x '{}' && echo '{}'"
```

This could be made handy trough a (non production-ready) function:

```
xfilter() {
    xargs -I{} sh -c "$* '{}' && echo '{}'"
}
ls | xfilter test -x
```

Alternatively, you could use a parallel filter implementation via GNU Parallel:

```
ls | parallel "test -x '{}' && echo '{}'"
```

Answer (score 8):

So, youre looking for the:

```
 reduce(  compare(  filter( map(.. list()) ) ) )
```

what can be rewiritten as

```
 list | map | filter | compare | reduce
```

The main power of `bash` is a *pipelining*, therefore isn't need to have one special `filter` and/or `reduce` command. In fact nearly all unix commands could act in one (or more) functions as:

- list
- map
- filter
- reduce

Imagine:

```
find mydir -type f -print | xargs grep -H '^[0-9]*$' | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -nr | head  -1
^------list+filter------^   ^--------map-----------^   ^--filter--^   ^compare^  ^reduce^
```

Creating a test case:

```
mkdir ./testcase
cd ./testcase || exit 1
for i in {1..10}
do
    strings -1 < /dev/random | head -1000 > file.$i.txt
done
mkdir emptydir
```

You will get a directory named `testcase` and in this directory 10 files and one directory

```
emptydir  file.1.txt  file.10.txt file.2.txt  file.3.txt  file.4.txt  file.5.txt  file.6.txt  file.7.txt  file.8.txt  file.9.txt
```

each file contains 1000 lines of random strings some lines are contains only numbers

now run the command

```
find testcase -type f -print | xargs grep -H '^[0-9]*$' | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -nr | head -1
```

and you will get the largest number-only line from each files like: `42`. (of course, this can be done more effectively, this is only for demo)

decomposed:

The `find testcase -type f -print` will print every plain files so, *LIST* (and reduced only to files).  ouput:

```
testcase/file.1.txt
testcase/file.10.txt
testcase/file.2.txt
testcase/file.3.txt
testcase/file.4.txt
testcase/file.5.txt
testcase/file.6.txt
testcase/file.7.txt
testcase/file.8.txt
testcase/file.9.txt
```

the `xargs grep -H '^[0-9]*$'` as *MAP* will run a `grep` command for each file from a list. The grep is usually using as *filter*, e.g: `command | grep`, but now (with xargs) changes the input (filenames) to (lines containing only digits). Output, many lines like:

```
testcase/file.1.txt:1
testcase/file.1.txt:8
....
testcase/file.9.txt:4
testcase/file.9.txt:5
```

structure of lines: `filename colon number`, want only numbers so calling a pure filter, what strips out the filenames from each line `cut -d: -f2`. It outputs many lines like:

```
1
8
...
4
5
```

Now the reduce (getting the largest number), the `sort -nr` sorts all number numerically and reverse order (desc), so its output is like:

```
42
18
9
9
...
0
0
```

and the `head -1` print the first line (the largest number).

Of course, you can write your own list/filter/map/reduce functions directly with `bash` programming constructions (loops, conditions and such), or you can employ any fullblown scripting language like `perl`, special languages like `awk`, `sed` "language", or `dc` (rpn) and such.

Having an *special filter* command such:

```
list | filter_command cut -d: -f 2
```

is simple doesn't needed, because you can use directly the

```
list | cut
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have `awk` do the `filter` and `reduce` function.

Filter:

```
awk 'NR % 2 { $0 = $0 " [EVEN]" } 1'
```

Reduce:

```
awk '{ p = p + $0 } END { print p }'
```

Comment: Thanks, but `xargs` has as a parameter a general shell command, which is the function to map over the input lines. By analogy, `filter` should take a shell command to use as a predicate over the input lines (for example, based on its return code being 0 or not). In your examples, the predicates are only defined in `awk`-speak.

Comment: @jameshfisher What you need is the shell I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script)?

Comment: @jameshfisher A loop in `bash` like `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done`. You can use all the variables you want to make it work the way you want it to and have `$?`, `if` conditions or logical operators `&&` and `||` for controlling the logic.

Answer (score 2):

I totally understand your question here as a long time functional programmer and here is the answer: Bash/unix command pipelining isn't as clean as you'd hoped.

In the example above:

```
find mydir -type f -print | xargs grep -H '^[0-9]*$' | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -nr | head  -1
^------list+filter------^   ^--------map-----------^   ^--filter--^   ^compare^  ^reduce^
```

a more pure form would look like:

```
find mydir | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'test -f $1 && echo $1' _ | grep -H '^[0-9]*$' | cut -d: -f 2 | sort -nr | head -1
^---list--^^-------filter---------------------------------^^------map----------^^--map-------^  ^reduce^
```

But, for example, grep also has a filtering capability: `grep -q mypattern` which simply return 0 if it matches the pattern.

To get a something more like what you want, you simply would have to define a filter bash function and make sure to export it so it was compatible with xargs

But then you get into some problems. Like, test has binary and unary operators. How will your filter function handle this? Hand, what would you decide to output on true for these cases? Not insurmountable, but weird. Assuming only unary operations:

```
filter(){
    while read -r LINE || [[ -n "${LINE}" ]]; do
        eval "[[ ${LINE} $1 ]]" 2> /dev/null && echo "$LINE"
    done
}
```

so you could do something like

```
seq 1 10 | filter "> 4"
5
6
7
8
9
```

As I wrote this I kinda liked it