# BASH: Filter list of files by return value of another command

Tags: linux, bash, find, command, pipe

I have series of directories with (mostly) video files in them, say

```
test1
  1.mpg
  2.avi
  3.mpeg
  junk.sh
test2
  123.avi
  432.avi
  432.srt
test3
  asdf.mpg
  qwerty.mpeg
```

I create a variable (`video_dir`) with the directory names (based on other parameters) and use that with `find` to generate the basic list.  I then filter based on another variable (`video_type`) for file types (because there is sometimes non-video files in the dirs) piping it through `egrep`.  Then I shuffle the list around and save it out to a file.  That file is later used by `mplayer` to slideshow through the list.
I currently use the following command to accomplish that.  I'm sure it's a horrible way to do it, but it works for me and it's quite fast even on big directories.

```
video_dir="/test1 /test2"
video_types=".mpg$|.avi$|.mpeg$"

find ${video_dir} -type f    |
  egrep -i "${video_types}"  |
  shuf > "$TEMP_OUT"
```

I now would like to add the ability to filter out files based on the resolution height of the video file.  I can get that from.

```
mediainfo --Output='Video;%Height%' filename
```

Which just returns a number.  I have tried using the -exec functionality of find to run that command on each file.

```
 find ${video_dir} -type f -exec mediainfo --Output='Video;%Height%' {} \;
```

but that just returns the list of heights, not the filenames and I can't figure out how to reject ones based on a comparison, like <480.
I could do a for next loop but that seems like a bad (slow) idea.

Using info from @mark-setchell I modified it to,

```
video_dir="test1"

find ${video_dir} -type f   \
   -exec bash -c 'h=$(mediainfo --Output="Video;%Height%" "$1"); [[ $h -gt 480 ]]' _ {} \; -print
```

Which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `egrep` with the following so you are still inside the `find` command (`-iname` is case insensitive and `-o` represents a logical OR):

```
find test1 test2 -type f                                       \
     \( -iname "*.mpg" -o -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mpeg" \) \
     NEXT_BIT
```

The NEXT_BIT can then `-exec bash` and exit with status 0 or 1 depending on whether you want the current file included or excluded. So it will look like this:

```
-exec bash -c 'H=$(mediainfo -output ... "$1"); [ $H -lt 480 ] && exit 1; exit 0' _ {} \;
```

So, taking note of @tripleee advice in comments about superfluous `exit` statements, I get this:

```
find test1 test2 -type f                                       \
    \( -iname "*.mpg" -o -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mpeg" \)  \
    -exec bash -c 'h=$(mediainfo ...options... "$1"); [ $h -lt 480 ]' _ {} \; -print
```

Comment: I think you need to replace `exit 0` with `echo "$1"`.

Comment: You can use `-iregex` to use the OP's expression verbatim instead of the refactored repeated `-iname`s.

Comment: `root` no, that's completely wrong; you want to use `-exec` as a predicate which indicates whether or not this is a file which should be found. But the explicit `exit` is redundant - `[` quite specifically sets its exit code to reflect the result, and the result code from `bash` will be whatever the last command in the script returned.

Comment: deleted comment

Comment: using 'find ${video_dir} -type f   \
   -exec bash -c 'H=$(mediainfo --Output=''Video;%Height%'' "$1"); [ $H -lt 480 ]' _ {} \;' gives '_: line 0: fg: no job control
_: line 0: [: too many arguments'

Comment: @Skitzman69 Please click `edit` under your question and update it with code you have tried and any error messages as it is impossible to read code b tried in comments. Thank you. Please also show the output of running a `media info` command.

Comment: Also, please use my latest, greatest code right at the end of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*This Q&A was focused on one particular case, so the accepted answer is not as general as it could be.*

### `find`

If the list of files comes from `find`, one can use its filtering facilities, e.g. `-exec`:

```
find ${video_dir} -type f \
     -exec COMMAND \; \
     -print
```

Here

- COMMAND is not enclosed in quotes -- `find` reads everything after `-exec` and up to a `\;`
- `find` will expand `{}` to the current file name (including path -- you might find `-execdir` helpful, which will `cd` to the file's directory and replace `{}` with the leaf file name)
- The exit code of COMMAND is treated as follows:

  - 0 -> true
  - non-0 -> false

Note that you can build more complex expressions (e.g. `-not -exec ...`), which will be evaluated *"from left to right, according to the rules of precedence ... `-and` is assumed where the operator is omitted.*" (per [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find))

### xargs

If the list of files comes from elsewhere (and is available on stdin), you can use `xargs` as follows (from
[If xargs is map, what is filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979323/if-xargs-is-map-what-is-filter) )

```
ls | xargs -I{} bash -c "COMMAND '{}' && echo '{}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

video_dir=(/test1 /test2)

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  if [[ $file = *.@(mpg|avi|mpeg|mp4) ]]; then
    h=$(mediainfo --Output="Video;%Height%"  "$file")
    (( h >= 480 )) && echo "$file"
  fi
done < <(find "${video_dir[@]}" -type f -print0)
```

This solution you can process everything inside the while read loop.