# How to use "find" and "grep" to get the file size too?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, grep

I have this script:

```
find test -type f \( -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.htm -o -iname \*.xhtml \) -exec grep -il ".swf" {} \; -printf '%k KB - \t %p\n' > result-swf-files.csv
```

This will search the directory "test" (and its subdirectories) for all HTML files which contains the word ".swf" in them. ANd will write a CSV file with the results.

But I want to get the file size too in the same line (now, the script outputs on one line the grep result - which doesn't have the file size -  and in another line the printf result - which includes the file size).
How do I add an option to grep to get the file size?

Comment: grep doesn't have such a feature. if you want to combine every two line by removing the line feed between them, use sed

Comment: Never heard of this command. Not sure how to use it in my example...but I don't want to combine the two lines, I want only the file size to be added to the grep result then.

Comment: Exec a `bash` script that does both and formats the results... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700096/2836621

Comment: Not sure how to use bash for this: find test -type f \( -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.htm -o -iname \*.xhtml \) -exec bash -c 'grep -il ".swf"' {} \;  > result-swf-files.csv
I tried that and the script seem to run forever....

Comment: Are you looking for the file size of the html file or the file size of the swf file?

Comment: Does adding `-q` to the grep options give the output you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A less verbose way is to use recursive grep (if your system supports it):

```
grep -rl --include="*.htm*" ".swf" test|xargs ls -l|awk '{ print $9 "," $5 }'
```

Explanation :

- Grep recursively using the "rl" flag
- **include** file pattern "*.htm"
- search for the string ".swf" in each htm* file
- search only under the "test" directory
- pipe the result to **xargs** where each filename becomes argument to "ls -l" command
- Then use **awk** to get to only filename and file size. Use comma "," in between 9th and 5th columns in awk print to get the csv output.

Feel free to replace "ls -l" with human readable variants such as "ls -lk" or "ls -lh"

Alternatively, in your script, you can just print only the 2nd line of each file (the one that contains the size). You can just pipe and use grep like this : **grep "[0-9] [KB]"**

Below is the complete command:

```
find . -type f \( -iname \*.html -o -iname \*.htm -o -iname \*.xhtml \) -exec grep -il ".swf" {} \; -printf '%k KB - \t %p\n'| grep "[0-9] [KB]"
```

Answer (score 0):

find . -name *PATTERN*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh

So you get ls for all files that you want.