# Using i as a variable in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script that will take command line arguments and create one or more files based off of that.  I know that each command line argument is stored in $0, $1, $2...and so on, so that is what this loop is based on.

```
for i in $(eval echo {1..$#})
do
    echo "File I'm about to edit/create: "$i""
    touch "$i"
done
```

However, $i is being taken literally as the number 1, 2..rather than the value in $1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script#255913

Comment: Thanks!  That was actually really helpful.  I can do this whole routine without even using a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use indirect parameter expansion:

```
echo "File...: ${!i}"
touch "${!i}"
```

However, it's much simpler to just iterate over the arguments themselves:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    echo "File...: $f"
    touch "$f"
done
```