# Bash $@ and $* string handling

Tags: git, bash

In my .bashrc file I have a function that at some some point needs to call git and pass to it all the parameters received. What I did is:

```
git $*
```

but when passing a string as a parameter, this is treated like there were no quotes.

When typing `myfunction commit -m "More than a word"`, an `echo "git $*"` from inside the function gives `git commit -m More that a word`, so I tried calling it with escape characters as follows:

```
myfunction commit -m \"More than a word\"
```

which correctly expands to `git commit -m "More than a word"`, but I still get the same errors:

```
error: pathspec 'than' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'word"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can I pass any parameter in a correct way? Also, what's actually happening?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is a good place to start.

Comment: Plain `$*` and `$@` are the same and almost invariably wrong.  You need to use `"$@"` to preserve the spacing in the arguments.  Occasionally (e.g. in `echo "Some info: $* :EOL"`) use `$*` inside double quotes.

Comment: Also, in `myfunction commit -m \"More than a word\"`, your quotes are literal, not syntactic. This means they don't serve their syntactic purpose of telling the shell to parse the string between them as a single word.

Comment: Now to try and find the question that this is functionally a duplicate of…

Comment: [How to iterate over the arguments in a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-bash-script/) covers the ground for functions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### On $* and $@

Your function should use:

```
git "$@"
```

...with the quotes.

---

- `$*` expands to a single string containing all arguments separated by the first character of `$IFS`, by default a space. The result is then split on all characters in IFS into multiple words, and each of those words is evaluated as a glob.
- `"$*"` expands to a single string containing all arguments separated by the first character of `$IFS`, and is *not* subsequently split into globbed pieces.
- `$@` is identical to (unquoted) `$*`.
- `"$@"` expands to the precise argument vector given to your function.

---

#### On \"\" vs ""

When quotes are escaped, they become *literal* rather than syntactic. This means that they no longer serve their syntactic purpose, but are data, treated as any other data would be.

Consequently:

```
printf '%s\n' \"hello world\"
```

...is entirely correct to emit:

```
"hello
world"
```

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR:* `"$@"` is what you want, written exactly that way with the quotes.

For full understanding, it happens that `$@` does something special *if it occurs within double quotes.*  This almost always means just `"$@"`.

*From bash(1):*

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands
>                 to  a  separate  word.   That  is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...  If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word,
>   the
>                 expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last
>   parameter
>                 is  joined  with  the  last  part  of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to nothing
>                 (i.e., they are removed).