# Shell how to test every input for file

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, input

so i am doing a shell script and am trying to figure out how to do this safe guard function:

```
if ! [[ -e "$@" ]]; then
    echo"Not a file!"
    exit 0
fi
```

my ideia is to check every input for file.
so when i call the script:
./scriptname file1.txt file2.tar NOTfile4
it will output NOT a file

Comment: Use a loop. (This suggestion brought to you by [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net))

Comment: +1. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-a-bash-script for how to use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys!
did the loop and it worked.
heres what i did if anyone who has the same problem:

```
for input in "$@"; do
if ! [ -e "$input" ]; then
    echo "Not a file!"
    exit 0
fi
done
```

Comment: That should probably be `exit 1`; Non-zero exit statuses indicate errors. If every file exists, your script will exit 0 anyway.