# How to get positional parameter passed in script bash?

Tags: c, bash

I start programming in c language, and I ask myself this question.

I have a file lol.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("argc\t= %d\n", argc);

    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++)
        printf ("argv[%i]\t= %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

So when I execute the file (after compilation) :

```
./lol "abc" "def"
```

He returns so :

```
argc    = 3
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
argv[2] = def
```

Now, I have a bash script lol.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

./lol "abc"
```

When I execute the file :

```
bash lol.sh def
```

So we get :

```
argc    = 2
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
```

How to retrieve the **positional parameters** passed to the bash script (from the file lol.c) ?

My first solution is to pass the positional parameters to the lol command like this (lol.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash

./lol "abc" "$*"
```

He returns so :

```
argc    = 3
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
argv[2] = def
```

I am not very satisfied with this solution, is there another way for that ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to use special parameters ? What is your exact question.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the arguments passed to the bash script (lol.sh) from the file c (lol.c), without specifying them from the bash file

Comment: Why don't you like `./lol "abc" "$*"`?

Comment: Isn't it you are already getting arguments passed to bash script  in lol.c? What is the issue?

Comment: You could get the parent process and get its command line but why go through all that when you've got a nice solution already.

Answer (score 0):

While `"$*"` works, it mashes all the arguments into one, with a space separating the original arguments.  You could see this by running:

```
bash lol.sh def ghi jkl
```

which would produce:

```
argc    = 3
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
argv[2] = def ghi jkl
```

and running `bash lol.sh` would produce:

```
argc    = 3
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
argv[2] =
```

Using `"$*"` is seldom the correct notation; you should normally use `"$@"` which relays the arguments verbatim as separate arguments, and handles 'no arguments' correctly (whereas `"$*"` creates an empty string as an argument).

This command should do what you want:

```
./lol "abc" "$@"
```

Then the output from `bash lol.sh def ghi jkl` would be:

```
argc    = 5
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
argv[2] = def
argv[3] = ghi
argv[4] = jkl
```

and the output from `bash lol.sh` would be:

```
argc    = 2
argv[0] = ./lol
argv[1] = abc
```

See also [How to iterate over arguments in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898))