# Drag and drop files to a bash script causes "Permission denied" when you output data to a file

Tags: bash

I need to work with different files in the script. The easy and convenient way to do it is to use "Drag and drop". But.

Drag and drop files to a bash script causes "Permission denied" when you output data to a file.

I use git-bash on Windows 10.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "123" > out123.txt
sleep 5
```

When I run script in common way (I double click on it) it works well.

When I drag and drop a file (from the same folder) on the script:

```sh
#bash: out123.txt: Permission denied
```

---

*Upd: It's for people who came from google:*

*How to get dropped data within bash script.*

It's usual argument. Code example [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255913/11468937) or [[2]](https://superuser.com/a/1215958):

```sh
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

Comment: Add `pwd` to your script. What does it output?

Comment: When I click on it `/c/folder`
When I drag and drop on it `/c/WINDOWS/system32`

Comment: So the script is run from a different directory. You're getting a "permission denied" error because the script is trying to create a file in `C:\Windows\system32`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for it. I need to parse the input data and change working directory via `cd`

Comment: The solution is `cd "$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"` The main part of the code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/).

Comment: That's crazy overcomplicated. In particular, `cd "$( cd ... && pwd )"` is redundant. I'd just use `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`.

Comment: Thanks second time. I have tried  `"\`dirname $0\`" ` from the other comment, but it does not work with the path that contain a space (.../new folder/...). Yours is working.