# Using getopts to process long and short command line options

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopts

I wish to have long and short forms of command line options invoked using my shell script.

I know that `getopts` can be used, but like in Perl, I have not been able to do the same with shell.

Any ideas on how this can be done, so that I can use options like:

```
./shell.sh --copyfile abc.pl /tmp/
./shell.sh -c abc.pl /tmp/
```

In the above, both the commands mean the same thing to my shell, but using `getopts`, I have not been able to implement these?

Comment: IMHO, the accepted answer is not the best one.  It does not show how to use getopts to handle both "-" and "--" arguments, which can be done, as @Arvid Requate demonstrated.  I'm inserting another answer using similar concept, but also deals with user error of "forgetting" to insert values for arguments that are needed.  Key point: getopts can be made to work. User should avoid using "getopt" instead if cross-platform portability is needed. Also, getopts is part of POSIX standard for shells, so it is likely to be portable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 354, accepted):

There are three implementations that may be considered:

- Bash builtin `getopts`. This does not support long option names with the double-dash prefix.  It only supports single-character options.
- BSD UNIX implementation of standalone `getopt` command (which is what MacOS uses). This does not support long options either.
- GNU implementation of standalone `getopt`.  GNU [`getopt(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html) (used by the command-line [`getopt(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) on Linux) supports parsing long options.

---

Some other answers show a solution for using the bash builtin `getopts` to mimic long options. That solution actually makes a short option whose character is "-". So you get "--" as the flag. Then anything following that becomes OPTARG, and you test the OPTARG with a nested `case`.

This is clever, but it comes with caveats:

- `getopts` can't enforce the opt spec. It can't return errors if the user supplies an invalid option. You have to do your own error-checking as you parse OPTARG.
- OPTARG is used for the long option name, which complicates usage when your long option itself has an argument. You end up having to code that yourself as an additional case.

So while it is possible to write more code to work around the lack of support for long options, this is a lot more work and partially defeats the purpose of using a getopt parser to simplify your code.

Comment: So. What is the cross-platform, portable solution?

Comment: GNU Getopt seems to be the only choice.  On Mac, install GNU getopt from macports.  On Windows, I'd install GNU getopt with Cygwin.

Comment: [Apparently](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?getopts+1), ksh getopts *can* handle long options.

Comment: @Bill +1, although it is also fairly simple to build getopt from source (http://software.frodo.looijaard.name/getopt/) on Mac.  You can also check the version of getopt installed on your system from within scripts with "getopt -T; echo $?".

Comment: @Bill Karwin: "The bash getopts builtin does not support long option names with the double-dash prefix." But getopts can be made to support long options: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7680682/915044 below.

Comment: @troelskn Use the fine [shell script that Stephane Chazelas](https://sourceforge.net/p/bashdb/code/ci/master/tree/getopts_long.sh). More information is given in my answer of a [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870341/bash-long-options-flags-how-to-do-it)

Comment: OS X 10.11, and still getopt that supports long option names :-(

Comment: @troelskn – The `getopts` built-in, even in basic POSIX shells, can have a nested `case` to parse the `$OPTARGS` of a `-` option, which allow for long options in the form `--long` (technically `--` with argument `long`) and `--long=argument` (`--` with argument `long=argument`), but not with a space separating the argument, like `--long argument`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/28466267#28466267) for one such implementation.

Comment: The question I have (and not seen answered properly) is why this is still an issue. Surely there is a practical way to solve this upstream that is portable? What is preventing a solution to what would be considered core scripting functionality?

Comment: @AmosFolarin: The code for BSD getopt is completely different code than GNU getopt. Can you install GNU getopt on macOS and call it from a bash script? Yes, you can.

Answer (score 430):

`getopt` and `getopts` are different beasts, and people seem to have a bit of misunderstanding of what they do.  `getopts` is a built-in command to `bash` to process command-line options in a loop and assign each found option and value in turn to built-in variables, so you can further process them.  `getopt`, however, is an external utility program, and it *doesn't actually process your options for you* the way that e.g. bash `getopts`, the Perl `Getopt` module or the Python `optparse`/`argparse` modules do.  All that `getopt` does is canonicalize the options that are passed in — i.e. convert them to a more standard form, so that it's easier for a shell script to process them.  For example, an application of `getopt` might convert the following:

```
myscript -ab infile.txt -ooutfile.txt
```

into this:

```
myscript -a -b -o outfile.txt infile.txt
```

You have to do the actual processing yourself.  You don't have to use `getopt` at all if you make various restrictions on the way you can specify options:

- only put one option per argument;
- all options go before any positional parameters (i.e. non-option arguments);
- for options with values (e.g. `-o` above), the value has to go as a separate argument (after a space).

Why use `getopt` instead of `getopts`?  The basic reason is that only GNU `getopt` gives you support for long-named command-line options.<sup>1</sup> (GNU `getopt` is the default on Linux. Mac OS X and FreeBSD come with a basic and not-very-useful `getopt`, but the GNU version can be installed; see below.)

For example, here's an example of using GNU `getopt`, from a script of mine called `javawrap`:

```
# NOTE: This requires GNU getopt.  On Mac OS X and FreeBSD, you have to install this
# separately; see below.
TEMP=$(getopt -o vdm: --long verbose,debug,memory:,debugfile:,minheap:,maxheap: \
              -n 'javawrap' -- "$@")

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

# Note the quotes around '$TEMP': they are essential!
eval set -- "$TEMP"

VERBOSE=false
DEBUG=false
MEMORY=
DEBUGFILE=
JAVA_MISC_OPT=
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -v | --verbose ) VERBOSE=true; shift ;;
    -d | --debug ) DEBUG=true; shift ;;
    -m | --memory ) MEMORY="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    --debugfile ) DEBUGFILE="$2"; shift 2 ;;
    --minheap )
      JAVA_MISC_OPT="$JAVA_MISC_OPT -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=$2"; shift 2 ;;
    --maxheap )
      JAVA_MISC_OPT="$JAVA_MISC_OPT -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=$2"; shift 2 ;;
    -- ) shift; break ;;
    * ) break ;;
  esac
done
```

This lets you specify options like `--verbose -dm4096 --minh=20 --maxhe 40 --debugfi="/Users/John Johnson/debug.txt"` or similar.  The effect of the call to `getopt` is to canonicalize the options to `--verbose -d -m 4096 --minheap 20 --maxheap 40 --debugfile "/Users/John Johnson/debug.txt"` so that you can more easily process them.  The quoting around `"$1"` and `"$2"` is important as it ensures that arguments with spaces in them get handled properly.

If you delete the first 9 lines (everything up through the `eval set` line), the code will *still work*!  However, your code will be much pickier in what sorts of options it accepts: In particular, you'll have to specify all options in the "canonical" form described above.  With the use of `getopt`, however, you can group single-letter options, use shorter non-ambiguous forms of long-options, use either the `--file foo.txt` or `--file=foo.txt` style, use either the `-m 4096` or `-m4096` style, mix options and non-options in any order, etc.  `getopt` also outputs an error message if unrecognized or ambiguous options are found.

*NOTE*: There are actually two *totally different* versions of `getopt`, basic `getopt` and GNU `getopt`, with different features and different calling conventions.<sup>2</sup> Basic `getopt` is quite broken: Not only does it not handle long options, it also can't even handle embedded spaces inside of arguments or empty arguments, whereas `getopts` does do this right. The above code will not work in basic `getopt`. GNU `getopt` is installed by default on Linux, but on Mac OS X and FreeBSD it needs to be installed separately. On Mac OS X, install MacPorts (http://www.macports.org) and then do `sudo port install getopt` to install GNU `getopt` (usually into `/opt/local/bin`), and make sure that `/opt/local/bin` is in your shell path ahead of `/usr/bin`. On FreeBSD, install `misc/getopt`.

A quick guide to modifying the example code for your own program: Of the first few lines, all is "boilerplate" that should stay the same, except the line that calls `getopt`.  You should change the program name after `-n`, specify short options after `-o`, and long options after `--long`.  Put a colon after options that take a value.

Finally, if you see code that has just `set` instead of `eval set`, it was written for BSD `getopt`. You should change it to use the `eval set` style, which works fine with both versions of `getopt`, while the plain `set` doesn't work right with GNU `getopt`.

<sup>1</sup>Actually, `getopts` in `ksh93` supports long-named options, but this shell isn't used as often as `bash`. In `zsh`, use `zparseopts` to get this functionality.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, "GNU `getopt`" is a misnomer; this version was actually written for Linux rather than the GNU project. However, it follows all the GNU conventions, and the term "GNU `getopt`" is commonly used (e.g. on FreeBSD).

Comment: This was very helpful, the idea of using getopt to check the options and then process those options in a very simple loop worked really well when I wanted to add long style options to a bash script. Thanks.

Comment: `getopt` on Linux is **not** a GNU utility and the traditional `getopt` doesn't come initially from BSD but  from AT&T Unix. ksh93's `getopts` (also from AT&T) supports GNU-style long options.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas -- edited to reflect your comments. I still prefer the term "GNU getopt" even though it's a misnomer, because this version follows GNU conventions and generally acts like a GNU program (e.g. making use of `POSIXLY_CORRECT`), while "Linux-enhanced getopt" wrongly suggests that this version exists only on Linux.

Comment: It comes from the util-linux package, so it is Linux only as that bundle of software is meant for Linux only (that `getopt` could easily be ported to other Unices, but many other software in `util-linux` are Linux-specific). All non-GNU programs making use of GNU getopt(3) understand `$POSIX_CORRECT`. For instance, you wouldn't say that `aplay` is GNU just on those grounds. I suspect that when FreeBSD mention GNU getopt, they mean the GNU getopt(3) C API.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas -- FreeBSD has an error message "Build dependency: Please install GNU getopt" that unambiguously refers to the `getopt` util, not getopt(3).

Comment: re getopts is a bash built-in: POSIX 2004 appears to have added it as a required utility? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getopts.html

Comment: What does this piece of code mean? `-n 'javawrap' -- "$@"
`

Comment: Thank you for the line of code `if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Terminating..." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi` in above example. Otherwise script will continue, even passes an invalid command-line option _e.g. -T for above example_. I followed the example [here](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt), but it's not terminating on invalid options.

Comment: Great explanation. But in your example, why not put a `shift` after `esac`, then you won't need to do `shift` for every case. Then you only need `shift` (not `shift 2`) for options with values.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what `eval set` precisely does. Is it safe?

Comment: Will tack on that shellcheck points to using `getopt` for long names in https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2213#exceptions

Comment: May I ask why we need **quotes around "$TEMP"**? After parsed by `getopt`, there will not be semicolons. After `set --`, dashes and quotes will just be regarded as arguments. I have tested for a few combinations. Yet I still cannot find an example where `eval set -- $TEMP` behaves differently from `eval set -- "$TEMP"`. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: I found the **quotes around "$TEMP"** is necessary when the command line option argument, $OPTARG, contains more than one space. For example `my.sh -t "A   A"`. There are 3 spaces in between. Without the **quotes around "$TEMP"**, things will not break. But the argument will become `A A` (one space), rather than the correct `A   A` (three spaces). Is this the only concern?

Comment: Could the installation of GNU `getopt`  break existing scripts in MacOS or BSD that relay on the old `getopt` behavior or is the GNU version bach-compatible  and works as spected in place of the old one in older scripts?

Comment: @midnite ALWAYS quote your variables to prevent word splitting. Anything with spaces will bust things up badly otherwise. It never hurts to quote variables, but it often hurts not to.

Answer (score 246):

The Bash builtin getopts function can be used to parse long options by putting a dash character followed by a colon into the optspec:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
optspec=":hv-:"
while getopts "$optspec" optchar; do
    case "${optchar}" in
        -)
            case "${OPTARG}" in
                loglevel)
                    val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
                    echo "Parsing option: '--${OPTARG}', value: '${val}'" >&2;
                    ;;
                loglevel=*)
                    val=${OPTARG#*=}
                    opt=${OPTARG%=$val}
                    echo "Parsing option: '--${opt}', value: '${val}'" >&2
                    ;;
                *)
                    if [ "$OPTERR" = 1 ] && [ "${optspec:0:1}" != ":" ]; then
                        echo "Unknown option --${OPTARG}" >&2
                    fi
                    ;;
            esac;;
        h)
            echo "usage: $0 [-v] [--loglevel[=]<value>]" >&2
            exit 2
            ;;
        v)
            echo "Parsing option: '-${optchar}'" >&2
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$OPTERR" != 1 ] || [ "${optspec:0:1}" = ":" ]; then
                echo "Non-option argument: '-${OPTARG}'" >&2
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done
```

After copying to executable file name=`getopts_test.sh` in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), one can produce output like

```
$ ./getopts_test.sh
$ ./getopts_test.sh -f
Non-option argument: '-f'
$ ./getopts_test.sh -h
usage: code/getopts_test.sh [-v] [--loglevel[=]<value>]
$ ./getopts_test.sh --help
$ ./getopts_test.sh -v
Parsing option: '-v'
$ ./getopts_test.sh --very-bad
$ ./getopts_test.sh --loglevel
Parsing option: '--loglevel', value: ''
$ ./getopts_test.sh --loglevel 11
Parsing option: '--loglevel', value: '11'
$ ./getopts_test.sh --loglevel=11
Parsing option: '--loglevel', value: '11'
```

Obviously getopts neither performs `OPTERR` checking nor option-argument parsing for the long options. The script fragment above shows how this may be done manually. The basic principle also works in the Debian Almquist shell ("dash"). Note the special case:

```
getopts -- "-:"  ## without the option terminator "-- " bash complains about "-:"
getopts "-:"     ## this works in the Debian Almquist shell ("dash")
```

Note that, as GreyCat from over at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ points out, this trick exploits a non-standard behaviour of the shell which permits the option-argument (i.e. the filename in "-f filename") to be concatenated to the option (as in "-ffilename"). The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) standard says there must be a space between them, which in the case of "-- longoption" would terminate the option-parsing and turn all longoptions into non-option arguments.

Comment: One question: what is the semantics of `!` in `val="${!OPTIND}` ?

Comment: @TomRoche it is Indirect Substitution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41293/84316

Comment: I have my own question though. When the --loglevel long option is parsed, why must I increment the value of OPTIND? Can't I just leave OPTIND as is?

Comment: @ecbrodie: It is because two arguments have actually been processed, as opposed to just one. The first argument is the word "loglevel", and the next is the argument to *that* argument. Meanwhile, `getopts` automatically only increments `OPTIND` with 1, but in our case we need it to increment by 2, so we increment it by 1 manually, then let `getopts` increment it by 1 again for us automatically.

Comment: Since we're into bash equilibrism here: Naked variable names are allowed inside arithmetic expressions, no `$` necessary. `OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))` can be just `OPTIND=$(( OPTIND + 1 ))`. Even more interestingly, you can even assign and increase variables inside an arithmetic expression, so it's possible to abbreviate it further to `: $(( ++OPTIND ))`, or even `(( ++OPTIND ))` taking into account that `++OPTIND` will always be positive, so it won't trip up a shell run with the `-e` option. :-)

 http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html

Comment: i get the error "Bad Substitution" when using --loglevel for the Line ```val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))``` Any Idea why? Another thing, is it ok to use ```#!/bin/bash``` instead of ```#!/usr/bin/env bash``` ?

Comment: This should be chosen answer. We wasted lots of time trying others. val="${!OPTIND}"  works like magic! Thanks. Only problem we have with this is user error. If they forget argument value, then name of next param" shows up in value:) I am working on new version with error control/checking. Am using ideas in BashFaq Q035 http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035, "How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?"

Comment: Is it possible to move that logic to a separate function? I was not able to find a convenient way to pass

Comment: Why doesn't `--very-bad` give a warning?

Comment: Why doesn't a better option processing function or built-in exist for bash? Processing command line options for bash is an important and widely used function but both `getopt` and `getopts` have serious, well-known limitations, as discussed on this page. Other tools/languages have developed comprehensive, robust, easy-to-use CLI processing tools. For example `argparse`, `Click`, and other CLI parsers are available to Python programmers. Why hasn't someone added this functionality to bash?

Comment: wow. I tried to do the same, but I was wayyyyy of that beauty and simplicity. Your solution includes the updating of OPTIND,  it makes long options's names easy to see in the code, etc. Hands down the best solution so far to handle "--options" on very old shell, like I have to use too many times.

Comment: @divramod: using  `#!/usr/bin/env  someshell`   instead of  `#!/path/to/someshell`   is preferred : `env` is almost guaranteed to be present in `/usr/bin` so whatever the host, /usr/bin/env will be found (whereas the `someshell` could sometimes be in `/usr/bin/someshell` or on other hosts be `/bin/someshell` or even at other places). If you may use your script on a variety of machines, use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to launch bash reliably.

Comment: @arvid-requate: one little "bug" : your separation of opt and val in the long option `--verbose=value` : it does work for `verbose=simplevalue`, but for a more complexe "val" (ie, another kind of long option) it could have the wrong separation point (*= : last "=" instead of first one, and retrieving opt can also break depending on what "val" contains). change into: `opt="$(printf "%s\n" "${OPTARG}" | cut -d'=' -f1 )" ; val="$(printf "%s\n" "${OPTARG}" | cut -d'=' -f2-)"` (a bit more reusable/portable, will separate on the first "=" and doesn't interpret val too much)

Comment: This doesn't look like you would be able to use --loglevel or -l for the same result as an example though.  The answer fromm Sridhar does.

Comment: when I tested this example I found that with more than one word arg added (add another after loglevel, say 'testvar'), that only the first arg had any function.  the second arg was ignored in mac os bash.

Comment: @TomHale --very-bad does not give a warning because the optspec=":hv-:" setting has a leading ":". This suppresses warnings for missing or not supported parameters.

Comment: The POSIX spec states “If the option-argument is not supplied as a separate argument from the option character, the value in OPTARG shall be stripped of the option character and the `-`” so such behavior is indeed within the standard. While you can’t do `-- loglevel=x` since `-- ` would terminate `getopts`, I see no circumstance in which that syntax would be desired. The (spec’s) reference to `-` as unspecified for being not alpha-numerical is contradicted by the spec’s reference to a “`--` argument that is not an option-argument” which specifies behavior for `-` as an option character.

Comment: optspec=":hv-:"
should be "optspec=":h:v:-:" in macos

Comment: When an option required argument, how can we show error that it requires an argument instead of saying that the argument is invalid? I like this method but not sure how this can be added

Answer (score 164):

Long options can be parsed by the standard `getopts` builtin as “arguments” to the `-` “option”

**This is portable and native POSIX shell – no external programs or bashisms are needed.**

This guide implements long options as arguments to the `-` option, so `--alpha` is seen by `getopts` as `-` with argument `alpha` and `--bravo=foo` is seen as `-` with argument `bravo=foo`.  The true argument is harvested via shell parameter expansion, updating `$OPT` and `$OPTARG`.

In this example, arguments are accepted for `-b`, `--bravo`, and `--charlie`. `-b`/`--bravo` requires an argument, `--charlie` accepts an optional argument, and `-c` prohibits arguments (`getopts` doesn't support optional arguments, so option `c` was specified without a `:` since that would *require* an argument). Arguments to long options come after equals signs, e.g. `--bravo=foo` (space delimiters for long options would be hard to implement, see below).

By using the [`getopts` builtin](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html), this supports usage like `cmd --charlie=chaplin -ab FILE`, which has combined options `-a` and `-b` and interleaves long options with standard options, something many other answers here either struggle or fail to do.

```bash
die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 2; }  # complain to STDERR and exit with error
needs_arg() { if [ -z "$OPTARG" ]; then die "No arg for --$OPT option"; fi; }

# Defaults (to be thorough, you could also assign alpha="" and charlie="")
bravo="$HOME/Downloads"       # Overridden by the value set by -b or --bravo
charlie_default="brown"       # Only set given -c or --charlie without an arg

while getopts ab:c-: OPT; do  # allow -a, -b with arg, -c, and -- "with arg"
  # support long options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/519360
  if [ "$OPT" = "-" ]; then   # long option: reformulate OPT and OPTARG
    OPT="${OPTARG%%=*}"       # extract long option name
    OPTARG="${OPTARG#$OPT}"   # extract long option argument (may be empty)
    OPTARG="${OPTARG#=}"      # if long option argument, remove assigning `=`
  fi
  case "$OPT" in
    a | alpha )    alpha=true ;;
    b | bravo )    needs_arg; bravo="$OPTARG" ;;
    c | charlie )  charlie="${OPTARG:-$charlie_default}" ;;  # optional argument
    \? )           exit 2 ;;  # bad short option (error reported via getopts)
    * )            die "Illegal option --$OPT" ;;            # bad long option
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1)) # remove parsed options and args from $@ list
```

When the option is a dash (`-`), it is a long option. `getopts` will have parsed the actual long option into `$OPTARG`, e.g. `--bravo=foo` originally sets `OPT='-'` and `OPTARG='bravo=foo'`. The `if` stanza sets `$OPT` to the contents of `$OPTARG` before the first equals sign (`bravo` in our example) and then removes that from the beginning of `$OPTARG` (yielding `=foo` in this step, or an empty string if there is no `=`). Finally, we strip the argument's leading `=`. At this point, `$OPT` is either a short option (one character) or a long option (2+ characters).

**You can accept optional arguments to long options!** `--charlie` omits `needs_arg` and assigns to `${OPTARG:-$charlie_default}`, which uses `$charlie_default` when `$OPTARG` is empty. (`getopts` can't allow an optional argument for `-c` and therefore prohibits it.)

The `case` then matches either short or long options (the pipe, `|`, indicates that "or" operation. A long-only option like `delta ) delta=true ;;` doesn't need a pipe). For short options, `getopts` automatically complains about options and missing arguments, so we have to manually replicate those by using the `needs_arg` function to fatally exit when `$OPTARG` is empty. The `??*` condition will match any remaining long option (`?` matches a single character and `*` matches zero or more, so `??*` matches 2+ characters), allowing us to issue the "Illegal option" error before exiting.

As is normal for GNU-style long options, providing `--` will stop parsing, so `-a -- --bravo=4` will set `$alpha` to `true` but `$bravo` will remain untouched and `$1` will be `--bravo=4`. I don't recommend naming files with leading dashes, but this is how you denote they aren't options.

---

*Uppercase variable names:* Generally, the advice is to reserve all-uppercase variables for system use. I'm keeping `$OPT` as all-uppercase to keep it in line with `$OPTARG`, but this does break that convention. I think it fits because this is something the system should have done, and it should be safe; I haven't heard of any standards that use this variable name.

*To complain about unexpected arguments to long options:* Mimic `needs_arg` with a flipped test to complain about an argument when one isn't expected:

```bash
no_arg() { if [ -n "$OPTARG" ]; then die "No arg allowed for --$OPT option"; fi; }
```

*To accept long options with space-delimited arguments:* You can pull in the next argument with `eval "ARG_B=\"\$$OPTIND\""` (or with bash's [indirect expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41293/87770), `ARG_B="${!OPTIND}"`) and then increment `$OPTIND` as noted in an [older version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28466267/11), but it's unreliable; `getopts` can prematurely terminate on the assumption that the argument was beyond its scope and some implementations don't take well to manual manipulations of `$OPTIND`.

Comment: Very nice self-contained solution.  One question: Since `letter-c` needs no argument, would it not be sufficient to use `letter-c)`?; the `*` seems redundant.

Comment: @PhilipKearns was right, the `*` is technically unnecessary in `letter-c* )`, but without it, specifying arguments like `--letter-c=oops` will be cited as an "illegal option" rather than "unexpected option to `--letter-c`."  I have added a line to handle that.

Comment: (In making this answer more legible, I renamed option `--letter-c` to `--charlie`)

Comment: I like the code, but I’m missing the option to mix arguments and options, and to have options without =: `command --foo=moo bar --baz waz

Comment: you can add --foo moo by replacing charly* with `charly*   ) ARG_C="$2" ; shift 1 ;;`

Comment: @ArneBabenhauserheide – In your earlier comment, what is `bar`?  In your second comment:  `--charlie` in my code does _not_ accept an argument, but `--bravo` does.  In that case, we can indeed use `shift` in the test for `--bravo` (no trailing wildcard), but I'd want to put in logic that rejects arguments that start with a dash (requiring the user to do e.g. `--bravo=-blah` if that's truly desired).  That test would be make this toy example too long.

Comment: @Adam bar is a positional argument between the options, equivalent to `command --foo=moo --baz waz bar` or `command bar --foo=moo --baz waz`.

Comment: @Adam why do you want to reject --bravo -blah?

Comment: @Arne Positional arguments are bad UX; they're hard to understand and optional arguments are quite messy. `getopts` stops at the first positional argument since it's not designed to deal with them. This allows sub-commands with their own arguments, e.g. `git diff --color`, so I'd interpret `command --foo=moo bar --baz waz` as having `--foo` as an argument to `command` and `--baz waz` as an argument (with option) to the `bar` sub-command. This can be done with the above code. I reject `--bravo -blah` because `--bravo` requires an argument and it is unclear that `-blah` isn't another option.

Comment: I disagree about the UX: positional arguments are useful and easy, as long as you limit their number (to at most 2 or 1 plus N-of-the-same-type). It should be possible to intersperse them with keyword arguments, because users can then build a command step by step (i.e. ls a b c -la).

Comment: @Adam: If your arguments can be files, rejecting -blah will be confusing to users: some files are OK, others not.

Comment: Hm. @ArneBabenhauserheide: Now that I'm trying it (with dash), your extra `shift` trick does _not_ work.  Looks like getopts is too smart and assumes the argument list terminates before getting to that next argument; try `bravo ) ARG_B="$2"; shift 1;;` with `cmd -a --bravo test -c` and you'll find it ignores the `-c` option.

Comment: @AdamKatz yes, getopts terminates parsing at the first positional argument. I’m taking care of that for a command invocation by calling it repeatedly, though that’s not really nice. See https://bitbucket.org/ArneBab/conf/src/3edda65277ae171d2b398a32fb3b5be0bc84b70b/conf.in#conf.in-209

Comment: @AdamKatz: I wrote a small article with this: http://www.draketo.de/english/free-software/shell-argument-parsing — includes repeated reading of remaining arguments to catch trailing options.

Comment: This is superb. Thank you very much for sharing it. You mention that this is POSIX-compatible and does not include any Bashisms. For situations where Bash is guaranteed, could this approach be simplified at all by embracing Bash, or would doing so provide no benefit?

Comment: @JohnKarahalis – Not really, with one exception: Bash can do spaced arguments a little easier (as noted), but I'm not sure of the reliability of altering `$OPTIND` (I suggest testing on both current and older versions of bash if you want to publish it; e.g. RHEL 7 uses bash 4.2).

Comment: This is absolutely BRILLIANT ! I tried many ways myself to mix short and long options in a kinda portable ways, but your way is by far simpler, easier to grok, and even more compatible than my attempts. Thank you

Comment: Such a lifesaver, but I still got a maybe-silly question, does `—`still be treaded as end-of-option in this case?

Comment: @jimmymcheung – Yes, `--` will properly stop option parsing. After parsing `-a -- --bravo=4`, `$alpha` will be set to true but `$bravo` will be unassigned since `$1` will be `--bravo=4`. I've updated the answer to make this explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I thought it may produce a conflict or will disable the default behaviour of `--` in the beginning. But it great to see `--` still does what we are expecting it to do.

Comment: Does not seems to work if I only want some options to only have long options without specifying short option

Comment: @KalibZen – You can have long-only options. You can even remove all short-only options with `while getopts -: OPT`. Example: add `delta ) delta=true ;;` to the `case` for a binary long-only option delta. The pipe (`|`) is just an OR operator, allowing easier combination of long and short options. It's not necessary. Thanks for pointing out this ambiguity. I've edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: What about adding `if [ -z "$OPTARG" ]; then shift $((OPTIND-1)); OPTARG="$1"; shift; OPTIND=1; fi` to also parse `--long value`?

Comment: @CervEd – I've found modifying `$OPTIND` is not reliable across shells; see the last paragraph of my answer. It may work in the most recent version of bash, which might be sufficient for you. Just be sure to restrict that to parsing options that have mandatory options.

Comment: @AdamKatz yes I saw that. Curious to know which shells

Answer (score 147):

The built-in `getopts` command is still, AFAIK, limited to single-character options only.

There is (or used to be) an external program `getopt` that would reorganize a set of options such that it was easier to parse.  You could adapt that design to handle long options too.  Example usage:

```
aflag=no
bflag=no
flist=""
set -- $(getopt abf: "$@")
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
    (-a) aflag=yes;;
    (-b) bflag=yes;;
    (-f) flist="$flist $2"; shift;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (-*) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    (*)  break;;
    esac
    shift
done

# Process remaining non-option arguments
...
```

You could use a similar scheme with a `getoptlong` command.

Note that the fundamental weakness with the external `getopt` program is the difficulty of handling arguments with spaces in them, and in preserving those spaces accurately.  This is why the built-in `getopts` is superior, albeit limited by the fact it only handles single-letter options.

Comment: getopt, except for the GNU version (which has a different calling convention), is fundamentally broken. Do not use it.

Please use **getopts instead http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: @hendry - from your own link: "Note that getopts is not able to parse GNU-style long options (--myoption) or XF86-style long options (-myoption)!"

Comment: Jonathan -- you should rewrite the example to use `eval set` with quotes (see my answer below) so that it also works correctly with GNU getopt (the default on Linux) and handles spaces correctly.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond: I'm not sure why I should do that.  The question is tagged Unix, not Linux.  I'm showing the traditional mechanism, deliberately, and it has issues with blanks in arguments, etc.  You can demonstrate the modern Linux-specific version if you wish, and your answer does that.  (I note, passim, that your use of `${1+"$@"}` is quaint and at odds with what's necessary in modern shells and specifically with any shell you'd find on Linux.  See [Using $1:+"$@"} in /bin/sh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154625/1-in-bin-sh/155044#155044) for a discussion of that notation.)

Comment: You should do it because `eval set` does the right thing with both GNU and BSD `getopt`, whereas plain `set` only does the right thing with BSD `getopt`.  So you may as well use `eval set` to encourage people to get in the habit of doing this.

BTW thanks, I didn't realize that `${1+"$@"}` wasn't needed any more.  I have to write things that work both on Mac OS X and Linux -- between the two of them they force lots of portability.  I just checked and `"$@"` does indeed do the right thing on all of `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` under Mac OS X; surely under Linux too.

Comment: There's AIX, Solaris and HP-UX to consider too — at least, I have to consider those as well as Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: Use `(-f) flist="$2"; shift;;` to keep an extra space from appearing before your flist arg.

Comment: @jaketrent:  That trashes the previous value in `flist`; if the `-f` option appears multiple times, then the current code keeps all the values in `flist`, separated by spaces.  If you've got spaces in file names to worry about, you have to work a whole lot harder (`bash` and arrays).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: "the built-in getopts is superior, albeit limited by the fact it only handles single-letter options." But getopts can be made to support long options: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7680682/915044 below.

Comment: use `getopt -l` to add support for long options and `getopt -a` to allow long options with a single `-`  (This is with the GNU version)

Comment: The link from @hendry’s comment (the first comment to this answer) has moved to https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 81):

Here's an example that actually uses getopt with long options:

```
aflag=no
bflag=no
cargument=none

# options may be followed by one colon to indicate they have a required argument
if ! options=$(getopt -o abc: -l along,blong,clong: -- "$@")
then
    # something went wrong, getopt will put out an error message for us
    exit 1
fi

set -- $options

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    -a|--along) aflag="yes" ;;
    -b|--blong) bflag="yes" ;;
    # for options with required arguments, an additional shift is required
    -c|--clong) cargument="$2" ; shift;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (-*) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    (*) break;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: You should rewrite the example to use `eval set` with quotes (see my answer below) so that it also works correctly with GNU getopt (the default on Linux) and handles spaces correctly.

Comment: This is using `getopt` while the question is about `getopts` though.

Comment: Are `(--`, `(-*` and `(*` valid patterns? How are they different from `--`, `-*` and `*`?

Comment: @Maëlan – The leading open parenthesis is optional, so `(--)` is identical to `--)` in a `case` stanza. It is odd to see the uneven indentation and inconsistent use of that optional leading parens, but the answer's current code looks valid to me.

Comment: Took me 1 day to read about getopt vs getops, I still prefer getopt because geopts is more confusing to implement long command.

Answer (score 41):

## Using `getopts` with short/long options and arguments

---

### Works with all combinations, e.g:

- foobar -f --bar
- foobar --foo -b
- foobar -bf --bar --foobar
- foobar -fbFBAshorty --bar -FB --arguments=longhorn
- foobar -fA "text shorty" -B --arguments="text longhorn"
- bash foobar -F --barfoo
- sh foobar -B --foobar - ...
- bash ./foobar -F --bar

---

### Some declarations for this example

```
Options=$@
Optnum=$#
sfoo='no '
sbar='no '
sfoobar='no '
sbarfoo='no '
sarguments='no '
sARG=empty
lfoo='no '
lbar='no '
lfoobar='no '
lbarfoo='no '
larguments='no '
lARG=empty
```

### How the Usage function would look

```
function _usage() 
{
  ###### U S A G E : Help and ERROR ######
  cat <<EOF
   foobar $Options
  $*
          Usage: foobar <[options]>
          Options:
                  -b   --bar            Set bar to yes    ($foo)
                  -f   --foo            Set foo to yes    ($bart)
                  -h   --help           Show this message
                  -A   --arguments=...  Set arguments to yes ($arguments) AND get ARGUMENT ($ARG)
                  -B   --barfoo         Set barfoo to yes ($barfoo)
                  -F   --foobar         Set foobar to yes ($foobar)
EOF
}

[ $# = 0 ] && _usage "  >>>>>>>> no options given "
```

### `getops` with long/short flags as well as long arguments

```
while getopts ':bfh-A:BF' OPTION ; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    b  ) sbar=yes                       ;;
    f  ) sfoo=yes                       ;;
    h  ) _usage                         ;;   
    A  ) sarguments=yes;sARG="$OPTARG"  ;;
    B  ) sbarfoo=yes                    ;;
    F  ) sfoobar=yes                    ;;
    -  ) [ $OPTIND -ge 1 ] && optind=$(expr $OPTIND - 1 ) || optind=$OPTIND
         eval OPTION="\$$optind"
         OPTARG=$(echo $OPTION | cut -d'=' -f2)
         OPTION=$(echo $OPTION | cut -d'=' -f1)
         case $OPTION in
             --foo       ) lfoo=yes                       ;;
             --bar       ) lbar=yes                       ;;
             --foobar    ) lfoobar=yes                    ;;
             --barfoo    ) lbarfoo=yes                    ;;
             --help      ) _usage                         ;;
             --arguments ) larguments=yes;lARG="$OPTARG"  ;; 
             * )  _usage " Long: >>>>>>>> invalid options (long) " ;;
         esac
       OPTIND=1
       shift
      ;;
    ? )  _usage "Short: >>>>>>>> invalid options (short) "  ;;
  esac
done
```

### Output

```
##################################################################
echo "----------------------------------------------------------"
echo "RESULT short-foo      : $sfoo                                    long-foo      : $lfoo"
echo "RESULT short-bar      : $sbar                                    long-bar      : $lbar"
echo "RESULT short-foobar   : $sfoobar                                 long-foobar   : $lfoobar"
echo "RESULT short-barfoo   : $sbarfoo                                 long-barfoo   : $lbarfoo"
echo "RESULT short-arguments: $sarguments  with Argument = \"$sARG\"   long-arguments: $larguments and $lARG"
```

---

## Combining the above into a cohesive script

```
#!/bin/bash
# foobar: getopts with short and long options AND arguments

function _cleanup ()
{
  unset -f _usage _cleanup ; return 0
}

## Clear out nested functions on exit
trap _cleanup INT EXIT RETURN

###### some declarations for this example ######
Options=$@
Optnum=$#
sfoo='no '
sbar='no '
sfoobar='no '
sbarfoo='no '
sarguments='no '
sARG=empty
lfoo='no '
lbar='no '
lfoobar='no '
lbarfoo='no '
larguments='no '
lARG=empty

function _usage() 
{
  ###### U S A G E : Help and ERROR ######
  cat <<EOF
   foobar $Options
   $*
          Usage: foobar <[options]>
          Options:
                  -b   --bar            Set bar to yes    ($foo)
                    -f   --foo            Set foo to yes    ($bart)
                      -h   --help           Show this message
                  -A   --arguments=...  Set arguments to yes ($arguments) AND get ARGUMENT ($ARG)
                  -B   --barfoo         Set barfoo to yes ($barfoo)
                  -F   --foobar         Set foobar to yes ($foobar)
EOF
}

[ $# = 0 ] && _usage "  >>>>>>>> no options given "

##################################################################    
#######  "getopts" with: short options  AND  long options  #######
#######            AND  short/long arguments               #######
while getopts ':bfh-A:BF' OPTION ; do
  case "$OPTION" in
    b  ) sbar=yes                       ;;
    f  ) sfoo=yes                       ;;
    h  ) _usage                         ;;   
    A  ) sarguments=yes;sARG="$OPTARG"  ;;
    B  ) sbarfoo=yes                    ;;
    F  ) sfoobar=yes                    ;;
    -  ) [ $OPTIND -ge 1 ] && optind=$(expr $OPTIND - 1 ) || optind=$OPTIND
         eval OPTION="\$$optind"
         OPTARG=$(echo $OPTION | cut -d'=' -f2)
         OPTION=$(echo $OPTION | cut -d'=' -f1)
         case $OPTION in
             --foo       ) lfoo=yes                       ;;
             --bar       ) lbar=yes                       ;;
             --foobar    ) lfoobar=yes                    ;;
             --barfoo    ) lbarfoo=yes                    ;;
             --help      ) _usage                         ;;
               --arguments ) larguments=yes;lARG="$OPTARG"  ;; 
             * )  _usage " Long: >>>>>>>> invalid options (long) " ;;
         esac
       OPTIND=1
       shift
      ;;
    ? )  _usage "Short: >>>>>>>> invalid options (short) "  ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Does this not work with more than one long argument (--). It seems to only read the first one for me.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic – Yeah, I was playing with the `eval` approach for spaced arguments on long options and found it unreliable with certain shells (though I expect it'll work with bash, in which case you don't have to use `eval`). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/519360) for how to accept long option arguments with `=` and my noted attempts for using space. My solution doesn't make external calls while this one uses `cut` a few times.

Comment: I tried getting $lARG to retain $OPTARG, but it never works. I cant seem to provide any actual options to --arguments.

Comment: `eval OPTION="\$$optind"` will fail if optind greater then 9.  $14 is evaluated to ${1}4.

Answer (score 34):

Take a look at **[shFlags](https://github.com/kward/shflags)** which is a portable shell library (meaning: sh, bash, dash, ksh, zsh on Linux, Solaris, etc.).

It makes adding new flags as simple as adding one line to your script, and it provides an auto generated usage function.

Here is a simple `Hello, world!` using **shFlag**:

```
#!/bin/sh

# source shflags from current directory
. ./shflags

# define a 'name' command-line string flag
DEFINE_string 'name' 'world' 'name to say hello to' 'n'

# parse the command-line
FLAGS "$@" || exit 1
eval set -- "${FLAGS_ARGV}"

# say hello
echo "Hello, ${FLAGS_name}!"
```

For OSes that have the enhanced getopt that supports long options (e.g. Linux), you can do:

```
$ ./hello_world.sh --name Kate
Hello, Kate!
```

For the rest, you must use the short option:

```
$ ./hello_world.sh -n Kate
Hello, Kate!
```

Adding a new flag is as simple as adding a new `DEFINE_ call`.

Comment: This is fantastic but unfortunately my getopt (OS X) doesn't support spaces in arguments :/ wonder if there is an alternative.

Comment: @AlastairStuart -- there is indeed an alternative on OS X.  Use MacPorts to install GNU getopt (it will usually be installed into /opt/local/bin/getopt).

Comment: @UrbanVagabond – the installation of non system default tools is unfortunately not an acceptable requirement for a sufficiently portable tool.

Comment: @AlastairStuart – see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/28466267#28466267) for a portable solution that uses the getopts builtin rather than GNU getopt. It's the same as basic getopts usage but with an extra iteration for long options.

Answer (score 25):

Another way...

```
# translate long options to short
for arg
do
    delim=""
    case "$arg" in
       --help) args="${args}-h ";;
       --verbose) args="${args}-v ";;
       --config) args="${args}-c ";;
       # pass through anything else
       *) [[ "${arg:0:1}" == "-" ]] || delim="\""
           args="${args}${delim}${arg}${delim} ";;
    esac
done
# reset the translated args
eval set -- $args
# now we can process with getopt
while getopts ":hvc:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h)  usage ;;
        v)  VERBOSE=true ;;
        c)  source $OPTARG ;;
        \?) usage ;;
        :)
        echo "option -$OPTARG requires an argument"
        usage
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Doesn't this need a space in each `$args` reassignment?  This could even be done with out bashisms, but this code will lose spaces in options and arguments (I don't think the `$delim` trick will work).  You can instead run `set` _inside_ the `for` loop if you are careful enough to empty it on only the first iteration.  [Here is a safer version](https://gist.github.com/adamhotep/895cebf290e95e613c006afbffef09d7) without bashisms.

Answer (score 23):

I kind of solved this way:

```
# A string with command options
options=$@

# An array with all the arguments
arguments=($options)

# Loop index
index=0

for argument in $options
  do
    # Incrementing index
    index=`expr $index + 1`

    # The conditions
    case $argument in
      -a) echo "key $argument value ${arguments[index]}" ;;
      -abc) echo "key $argument value ${arguments[index]}" ;;
    esac
  done

exit;
```

Am I being dumb or something? `getopt` and `getopts` are so confusing.

Comment: This seems to work for me, I don't know what the problem is with this method, but it seems simple, so there must be a reason everyone else is not using it.

Comment: @Billy Yes, this is simple because I don't use any script to manage my parameters and etc. Basically I convert the arguments string ($@) to an array and I loop through it. In the loop, current value will be the key and the next one will be the value. Simple as that.

Comment: @Theodore I'm glad this was helpful to you! It was a pain to me as well. If you're interested, you can see an example of it in action here: https://raw.github.com/rafaelrinaldi/swf-to-html/master/swf-to-html.sh

Comment: Simple. It puts down the broad strokes. Thank you very much for you comment... I found you can do --option) or --option=*) on each case to handle both assignment types (spaces or equals).  With the later, just process $argument with: value=${argument/*=/""} instead of: ${arguments[index]} to get your value.

Comment: Definitely the easiest way I've seen. I changed it a bit such as using i=$(( $i + 1 )) instead of expr but the concept is air-tight.

Comment: You are not dumb at all, but you may be missing a feature: getopt(s) can recognise options that are mixed (ex:  `-ltr` or `-lt -r` as well as `-l -t -r` ). And it also provides some error handling, and an easy way to shift the treated parameters away once options treatment is finished.

Comment: Despite shortcomings described by @olivier-dulac this is the best answer in my opinion. By far the easiest to implement. One can also declare an associative array aa `declare -A aa`, populate it with `aa[$argument]=${arguments[index]}` and then fetch those arguments with `${aa["-a"]}`.

Answer (score 16):

In case you don't want the `getopt` dependency, you can do this:

```
while test $# -gt 0
do
  case $1 in

  # Normal option processing
    -h | --help)
      # usage and help
      ;;
    -v | --version)
      # version info
      ;;
  # ...

  # Special cases
    --)
      break
      ;;
    --*)
      # error unknown (long) option $1
      ;;
    -?)
      # error unknown (short) option $1
      ;;

  # FUN STUFF HERE:
  # Split apart combined short options
    -*)
      split=$1
      shift
      set -- $(echo "$split" | cut -c 2- | sed 's/./-& /g') "$@"
      continue
      ;;

  # Done with options
    *)
      break
      ;;
  esac

  # for testing purposes:
  echo "$1"

  shift
done
```

Of course, then you can't use long style options with one dash. And if you want to add shortened versions (e.g. --verbos instead of --verbose), then you need to add those manually.

But if you are looking to get `getopts` functionality along with long options, this is a simple way to do it.

I also put this snippet in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2221367).

Comment: This seems to only work with one long option at a time, but it met my need. Thank you!

Comment: In the special case `--)` there seems to be a `shift ;` missing. At the moment the `--` will stay as first non option argument.

Comment: I think that this is actually the better answer, though as dgw points out the `--` option needs a `shift` in there. I say this is better because the alternatives are either platform dependent versions of `getopt` or `getopts_long` or you have to force short-options to be used only at the start of the command (i.e - you use `getopts` then process long options afterwards), whereas this gives any order and complete control.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder why we have a thread of dozens of answers to do the job that can be done with nothing more than this *absolutely clear and straightforward* solution, and if there's any reason for the billion getopt(s) use cases other than proving oneself.

Answer (score 12):

The built-in `getopts` can't do this.  There is an external *getopt*(1) program that can do this, but you only get it on Linux from the *util-linux* package. It comes with an example script *getopt-parse.bash*.

There is also a [`getopts_long`](http://stchaz.free.fr/getopts_long) written as a shell function.

Comment: The `getopt` was included in FreeBSD version 1.0 in 1993, and has been part of FreeBSD since then.  As such, it was adopted from FreeBSD 4.x for inclusion in Apple's Darwin project.  As of OS X 10.6.8, the man page included by Apple remains an exact duplicate of the FreeBSD man page.  So yes, it's included in OS X and gobs of other operating systems beside Linux.  -1 on this answer for the misinformation.

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "abc:d:" flag
do
  case $flag in
    a) echo "[getopts:$OPTIND]==> -$flag";;
    b) echo "[getopts:$OPTIND]==> -$flag";;
    c) echo "[getopts:$OPTIND]==> -$flag $OPTARG";;
    d) echo "[getopts:$OPTIND]==> -$flag $OPTARG";;
  esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "[otheropts]==> $@"

exit
```

.

```
#!/bin/bash
until [ -z "$1" ]; do
  case $1 in
    "--dlong")
      shift
      if [ "${1:1:0}" != "-" ]
      then
        echo "==> dlong $1"
        shift
      fi;;
    *) echo "==> other $1"; shift;;
  esac
done
exit
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.  The first script accepts short options only while the second script has a bug in its long option argument parsing; its variable should be `"${1:0:1}"` for argument #1, substring at index 0, length 1. This does not permit mixing short and long options.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer does a very nice job of pointing out all the shortcomings of bash built-in `getopts`. The answer ends with:

> So while it is possible to write more code to work around the lack of support for long options, this is a lot more work and partially defeats the purpose of using a getopt parser to simplify your code.

And even though I agree in principle with that statement, I feel that the number of times we all implemented this feature in various scripts justifies putting a bit of effort into creating a "standardised", well tested solution.

As such, I've "upgraded" bash built in `getopts` by implementing [`getopts_long`](https://github.com/UrsaDK/getopts_long/blob/master/lib/getopts_long.bash) in pure bash, with no external dependencies. The usage of the function is 100% compatible  with the built-in `getopts`.

By including `getopts_long` (which is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/UrsaDK/getopts_long)) in a script, the answer to the original question can be implemented as simply as:

```sh
source "${PATH_TO}/getopts_long.bash"

while getopts_long ':c: copyfile:' OPTKEY; do
    case ${OPTKEY} in
        'c'|'copyfile')
            echo 'file supplied -- ${OPTARG}'
            ;;
        '?')
            echo "INVALID OPTION -- ${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        ':')
            echo "MISSING ARGUMENT for option -- ${OPTARG}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Misconfigured OPTSPEC or uncaught option -- ${OPTKEY}" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
[[ "${1}" == "--" ]] && shift
```

Comment: Nice work but wish to have different license like CC0 on that.

Comment: @kalib-zen: It's already licensed under [MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), which is one of the most permissive software licenses out there. Plus, Creative Commons themselves [discourage](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) the use of their licenses for software, though CC0 is a bit of a [special case](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F). Saying all that, I'm happy to consider dual licensing if you can make your case for CC0.

Answer (score 7):

In `ksh93`, `getopts` does support long names...

```
while getopts "f(file):s(server):" flag
do
    echo "$flag" $OPTIND $OPTARG
done
```

Or so the tutorials I have found have said.  Try it and see.

Comment: This is ksh93's getopts builtin. Apart from this syntax, it also has a more complicated syntax that also allows long options without a short equivalent, and more.

Comment: A reasonable answer.  The OP didn't specify WHAT shell.

Answer (score 6):

Inventing yet another version of the wheel...

This function is a (hopefully) POSIX-compatible plain bourne shell replacement for GNU getopt. It supports short/long options which can accept mandatory/optional/no arguments, and the way in which options are specified is almost identical to GNU getopt, so conversion is trivial.

Of course this is still a sizeable chunk of code to drop into a script, but it's about half the lines of the well-known getopt_long shell function, and might be preferable in cases where you just want to replace existing GNU getopt uses.

This is pretty new code, so YMMV (and definitely please let me know if this isn't actually POSIX-compatible for any reason -- portability was the intention from the outset, but I don't have a useful POSIX test environment).

Code and example usage follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# posix_getopt shell function
# Author: Phil S.
# Version: 1.0
# Created: 2016-07-05
# URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087374/324105

# POSIX-compatible argument quoting and parameter save/restore
# http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html
# Usage:
# parameters=$(save "$@") # save the original parameters.
# eval "set -- ${parameters}" # restore the saved parameters.
save () {
    local param
    for param; do
        printf %s\\n "$param" \
            | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/"
    done
    printf %s\\n " "
}

# Exit with status $1 after displaying error message $2.
exiterr () {
    printf %s\\n "$2" >&2
    exit $1
}

# POSIX-compatible command line option parsing.
# This function supports long options and optional arguments, and is
# a (largely-compatible) drop-in replacement for GNU getopt.
#
# Instead of:
# opts=$(getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -- "$@")
# eval set -- ${opts}
#
# We instead use:
# opts=$(posix_getopt "$shortopts" "$longopts" "$@")
# eval "set -- ${opts}"
posix_getopt () { # args: "$shortopts" "$longopts" "$@"
    local shortopts longopts \
          arg argtype getopt nonopt opt optchar optword suffix

    shortopts="$1"
    longopts="$2"
    shift 2

    getopt=
    nonopt=
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        opt=
        arg=
        argtype=
        case "$1" in
            # '--' means don't parse the remaining options
            ( -- ) {
                getopt="${getopt}$(save "$@")"
                shift $#
                break
            };;
            # process short option
            ( -[!-]* ) {         # -x[foo]
                suffix=${1#-?}   # foo
                opt=${1%$suffix} # -x
                optchar=${opt#-} # x
                case "${shortopts}" in
                    ( *${optchar}::* ) { # optional argument
                        argtype=optional
                        arg="${suffix}"
                        shift
                    };;
                    ( *${optchar}:* ) { # required argument
                        argtype=required
                        if [ -n "${suffix}" ]; then
                            arg="${suffix}"
                            shift
                        else
                            case "$2" in
                                ( -* ) exiterr 1 "$1 requires an argument";;
                                ( ?* ) arg="$2"; shift 2;;
                                (  * ) exiterr 1 "$1 requires an argument";;
                            esac
                        fi
                    };;
                    ( *${optchar}* ) { # no argument
                        argtype=none
                        arg=
                        shift
                        # Handle multiple no-argument parameters combined as
                        # -xyz instead of -x -y -z. If we have just shifted
                        # parameter -xyz, we now replace it with -yz (which
                        # will be processed in the next iteration).
                        if [ -n "${suffix}" ]; then
                            eval "set -- $(save "-${suffix}")$(save "$@")"
                        fi
                    };;
                    ( * ) exiterr 1 "Unknown option $1";;
                esac
            };;
            # process long option
            ( --?* ) {            # --xarg[=foo]
                suffix=${1#*=}    # foo (unless there was no =)
                if [ "${suffix}" = "$1" ]; then
                    suffix=
                fi
                opt=${1%=$suffix} # --xarg
                optword=${opt#--} # xarg
                case ",${longopts}," in
                    ( *,${optword}::,* ) { # optional argument
                        argtype=optional
                        arg="${suffix}"
                        shift
                    };;
                    ( *,${optword}:,* ) { # required argument
                        argtype=required
                        if [ -n "${suffix}" ]; then
                            arg="${suffix}"
                            shift
                        else
                            case "$2" in
                                ( -* ) exiterr 1 \
                                       "--${optword} requires an argument";;
                                ( ?* ) arg="$2"; shift 2;;
                                (  * ) exiterr 1 \
                                       "--${optword} requires an argument";;
                            esac
                        fi
                    };;
                    ( *,${optword},* ) { # no argument
                        if [ -n "${suffix}" ]; then
                            exiterr 1 "--${optword} does not take an argument"
                        fi
                        argtype=none
                        arg=
                        shift
                    };;
                    ( * ) exiterr 1 "Unknown option $1";;
                esac
            };;
            # any other parameters starting with -
            ( -* ) exiterr 1 "Unknown option $1";;
            # remember non-option parameters
            ( * ) nonopt="${nonopt}$(save "$1")"; shift;;
        esac

        if [ -n "${opt}" ]; then
            getopt="${getopt}$(save "$opt")"
            case "${argtype}" in
                ( optional|required ) {
                    getopt="${getopt}$(save "$arg")"
                };;
            esac
        fi
    done

    # Generate function output, suitable for:
    # eval "set -- $(posix_getopt ...)"
    printf %s "${getopt}"
    if [ -n "${nonopt}" ]; then
        printf %s "$(save "--")${nonopt}"
    fi
}
```

Example usage:

```sh
# Process command line options
shortopts="hvd:c::s::L:D"
longopts="help,version,directory:,client::,server::,load:,delete"
#opts=$(getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -n "$(basename $0)" -- "$@")
opts=$(posix_getopt "$shortopts" "$longopts" "$@")
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #eval set -- ${opts}
    eval "set -- ${opts}"
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
            ( --                ) shift; break;;
            ( -h|--help         ) help=1; shift; break;;
            ( -v|--version      ) version_help=1; shift; break;;
            ( -d|--directory    ) dir=$2; shift 2;;
            ( -c|--client       ) useclient=1; client=$2; shift 2;;
            ( -s|--server       ) startserver=1; server_name=$2; shift 2;;
            ( -L|--load         ) load=$2; shift 2;;
            ( -D|--delete       ) delete=1; shift;;
        esac
    done
else
    shorthelp=1 # getopt returned (and reported) an error.
fi
```

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what `eval set` precisely does. Is it safe?

Comment: It's safe if the arguments (following all the normal shell substitution and expansion processes) produce a safe expression.  In this case we're producing a `set -- ...` command, which the man page for [dash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) explains like so:  "The third use of the set command is to set the values of the shell's positional parameters to the specified args.  To change the positional parameters without changing any options, use “--” as the first argument to set." (POSIX shell docs say the same, but less clearly.)

Comment: Thank you. I did not fully understand two things yet. 1. Why is "eval" needed? My research only shows that you need it when using GNU getopt. But why? 2. Can we assume that "the arguments produce a safe expression"?

Comment: `eval` is needed because we both (GNU getopt and posix_getopt) support options containing special characters by virtue of generating a string of *shell-quoted values* which, once `eval`uated, will produce the original values again (now manipulated into a normalised format ready for processing).  For instance, the space in `--foo="hello, world."` would be a problem otherwise.  The return value of `posix_getopt` must be passed through `eval` in the manner demonstrated in order to work.

Comment: Regarding (2), all I can say is that *I'm* confident that a safe expression is produced (I wrote this for my own usage, after all), but I'm not sure I can do more than encourage you to read/understand the code in order to convince yourself of the same thing.  To get a sense of what's going on, you might try passing various "unsafe" input to it, and then instead of `eval "set -- ${opts}"`, instead `echo "set -- ${opts}"` to see what *would* be evaluated.

Comment: See also the heading "Working with arrays" at http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html which explains the technique in question in some detail.

Answer (score 6):

I only write shell scripts now and then and fall out of practice, so any feedback is appreciated.

Using the strategy proposed by @Arvid Requate, we noticed some user errors. A user who forgets to include a value will accidentally have the next option's name treated as a value:

```
./getopts_test.sh --loglevel= --toc=TRUE
```

will cause the value of "loglevel" to be seen as "--toc=TRUE". This can
be avoided.

I adapted some ideas about checking user error for CLI from  http://mwiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 discussion of manual parsing. I inserted error checking into handling both "-" and "--" arguments.

Then I started fiddling around with the syntax, so any errors in here are strictly my fault, not the original authors.

My approach helps users who prefer to enter long with or without the equal sign. That is, it should have same response to "--loglevel 9" as "--loglevel=9". In the --/space method, it is not possible to know for sure if the user forgets an argument, so some guessing is needed.

1. if the user has the long/equal sign format (--opt=), then a space after = triggers an error because an argument was not supplied.
2. if user has long/space arguments (--opt ), this script causes a fail if no argument follows (end of command) or if argument begins with dash)

In case you are starting out on this, there is an interesting difference between "--opt=value" and "--opt value" formats. With the equal sign, the command line argument is seen as "opt=value" and the work to handle that is string parsing, to separate at the "=".  In contrast, with "--opt value", the name of the argument is "opt" and we have the challenge of getting the next value supplied in the command line.  That's where @Arvid Requate used ${!OPTIND}, the indirect reference. I still don't understand that, well, at all, and comments in BashFAQ seem to warn against that style (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). BTW, I don't think previous poster's comments about importance of  OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 )) are correct. I mean to say, I see no harm from omitting it.

In newest version of this script, flag -v means VERBOSE printout.

Save it in a file called "cli-5.sh", make executable, and any of these will work, or fail in the desired way

```
./cli-5.sh  -v --loglevel=44 --toc  TRUE
./cli-5.sh  -v --loglevel=44 --toc=TRUE
./cli-5.sh --loglevel 7
./cli-5.sh --loglevel=8
./cli-5.sh -l9

./cli-5.sh  --toc FALSE --loglevel=77
./cli-5.sh  --toc=FALSE --loglevel=77

./cli-5.sh   -l99 -t yyy
./cli-5.sh   -l 99 -t yyy
```

Here is example output of the error-checking on user intpu

```
$ ./cli-5.sh  --toc --loglevel=77
ERROR: toc value must not have dash at beginning
$ ./cli-5.sh  --toc= --loglevel=77
ERROR: value for toc undefined
```

You should consider turning on -v, because it prints out internals of OPTIND and OPTARG

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

## Paul Johnson
## 20171016
##

## Combines ideas from
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options
## by @Arvid Requate, and http://mwiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

# What I don't understand yet: 
# In @Arvid REquate's answer, we have 
# val="${!OPTIND}"; OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))
# this works, but I don't understand it!


die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

printparse(){
    if [ ${VERBOSE} -gt 0 ]; then
        printf 'Parse: %s%s%s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3" >&2;
    fi
}

showme(){
    if [ ${VERBOSE} -gt 0 ]; then
        printf 'VERBOSE: %s\n' "$1" >&2;
    fi
}


VERBOSE=0
loglevel=0
toc="TRUE"

optspec=":vhl:t:-:"
while getopts "$optspec" OPTCHAR; do

    showme "OPTARG:  ${OPTARG[*]}"
    showme "OPTIND:  ${OPTIND[*]}"
    case "${OPTCHAR}" in
        -)
            case "${OPTARG}" in
                loglevel) #argument has no equal sign
                    opt=${OPTARG}
                    val="${!OPTIND}"
                    ## check value. If negative, assume user forgot value
                    showme "OPTIND is {$OPTIND} {!OPTIND} has value \"${!OPTIND}\""
                    if [[ "$val" == -* ]]; then
                        die "ERROR: $opt value must not have dash at beginning"
                    fi
                    ## OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 )) # CAUTION! no effect?
                    printparse "--${OPTARG}" "  " "${val}"
                    loglevel="${val}"
                    shift
                    ;;
                loglevel=*) #argument has equal sign
                    opt=${OPTARG%=*}
                    val=${OPTARG#*=}
                    if [ "${OPTARG#*=}" ]; then
                        printparse "--${opt}" "=" "${val}"
                        loglevel="${val}"
                        ## shift CAUTION don't shift this, fails othewise
                    else
                        die "ERROR: $opt value must be supplied"
                    fi
                    ;;
                toc) #argument has no equal sign
                    opt=${OPTARG}
                    val="${!OPTIND}"
                    ## check value. If negative, assume user forgot value
                    showme "OPTIND is {$OPTIND} {!OPTIND} has value \"${!OPTIND}\""
                    if [[ "$val" == -* ]]; then
                        die "ERROR: $opt value must not have dash at beginning"
                    fi
                    ## OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 )) #??
                    printparse "--${opt}" " " "${val}"
                    toc="${val}"
                    shift
                    ;;
                toc=*) #argument has equal sign
                    opt=${OPTARG%=*}
                    val=${OPTARG#*=}
                    if [ "${OPTARG#*=}" ]; then
                        toc=${val}
                        printparse "--$opt" " -> " "$toc"
                        ##shift ## NO! dont shift this
                    else
                        die "ERROR: value for $opt undefined"
                    fi
                    ;;

                help)
                    echo "usage: $0 [-v] [--loglevel[=]<value>] [--toc[=]<TRUE,FALSE>]" >&2
                    exit 2
                    ;;
                *)
                    if [ "$OPTERR" = 1 ] && [ "${optspec:0:1}" != ":" ]; then
                        echo "Unknown option --${OPTARG}" >&2
                    fi
                    ;;
            esac;;
        h|-\?|--help)
            ## must rewrite this for all of the arguments
            echo "usage: $0 [-v] [--loglevel[=]<value>] [--toc[=]<TRUE,FALSE>]" >&2
            exit 2
            ;;
        l)
            loglevel=${OPTARG}
            printparse "-l" " "  "${loglevel}"
            ;;
        t)
            toc=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        v)
            VERBOSE=1
            ;;

        *)
            if [ "$OPTERR" != 1 ] || [ "${optspec:0:1}" = ":" ]; then
                echo "Non-option argument: '-${OPTARG}'" >&2
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done



echo "
After Parsing values
"
echo "loglevel  $loglevel" 
echo "toc  $toc"
```

Comment: `OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 ))` : it is needed whenever you 'gobble' the OPTIND's parameter (for ex: when one used `--toc  value`  :   value is in parameter number $OPTIND . Once you retrieve it for toc's value, you should tell getopts that the next parameter to parse is not value, but the one after it (hence the : `OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND + 1 )) `.
and your script (as well as the script you refer to) are missing, after the done : `shift $(( $OPTIND -1 ))` (as getopts exited after parsing parameterrs 1 to OPTIND-1, you need to shift them out so `$@` is now any remaining "non-options" parameters

Comment: oh, as you shift yourself, you "shift" the parameters underneath getopts, so OPTIND is always pointing the right thing... but I find it very confusing. I believe (can't test your script right now) that you still need the shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 )) after the getopts while loop, so that $1 now doesn't point to the original $1 (an option) but to the first of the remaining arguments (the ones comming after all options and their values).  ex:       myrm -foo  -bar=baz  thisarg thenthisone thenanother

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep yet to comment or vote his solution up, but [sme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5230306/874188) worked extremely well for me. The only issue I ran into was that the arguments end up wrapped in single-quotes (so I have an strip them out).

I also added some example usages and HELP text.  I'll included my slightly extended version here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# getopt example
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options
HELP_TEXT=\
"   USAGE:\n
    Accepts - and -- flags, can specify options that require a value, and can be in any order. A double-hyphen (--) will stop processing options.\n\n

    Accepts the following forms:\n\n

    getopt-example.sh -a -b -c value-for-c some-arg\n
    getopt-example.sh -c value-for-c -a -b some-arg\n
    getopt-example.sh -abc some-arg\n
    getopt-example.sh --along --blong --clong value-for-c -a -b -c some-arg\n
    getopt-example.sh some-arg --clong value-for-c\n
    getopt-example.sh
"

aflag=false
bflag=false
cargument=""

# options may be followed by one colon to indicate they have a required argument
if ! options=$(getopt -o abc:h\? -l along,blong,help,clong: -- "$@")
then
    # something went wrong, getopt will put out an error message for us
    exit 1
fi

set -- $options

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    -a|--along) aflag=true ;;
    -b|--blong) bflag=true ;;
    # for options with required arguments, an additional shift is required
    -c|--clong) cargument="$2" ; shift;;
    -h|--help|-\?) echo -e $HELP_TEXT; exit;;
    (--) shift; break;;
    (-*) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    (*) break;;
    esac
    shift
done

# to remove the single quotes around arguments, pipe the output into:
# | sed -e "s/^'\\|'$//g"  (just leading/trailing) or | sed -e "s/'//g"  (all)

echo aflag=${aflag}
echo bflag=${bflag}
echo cargument=${cargument}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo arg=$1
    shift

    if [[ $aflag == true ]]; then
        echo a is true
    fi

done
```

Comment: Just use -u as argument to getopt and you get unquotes values.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find a few different approaches for complex option parsing in bash:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing

I did create the following one, and I think it's a good one, because it's minimal code
and both long and short options work. A long option can also have multiple arguments with this approach.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Uses bash extensions.  Not portable as written.

declare -A longoptspec
longoptspec=( [loglevel]=1 ) #use associative array to declare how many arguments a long option expects, in this case we declare that loglevel expects/has one argument, long options that aren't listed i n this way will have zero arguments by default
optspec=":h-:"
while getopts "$optspec" opt; do
while true; do
    case "${opt}" in
        -) #OPTARG is name-of-long-option or name-of-long-option=value
            if [[ "${OPTARG}" =~ .*=.* ]] #with this --key=value format only one argument is possible
            then
                opt=${OPTARG/=*/}
                OPTARG=${OPTARG#*=}
                ((OPTIND--))    
            else #with this --key value1 value2 format multiple arguments are possible
                opt="$OPTARG"
                OPTARG=(${@:OPTIND:$((longoptspec[$opt]))})
            fi
            ((OPTIND+=longoptspec[$opt]))
            continue #now that opt/OPTARG are set we can process them as if getopts would've given us long options
            ;;
        loglevel)
          loglevel=$OPTARG
            ;;
        h|help)
            echo "usage: $0 [--loglevel[=]<value>]" >&2
            exit 2
            ;;
    esac
break; done
done

# End of file
```

Answer (score 3):

if simply this is how you want to call the script

```
myscript.sh --input1 "ABC" --input2 "PQR" --input2 "XYZ"
```

then you can follow this simplest way to achieve it with the help of getopt and --longoptions

try this , hope this is useful

```
# Read command line options
ARGUMENT_LIST=(
    "input1"
    "input2"
    "input3"
)



# read arguments
opts=$(getopt \
    --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")" \
    --name "$(basename "$0")" \
    --options "" \
    -- "$@"
)


echo $opts

eval set --$opts

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    --input1)  
        shift
        empId=$1
        ;;
    --input2)  
        shift
        fromDate=$1
        ;;
    --input3)  
        shift
        toDate=$1
        ;;
      --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Comment: how to add short options?

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on that subject for quite a long time... and made my own library which you will need to source in your main script.
See [libopt4shell](http://liealgebra.free.fr/libopt4shell) and [cd2mpc](http://liealgebra.free.fr/cd2mpc) for an example.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

An improved solution:

```
# translate long options to short
# Note: This enable long options but disable "--?*" in $OPTARG, or disable long options after  "--" in option fields.
for ((i=1;$#;i++)) ; do
    case "$1" in
        --)
            # [ ${args[$((i-1))]} == ... ] || EndOpt=1 ;;& # DIRTY: we still can handle some execptions...
            EndOpt=1 ;;&
        --version) ((EndOpt)) && args[$i]="$1"  || args[$i]="-V";;
        # default case : short option use the first char of the long option:
        --?*) ((EndOpt)) && args[$i]="$1"  || args[$i]="-${1:2:1}";;
        # pass through anything else:
        *) args[$i]="$1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done
# reset the translated args
set -- "${args[@]}"

function usage {
echo "Usage: $0 [options] files" >&2
    exit $1
}

# now we can process with getopt
while getopts ":hvVc:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h)  usage ;;
        v)  VERBOSE=true ;;
        V)  echo $Version ; exit ;;
        c)  source $OPTARG ;;
        \?) echo "unrecognized option: -$opt" ; usage -1 ;;
        :)
        echo "option -$OPTARG requires an argument"
        usage -1
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
[[ "$1" == "--" ]] && shift
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's simpler to use ksh, just for the getopts part, if need long command line options, as it can be easier done there.

```
# Working Getopts Long => KSH

#! /bin/ksh
# Getopts Long
USAGE="s(showconfig)"
USAGE+="c:(createdb)"
USAGE+="l:(createlistener)"
USAGE+="g:(generatescripts)"
USAGE+="r:(removedb)"
USAGE+="x:(removelistener)"
USAGE+="t:(createtemplate)"
USAGE+="h(help)"

while getopts "$USAGE" optchar ; do
    case $optchar in
    s)  echo "Displaying Configuration" ;;
        c)  echo "Creating Database $OPTARG" ;;
    l)  echo "Creating Listener LISTENER_$OPTARG" ;;
    g)  echo "Generating Scripts for Database $OPTARG" ;;
    r)  echo "Removing Database $OPTARG" ;;
    x)  echo "Removing Listener LISTENER_$OPTARG" ;;
    t)  echo "Creating Database Template" ;;
    h)  echo "Help" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: +1 -- Note that this is limited to ksh93 - from the open source AST project (AT&T Research).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something without external dependencies, with strict bash support (-u), and I needed it to work on even the older bash versions. This handles various types of params:

- short bools (-h)
- short options (-i "image.jpg")
- long bools (--help)
- equals options (--file="filename.ext")
- space options (--file "filename.ext")
- concatinated bools (-hvm)

Just insert the following at the top of your script:

```
# Check if a list of params contains a specific param
# usage: if _param_variant "h|?|help p|path f|file long-thing t|test-thing" "file" ; then ...
# the global variable $key is updated to the long notation (last entry in the pipe delineated list, if applicable)
_param_variant() {
  for param in $1 ; do
    local variants=${param//\|/ }
    for variant in $variants ; do
      if [[ "$variant" = "$2" ]] ; then
        # Update the key to match the long version
        local arr=(${param//\|/ })
        let last=${#arr[@]}-1
        key="${arr[$last]}"
        return 0
      fi
    done
  done
  return 1
}

# Get input parameters in short or long notation, with no dependencies beyond bash
# usage:
#     # First, set your defaults
#     param_help=false
#     param_path="."
#     param_file=false
#     param_image=false
#     param_image_lossy=true
#     # Define allowed parameters
#     allowed_params="h|?|help p|path f|file i|image image-lossy"
#     # Get parameters from the arguments provided
#     _get_params $*
#
# Parameters will be converted into safe variable names like:
#     param_help,
#     param_path,
#     param_file,
#     param_image,
#     param_image_lossy
#
# Parameters without a value like "-h" or "--help" will be treated as
# boolean, and will be set as param_help=true
#
# Parameters can accept values in the various typical ways:
#     -i "path/goes/here"
#     --image "path/goes/here"
#     --image="path/goes/here"
#     --image=path/goes/here
# These would all result in effectively the same thing:
#     param_image="path/goes/here"
#
# Concatinated short parameters (boolean) are also supported
#     -vhm is the same as -v -h -m
_get_params(){

  local param_pair
  local key
  local value
  local shift_count

  while : ; do
    # Ensure we have a valid param. Allows this to work even in -u mode.
    if [[ $# == 0 || -z $1 ]] ; then
      break
    fi

    # Split the argument if it contains "="
    param_pair=(${1//=/ })
    # Remove preceeding dashes
    key="${param_pair[0]#--}"

    # Check for concatinated boolean short parameters.
    local nodash="${key#-}"
    local breakout=false
    if [[ "$nodash" != "$key" && ${#nodash} -gt 1 ]]; then
      # Extrapolate multiple boolean keys in single dash notation. ie. "-vmh" should translate to: "-v -m -h"
      local short_param_count=${#nodash}
      let new_arg_count=$#+$short_param_count-1
      local new_args=""
      # $str_pos is the current position in the short param string $nodash
      for (( str_pos=0; str_pos<new_arg_count; str_pos++ )); do
        # The first character becomes the current key
        if [ $str_pos -eq 0 ] ; then
          key="${nodash:$str_pos:1}"
          breakout=true
        fi
        # $arg_pos is the current position in the constructed arguments list
        let arg_pos=$str_pos+1
        if [ $arg_pos -gt $short_param_count ] ; then
          # handle other arguments
          let orignal_arg_number=$arg_pos-$short_param_count+1
          local new_arg="${!orignal_arg_number}"
        else
          # break out our one argument into new ones
          local new_arg="-${nodash:$str_pos:1}"
        fi
        new_args="$new_args \"$new_arg\""
      done
      # remove the preceding space and set the new arguments
      eval set -- "${new_args# }"
    fi
    if ! $breakout ; then
      key="$nodash"
    fi

    # By default we expect to shift one argument at a time
    shift_count=1
    if [ "${#param_pair[@]}" -gt "1" ] ; then
      # This is a param with equals notation
      value="${param_pair[1]}"
    else
      # This is either a boolean param and there is no value,
      # or the value is the next command line argument
      # Assume the value is a boolean true, unless the next argument is found to be a value.
      value=true
      if [[ $# -gt 1 && -n "$2" ]]; then
        local nodash="${2#-}"
        if [ "$nodash" = "$2" ]; then
          # The next argument has NO preceding dash so it is a value
          value="$2"
          shift_count=2
        fi
      fi
    fi

    # Check that the param being passed is one of the allowed params
    if _param_variant "$allowed_params" "$key" ; then
      # --key-name will now become param_key_name
      eval param_${key//-/_}="$value"
    else
      printf 'WARNING: Unknown option (ignored): %s\n' "$1" >&2
    fi
    shift $shift_count
  done
}
```

And use it like so:

```
# Assign defaults for parameters
param_help=false
param_path=$(pwd)
param_file=false
param_image=true
param_image_lossy=true
param_image_lossy_quality=85

# Define the params we will allow
allowed_params="h|?|help p|path f|file i|image image-lossy image-lossy-quality"

# Get the params from arguments provided
_get_params $*
```

Answer (score 2):

It took some time, but I wanted it all:

- short options
- long options
- with or without arguments
- non-option arguments (those without "-" or "--")
- order shouldn't matter (`script.sh /file -V` or `script.sh -V /file`)
- catch wrong usage
- use it as a module in different scripts without the need to change multiple lines of code

Finally I came up with the following solution, which uses `getopt` to catch errors and move non-options to the end of the list and after that `getopts`, which parses the short and long options.

All options are automatically parsed with their long option name as variable name (look at the example):

```
# create string of short options
opt_short=$(printf "%s" "${!options[@]}")

# create string of long options
opt_long="$(printf ",%s" "${options[@]}")"

# catch wrong options and move non-options to the end of the string
args=$(getopt -l "$opt_long" "$opt_short" "$@" 2> >(sed -e 's/^/stderr/g')) || echo -n "Error: " && echo "$args" | grep -oP "(?<=^stderr).*" && exit 1

# create new array of options
mapfile -t args < <(xargs -n1 <<< "$(echo "$args" | sed -E "s/(--[^ ]+) '/\1='/g")" )

# overwrite $@ (options)
set -- "${args[@]}"

# parse options ([h]=help sets the variable "$opt_help" and [V]="" sets the variable "$opt_V")
while getopts "$opt_short-:" opt; do

  echo "$opt:$OPTARG"

  # long option
  if [[ "$opt" == "-" ]]; then

    # extract long option name
    opt="${OPTARG%%=*}"

    # extract long option argument (may be empty)
    OPTARG="${OPTARG#"$opt"}"

    # remove "=" from long option argument
    OPTARG="${OPTARG#=}"

    # set variable name
    opt=opt_$opt

  # short option without argument uses long option name as variable name
  elif [[ "${options[$opt]+x}" ]] && [[ "${options[$opt]}" ]]; then
    opt=opt_${options[$opt]} 

  # short option with argument uses long option name as variable name
  elif [[ "${options[$opt:]+x}" ]] && [[ "${options[$opt:]}" ]]; then
    opt=opt_${options[$opt:]} 

  # short option without long option name uses short option name as variable name
  else
    opt=opt_$opt
  fi

  # remove double colon
  opt="${opt%:}" 

  # options without arguments are set to 1
  [[ ! $OPTARG ]] && OPTARG=1 

  # replace hyphen against underscore
  opt="${opt//-/_}"

  # set variable variables (replaces hyphen against underscore)
  printf -v "$opt" '%s' "$OPTARG" 

done
```

Now, I only need to define the needed option names and `source` the script:

```
# import options module
declare -A options=( [h]=help [f:]=file: [V]=verbose [0]=long_only: [s]="" )
source "/usr/local/bin/inc/options.sh";

# display help text
if [[ $opt_help ]]; then
  echo "help text"
  exit
fi

# output
echo "opt_help:$opt_help"
echo "opt_file:$opt_file"
echo "opt_verbose:$opt_verbose"
echo "opt_long_only:$opt_long_only"
echo "opt_short_only:$opt_s"
echo "opt_path:$1"
echo "opt_mail:$2"
```

And while calling the script, it's possible to pass all options and non-options in a complete random order:

```
#             $opt_file     $1        $2       $opt_V  $opt_long_only $opt_s
# /demo.sh --file=file.txt /dir info@example.com -V --long_only=yes -s
opt_help:1
opt_file:file.txt
opt_verbose:1
opt_long_only:yes
opt_short_only:1
opt_path=/dir
opt_mail:info@example.com
```

**Notes**

- In the `options` array add `:` after an option name to enable arguments.
- If no long option name is given, the variable name will be `$opt_X`, where `X` is the short option name.
- If you want to use a long option name without defining a short option name, then set the array index to a number as in the above example done with `[0]=long_only`. Of course every array index must be unique.

**Used techniques**

- [Capture `stderr` without using a temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266870/318765)
- [Convert string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61474683/318765)
- [Use `:` to parse arguments with `getopt`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674277/318765)
- [Parse long option names with `getopts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/318765)

Comment: Any idea why this is not working on macOS? I'm getting the error `b:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")` for `declare -A options=( [h]=help [b:]=batchId:...` part.

Answer (score 1):

getopts "could be used" for parsing long options as long as you don't expect them to have arguments...

Here's how to:

```
$ cat > longopt
while getopts 'e:-:' OPT; do
  case $OPT in
    e) echo echo: $OPTARG;;
    -) #long option
       case $OPTARG in
         long-option) echo long option;;
         *) echo long option: $OPTARG;;
       esac;;
  esac
done

$ bash longopt -e asd --long-option --long1 --long2 -e test
echo: asd
long option
long option: long1
long option: long2
echo: test
```

If you try to use OPTIND for getting a parameter for the long option, getopts will treat it as the first no optional positional parameter and will stop parsing any other parameters. 
In such a case you'll be better off handling it manually with a simple case statement.

This will "always" work:

```
$ cat >longopt2
while (($#)); do
    OPT=$1
    shift
    case $OPT in
        --*) case ${OPT:2} in
            long1) echo long1 option;;
            complex) echo comples with argument $1; shift;;
        esac;;

        -*) case ${OPT:1} in
            a) echo short option a;;
            b) echo short option b with parameter $1; shift;;
        esac;;
    esac
done


$ bash longopt2 --complex abc -a --long -b test
comples with argument abc
short option a
short option b with parameter test
```

Albeit is not as flexible as getopts and you have to do much of the error checking code yourself within the case instances...

But it is an option.

Comment: But long options often do expect arguments. And you could do more with the *-* to make it work even though it's something of a hack. In the end one could argue that if it does not natively support it then every way of implementing it is something of a hack but nevertheless you could extend the *-* too. And yes *shift* is very useful but of course if it expects an argument it could end up that the next argument (if none specified by user) is part of the expected argument.

Comment: yes, this is a poc for long arguments name without arguments, to diferentiate between the two you need some kind of configuration, like getops. And regarding shift, you can always "put it back"  with set. In any case it must be configurable if a parameter is expected or not. You could even use some magic for it, but then you'll force users to use -- to signal that the magic stops and positional parameters start, which is worse imho.

Comment: Fair enough. That's more than reasonable. Tbh I don't even remember what I was going on about and I had totally forgotten about this question itself. I only vaguely remember how I found it even. Cheers. Oh and have a +1 for the idea. You went through the effort and you also clarified what you were getting at. I respect people who do go through the effort to give others ideas etc.

Answer (score 1):

If all your long options have unique, and matching, first characters as the short options, so for example

```
./slamm --chaos 23 --plenty test -quiet
```

Is the same as

```
./slamm -c 23 -p test -q
```

You can use this *before* getopts to rewrite $args:

```
# change long options to short options

for arg; do 
    [[ "${arg:0:1}" == "-" ]] && delim="" || delim="\""
    if [ "${arg:0:2}" == "--" ]; 
       then args="${args} -${arg:2:1}" 
       else args="${args} ${delim}${arg}${delim}"
    fi
done

# reset the incoming args
eval set -- $args

# proceed as usual
while getopts ":b:la:h" OPTION; do
    .....
```

Thanks for mtvee for the inspiration ;-)

Comment: I don't get the significance of eval here

Answer (score 1):

In order to stay cross-platform compatible, and avoid the reliance on external executables, I ported some code from another language.

I find it very easy to use, here is an example:

```
ArgParser::addArg "[h]elp"    false    "This list"
ArgParser::addArg "[q]uiet"   false    "Supress output"
ArgParser::addArg "[s]leep"   1        "Seconds to sleep"
ArgParser::addArg "v"         1        "Verbose mode"

ArgParser::parse "$@"

ArgParser::isset help && ArgParser::showArgs

ArgParser::isset "quiet" \
   && echo "Quiet!" \
   || echo "Noisy!"

local __sleep
ArgParser::tryAndGetArg sleep into __sleep \
   && echo "Sleep for $__sleep seconds" \
   || echo "No value passed for sleep"

# This way is often more convienient, but is a little slower
echo "Sleep set to: $( ArgParser::getArg sleep )"
```

The required BASH is a little longer than it could be, but I wanted to avoid reliance on BASH 4's associative arrays.  You can also download this directly from http://nt4.com/bash/argparser.inc.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Updates to this script may be found at
# http://nt4.com/bash/argparser.inc.sh

# Example of runtime usage:
# mnc.sh --nc -q Caprica.S0*mkv *.avi *.mp3 --more-options here --host centos8.host.com

# Example of use in script (see bottom)
# Just include this file in yours, or use
# source argparser.inc.sh

unset EXPLODED
declare -a EXPLODED
function explode 
{
    local c=$# 
    (( c < 2 )) && 
    {
        echo function "$0" is missing parameters 
        return 1
    }

    local delimiter="$1"
    local string="$2"
    local limit=${3-99}

    local tmp_delim=$'\x07'
    local delin=${string//$delimiter/$tmp_delim}
    local oldifs="$IFS"

    IFS="$tmp_delim"
    EXPLODED=($delin)
    IFS="$oldifs"
}


# See: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference
# Usage: local "$1" && upvar $1 "value(s)"
upvar() {
    if unset -v "$1"; then           # Unset & validate varname
        if (( $# == 2 )); then
            eval $1=\"\$2\"          # Return single value
        else
            eval $1=\(\"\${@:2}\"\)  # Return array
        fi
    fi
}

function decho
{
    :
}

function ArgParser::check
{
    __args=${#__argparser__arglist[@]}
    for (( i=0; i<__args; i++ ))
    do
        matched=0
        explode "|" "${__argparser__arglist[$i]}"
        if [ "${#1}" -eq 1 ]
        then
            if [ "${1}" == "${EXPLODED[0]}" ]
            then
                decho "Matched $1 with ${EXPLODED[0]}"
                matched=1

                break
            fi
        else
            if [ "${1}" == "${EXPLODED[1]}" ]
            then
                decho "Matched $1 with ${EXPLODED[1]}"
                matched=1

                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    (( matched == 0 )) && return 2
    # decho "Key $key has default argument of ${EXPLODED[3]}"
    if [ "${EXPLODED[3]}" == "false" ]
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

function ArgParser::set
{
    key=$3
    value="${1:-true}"
    declare -g __argpassed__$key="$value"
}

function ArgParser::parse
{

    unset __argparser__argv
    __argparser__argv=()
    # echo parsing: "$@"

    while [ -n "$1" ]
    do
        # echo "Processing $1"
        if [ "${1:0:2}" == '--' ]
        then
            key=${1:2}
            value=$2
        elif [ "${1:0:1}" == '-' ]
        then
            key=${1:1}               # Strip off leading -
            value=$2
        else
            decho "Not argument or option: '$1'" >& 2
            __argparser__argv+=( "$1" )
            shift
            continue
        fi
        # parameter=${tmp%%=*}     # Extract name.
        # value=${tmp##*=}         # Extract value.
        decho "Key: '$key', value: '$value'"
        # eval $parameter=$value
        ArgParser::check $key
        el=$?
        # echo "Check returned $el for $key"
        [ $el -eq  2 ] && decho "No match for option '$1'" >&2 # && __argparser__argv+=( "$1" )
        [ $el -eq  0 ] && decho "Matched option '${EXPLODED[2]}' with no arguments"        >&2 && ArgParser::set true "${EXPLODED[@]}"
        [ $el -eq  1 ] && decho "Matched option '${EXPLODED[2]}' with an argument of '$2'"   >&2 && ArgParser::set "$2" "${EXPLODED[@]}" && shift
        shift
    done
}

function ArgParser::isset
{
    declare -p "__argpassed__$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 && return 0
    return 1
}

function ArgParser::getArg
{
    # This one would be a bit silly, since we can only return non-integer arguments ineffeciently
    varname="__argpassed__$1"
    echo "${!varname}"
}

##
# usage: tryAndGetArg <argname> into <varname>
# returns: 0 on success, 1 on failure
function ArgParser::tryAndGetArg
{
    local __varname="__argpassed__$1"
    local __value="${!__varname}"
    test -z "$__value" && return 1
    local "$3" && upvar $3 "$__value"
    return 0
}

function ArgParser::__construct
{
    unset __argparser__arglist
    # declare -a __argparser__arglist
}

##
# @brief add command line argument
# @param 1 short and/or long, eg: [s]hort
# @param 2 default value
# @param 3 description
##
function ArgParser::addArg
{
    # check for short arg within long arg
    if [[ "$1" =~ \[(.)\] ]]
    then
        short=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        long=${1/\[$short\]/$short}
    else
        long=$1
    fi
    if [ "${#long}" -eq 1 ]
    then
        short=$long
        long=''
    fi
    decho short: "$short"
    decho long: "$long"
    __argparser__arglist+=("$short|$long|$1|$2|$3")
}

## 
# @brief show available command line arguments
##
function ArgParser::showArgs
{
    # declare -p | grep argparser
    printf "Usage: %s [OPTION...]\n\n" "$( basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
    printf "Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.\n\n";

    __args=${#__argparser__arglist[@]}
    for (( i=0; i<__args; i++ ))
    do
        local shortname=
        local fullname=
        local default=
        local description=
        local comma=

        explode "|" "${__argparser__arglist[$i]}"

        shortname="${EXPLODED[0]:+-${EXPLODED[0]}}" # String Substitution Guide: 
        fullname="${EXPLODED[1]:+--${EXPLODED[1]}}" # http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
        test -n "$shortname" \
            && test -n "$fullname" \
            && comma=","

        default="${EXPLODED[3]}"
        case $default in
            false )
                default=
                ;;
            "" )
                default=
                ;;
            * )
                default="[$default]"
        esac

        description="${EXPLODED[4]}"

        printf "  %2s%1s %-19s %s %s\n" "$shortname" "$comma" "$fullname" "$description" "$default"
    done
}

function ArgParser::test
{
    # Arguments with a default of 'false' do not take paramaters (note: default
    # values are not applied in this release)

    ArgParser::addArg "[h]elp"      false       "This list"
    ArgParser::addArg "[q]uiet" false       "Supress output"
    ArgParser::addArg "[s]leep" 1           "Seconds to sleep"
    ArgParser::addArg "v"           1           "Verbose mode"

    ArgParser::parse "$@"

    ArgParser::isset help && ArgParser::showArgs

    ArgParser::isset "quiet" \
        && echo "Quiet!" \
        || echo "Noisy!"

    local __sleep
    ArgParser::tryAndGetArg sleep into __sleep \
        && echo "Sleep for $__sleep seconds" \
        || echo "No value passed for sleep"

    # This way is often more convienient, but is a little slower
    echo "Sleep set to: $( ArgParser::getArg sleep )"

    echo "Remaining command line: ${__argparser__argv[@]}"

}

if [ "$( basename "$0" )" == "argparser.inc.sh" ]
then
    ArgParser::test "$@"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Builtin `getopts`** only parse short options (except in ksh93),
but you can still add few lines of scripting to make getopts handles long options.

Here is a part of code found in http://www.uxora.com/unix/shell-script/22-handle-long-options-with-getopts

```
  #== set short options ==#
SCRIPT_OPTS=':fbF:B:-:h'
  #== set long options associated with short one ==#
typeset -A ARRAY_OPTS
ARRAY_OPTS=(
    [foo]=f
    [bar]=b
    [foobar]=F
    [barfoo]=B
    [help]=h
    [man]=h
)

  #== parse options ==#
while getopts ${SCRIPT_OPTS} OPTION ; do
    #== translate long options to short ==#
    if [[ "x$OPTION" == "x-" ]]; then
        LONG_OPTION=$OPTARG
        LONG_OPTARG=$(echo $LONG_OPTION | grep "=" | cut -d'=' -f2)
        LONG_OPTIND=-1
        [[ "x$LONG_OPTARG" = "x" ]] && LONG_OPTIND=$OPTIND || LONG_OPTION=$(echo $OPTARG | cut -d'=' -f1)
        [[ $LONG_OPTIND -ne -1 ]] && eval LONG_OPTARG="\$$LONG_OPTIND"
        OPTION=${ARRAY_OPTS[$LONG_OPTION]}
        [[ "x$OPTION" = "x" ]] &&  OPTION="?" OPTARG="-$LONG_OPTION"

        if [[ $( echo "${SCRIPT_OPTS}" | grep -c "${OPTION}:" ) -eq 1 ]]; then
            if [[ "x${LONG_OPTARG}" = "x" ]] || [[ "${LONG_OPTARG}" = -* ]]; then 
                OPTION=":" OPTARG="-$LONG_OPTION"
            else
                OPTARG="$LONG_OPTARG";
                if [[ $LONG_OPTIND -ne -1 ]]; then
                    [[ $OPTIND -le $Optnum ]] && OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND+1 ))
                    shift $OPTIND
                    OPTIND=1
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi

    #== options follow by another option instead of argument ==#
    if [[ "x${OPTION}" != "x:" ]] && [[ "x${OPTION}" != "x?" ]] && [[ "${OPTARG}" = -* ]]; then 
        OPTARG="$OPTION" OPTION=":"
    fi

    #== manage options ==#
    case "$OPTION" in
        f  ) foo=1 bar=0                    ;;
        b  ) foo=0 bar=1                    ;;
        B  ) barfoo=${OPTARG}               ;;
        F  ) foobar=1 && foobar_name=${OPTARG} ;;
        h ) usagefull && exit 0 ;;
        : ) echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: -$OPTARG: option requires an argument" >&2 && usage >&2 && exit 99 ;;
        ? ) echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: -$OPTARG: unknown option" >&2 && usage >&2 && exit 99 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((${OPTIND} - 1))
```

Here is a test:

```
# Short options test
$ ./foobar_any_getopts.sh -bF "Hello world" -B 6 file1 file2
foo=0 bar=1
barfoo=6
foobar=1 foobar_name=Hello world
files=file1 file2

# Long and short options test
$ ./foobar_any_getopts.sh --bar -F Hello --barfoo 6 file1 file2
foo=0 bar=1
barfoo=6
foobar=1 foobar_name=Hello
files=file1 file2
```

Otherwise **in recent Korn Shell** ksh93, `getopts` can naturally parse long options and even display a man page alike. (See http://www.uxora.com/unix/shell-script/20-getopts-with-man-page-and-long-options)

Answer (score 0):

Th built-in OS X (BSD) getopt does not support long options, but the GNU version does: `brew install gnu-getopt`.  Then, something similar to: `cp /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-getopt/1.1.6/bin/getopt /usr/local/bin/gnu-getopt`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple DIY to get only long named args:

Use:

```sh
$ ./test-args.sh --a1 a1 --a2 "a 2" --a3 --a4= --a5=a5 --a6="a 6"
a1 = "a1"
a2 = "a 2"
a3 = "TRUE"
a4 = ""
a5 = "a5"
a6 = "a 6"
a7 = ""
```

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function main() {
    ARGS=`getArgs "$@"`

    a1=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a1`
    a2=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a2`
    a3=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a3`
    a4=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a4`
    a5=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a5`
    a6=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a6`
    a7=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a7`

    echo "a1 = \"$a1\""
    echo "a2 = \"$a2\""
    echo "a3 = \"$a3\""
    echo "a4 = \"$a4\""
    echo "a5 = \"$a5\""
    echo "a6 = \"$a6\""
    echo "a7 = \"$a7\""

    exit 0
}


function getArgs() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}


function getNamedArg() {
    ARG_NAME=$1

    sed --regexp-extended --quiet --expression="
        s/^--$ARG_NAME=(.*)\$/\1/p  # Get arguments in format '--arg=value': [s]ubstitute '--arg=value' by 'value', and [p]rint
        /^--$ARG_NAME\$/ {          # Get arguments in format '--arg value' ou '--arg'
            n                       # - [n]ext, because in this format, if value exists, it will be the next argument
            /^--/! p                # - If next doesn't starts with '--', it is the value of the actual argument
            /^--/ {                 # - If next do starts with '--', it is the next argument and the actual argument is a boolean one
                # Then just repla[c]ed by TRUE
                c TRUE
            }
        }
    "
}


main "$@"
```

Answer (score -1):

hm.

not really satisfied with the pure bash options. why not use perl to get what you want. Directly parse the $* array, and auto-name your options.

simple helper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Getopt::Long;

my $optstring = shift;

my @opts = split(m#,#, $optstring);

my %opt;
GetOptions(\%opt, @opts);

print "set -- " . join(' ', map("'$_'", @ARGV)) . ";";
my $xx;

my $key;
foreach $key (keys(%opt))
{
    print "export $key='$opt{$key}'; ";
}
```

then you can use in your script as a one liner, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

eval `getopts.pl reuse:s,long_opt:s,hello $*`;

echo "HELLO: $hello"
echo "LONG_OPT: $long_opt"
echo "REUSE: $reuse"

echo $*
```

/tmp/script.sh hello --reuse me --long_opt whatever_you_want_except_spaces --hello 1 2 3

HELLO: 1
LONG_OPT: whatever_you_want_except spaces
REUSE: me

1 2 3

Only caveat here is spaces don't work. But it avoids bash's rather complicated looping syntax, works with long args, auto-names them as variables and automatically resizes $*, so will work 99% of the time.

Comment: This is flawed.  You need to use `"$@"` rather than `$*` to correctly preserve whitespace and other shell metacharacter in the list of arguments. (I have not examined the code any further.)

Comment: Why not use perl is because it adds a layer of complexity (another thing to rely on). I cannot say with certainty in my tired head but I would think also that this would be less efficient. Personally I don't think bash has a complicated looping syntax though ironically I don't use the similar syntax to C when C is by far my favourite to work with. I don't know if that is a POSIX compliant thing is one reason I guess but the other way is just as fine too. Of course shells do vary in some ways but still. Even so it's certainly possible to use another language but not necessarily ideal.