# Bash Shell Specify valid options for getops

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

This is the code I'm working with:

```
TYPE=""
FILE=""

while getopts "t:f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)  TYPE="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        f)  FILE="$OPTARG"
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$TYPE" ]; then
  echo "No -t. Bye."
  exit 1 # error
else
  if [ -n "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$TYPE and $FILE"
  else
    echo JUST $TYPE
  fi
fi
```

Is it possible to specify valid options for $TYPE? For example valid type options are:

```
IMAGE, ZIP, DOC
```

If one of these types are specified as valid arguments then the script runs the existing line:

```
"echo "$TYPE and $FILE""
```

Otherwise it echos an error and quits. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Sure, what have you search/try ?

Comment: This is the closest I could find but I couldnt work out how to adapt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587076/how-to-create-a-bash-script-that-takes-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to filter out `-t` switch :

```
(...)
        t)
            case $OPTARG in
                img|image|doc)
                    TYPE="$OPTARG"
                ;;
                *)
                    echo >&2 "Unsupported type..."
                    exit 1
                ;;
            esac
        ;;
(...)
```

Comment: probably don't want to `break` -- `t) case $OPTARG in (img|image|doc) TYPE=$OPTARG ;; ...` might be better

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm a little confused by your example, do I still need the while getopts "t:f:" opt; do line?

Comment: I have guessed how to implement it here but I'm worried I have misunderstood https://gist.github.com/4599218