# Extract options and arguments from a command in unix

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am writing a script which will intercept any command I fire on my shell (ksh93),
and process the options and arguments according to my requirement.

Say, I have script.ksh

```
./script.ksh
$ rm -rf dir1 dir2
```

Then I want to extract r,f and dir1, dir2 separately, so that I can examine each option individually and then do something more before deleting dir1, dir2

I came up with the following code to separate options and arguments into different arrays:

```
read INPUT

count=`echo $INPUT | wc -w`
echo $count

command=`echo $INPUT | cut -d' ' -f1`
echo $command

counter=2
indexOptions=0
indexArgs=0
while [ "$counter" -le "$count" ]
do
    word=`echo $INPUT | cut -d' ' -f$counter`

    if [[ "$word" == -* ]]
    then

        options["$indexOptions"]=$word
        ((indexOptions=indexOptions+1))
    else
        args["$indexArgs"]=$word
        ((indexArgs=indexArgs+1))
    fi
    ((counter=counter+1))
done
```

But I wish to know if there is a better way or any other command or tool which I can use to improve my approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getopts`. It is newer and IMHO better than `getopt`, see [a question about getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721946/cross-platform-getopt-for-a-shell-script) for some more discussion.

Comment: I am not passing arguments to the script, after running the script I will type any command and then from that command I have to extract the options and arguments.
I tried looking into the command `getopts` but am not able to do what I need.
Maybe it is not obvious to me because I am new to Unix and shell scripting ( 1 month experience ). Could you please nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Try and find some examples.  Your use case is different from the default in that you will need to provide `$INPUT` as the final argument of `getopts` explicitly.  Whenever you read a new command and `$INPUT` changes, you must reset `getopts` with `OPTIND=1`.